# How can I vote to close a question without instantly closing it with a gold badge?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, dupehammer

Closing questions as duplicates is a great feature, however for some of the questions, I would prefer to vote to close instead of instantly closing it as a duplicate since I am having a gold badge in one of its tags. Sometimes we prefer to make sure that other eyes have looked at it and we all made sure that it is a duplicate.

Obviously, when choosing "close" -> "duplicate of", it would instantly close it. It is the same for choosing "flag" -> "a duplicate", it would also close it.

So, how can I vote to close the question (which would need more 4 votes to be closed) as a duplicate without actually closing it?

Comment: Just fake the auto-generated close comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow user to choose between an ordinary close vote and the mighty Mjölnir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255064/allow-user-to-choose-between-an-ordinary-close-vote-and-the-mighty-mj%c3%b6lnir)

Comment: @HansPassant actually I though of it, but I prefered to find a more neat way to do it...

Comment: close it as duplicate and stay around in case the OP or some user disagree so that you can reply or be aware about any edit made to the post

Answer (score 6):

A (rather stupid, I admit) workaround is to remove the tags you have a gold badge in, vote to close, then rollback.

Another option is to 'just' leave the standard comment ("Possible duplicate of"); maybe the OP or someone else is smart enough to vote to close as well? Of course, that counts as 0 votes instead of 1.

Comment: Don't use the edit workaround please, it just bumps the question needlessly. If it is a duplicate, then close it as such. If not, then don't.