# Is a question still a duplicate if there are better ways to solve the underlying problem even though OP didn't ask for?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I just closed [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62559574/9867451) for being a direct duplicate of [**this other question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/9867451) (trying to copy a javascript array using assignment). It got reopened right away. When I commented, [Scott Sauyet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243641/scott-sauyet), who I assume is the user who reopened the question, replied:

> *The answer there will solve the problem, yes, but there are better solutions to the underlying problem.*

OP never asked for a better solution. OP even admitted that their solution wasn't the best one and that they are still learning.

With that in mind, should questions like these be closed as duplicates or left open for a better solution to emerge?

Comment: I agree, it's a dupe

Comment: They *aren't* exact duplicates. The dupe target has a *specific* point - copying arrays. The closed question asks for a solution where copying arrays is *one* solution.

Comment: Scott has a gold badge in javascript.  I'm inclined to give him the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So does ibrahim, so that point doesn't hold much weight

Comment: Then I guess it's cage match time.  Who wants to place bets?

Comment: @VLAZ They're asking why it didn't work, it didn't work because the array wasn't copied on the line `let unsorted = arr;` if they were asking how _else_ to solve it i'd maybe agree, but... they aren't, they're asking why it didn't work

Comment: @Nick again, I disagree. The user is asking multiple questions there including "Is this an issue with `let`? should I be using `const` instead?" - clearly they are searching for something they aren't sure of. It's clearly asking for an improvement over their current approach in any case. The dupe shows the *issue* but only a specific way of addressing it, that doesn't cover the all possibilities in this case. I don't think we should be applying [the XY problem in reverse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and binding the user to a Y solution.

Comment: @VLAZ That's looking at the explicit questions and not the problem identified by the OP:
*"my `unsorted.map` is returning a sorted array. I have no idea why."* - That is what they want to solve, and they know that

Comment: @VLAZ They are asking whether to use `let` or `const` on the line of code they are trying to copy the array. They are basically asking whether to use `let unsorted = arr;` or `const unsorted = arr;`. Neither will work because that's not how you copy arrays in javascript and the close question solves exactly that.

Comment: Question closed again, due to the meta effect of posting this here.  Nothing more to see.

Comment: @RobertHarvey.  I'm really out of shape in the Covid shutdown era.  So I'm betting on ibrahim in our cage match.

Comment: I want to note that although this happened to me once before, I'd forgotten and I actually didn't intend to single-handedly reopen that question.  I wanted to vote to reopen it for the exact reasons discussed here.  But I was expecting that others would vote and it would be more of a community decision.  I'm not sure I like the power to do it alone...

Comment: @ScottSauyet you might be interested in this feature request https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255064/allow-user-to-choose-between-an-ordinary-close-vote-and-the-mighty-mj%c3%b6lnir

Comment: Thanks, @Nick.  I don't spend much time on Meta, so hadn't seen that.  But you're right, I'd be very much in favor of at least having the *option* of adding my vote to the tally rather than making the decision alone.

Comment: The OP got a perfect answer for his usecase, future visitors find the common duplicate. I'd say that's a win win :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the camp that believes that closing a question as a duplicate means that either

- this question is a clear duplicate of the (presumably well-answered) other one.  (In Javascript, where I spend much of my SO time, this might be a pointer to [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321) for the many times someone asks a nearly identical question.)
- the accepted -- or the top-voted -- answer there will answer this question with little ambiguity.  (In JS this might be a pointer to [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102), which can explain many different behaviors that seem odd to newcomers.)

In other circumstances, I will usually choose not to close them.  I do wish there was a reputation level that allowed users to vote *against* closing question rather than waiting for a close and voting to reopen.

Here the OP was reporting a "Whiteboard problem".  Whether that's an actual interview-style code-this-in-front-of-us question or one of the myriad code-and-compete-to-learn sites, I don't know.  Either way, I assumed that the OP was trying to learn in this exercise, rather than just solving the immediate practical problem.  This was reinforced by:

> I use sorting to find the shortest string. (not best practice but hey i'm learning).

But I don't know if making that call is appropriate.  I've been around a while and I tend to want to close as a duplicate only when it's really obvious.  This is amplified by the OP being very new to SO.  But this viewpoint may be counterproductive, and I'd love to hear if it is from those more experienced or those more active in meta.

Comment: But isn't it a clear duplicate, though? OP said in the second paragraph: _"But when I try to map the arr later, it remains sorted, **even if I set it to a different variable early in the function**. Is this an issue with let? should I be using const instead?"_ If the wording had been a little different, I wouldn't have closed it.

Comment: Well, we wouldn't be having this conversation unless I disagreed with that!  :-)  And I still do.  I still feel this was a broader question to which the proposed duplicate could only supply a less-useful answer.  I was actually in the process of writing my first comment there when the question was closed.  And the duplicate didn't seem to fit either of my categories above.  I think that's just our different readings of the OP's wording.   But I also think you've raised an interesting broader point worth discussing.

Comment: The disagreement here is not on when questions are dupes, but on answering what OP asks for vs what they should have asked.