# What is the gold point near the username?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

See the screen shot: *lonesomeday `*`*

> [image]

What does it represent?

An example could be found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23853572/1420197).

Comment: Move your mouse over it, check the tooltip.

Comment: @Mat Ah, you're right: *Users with the [javascript] gold badge can single-handedly mark [javascript] questions as duplicates* - but when was it implemented?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers

Comment: @Mat OK, but [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23616682/1420197) the gold badge doesn't appear.

Comment: The indicator was added a bit later.

Comment: Well, that does seem like a bug. Adding the indicator should have added it to *all* of the questions closed with this ability, regardless of when it happened.

Comment: @CodyGray I doubt they consider it a bug, they didn't update already closed questions when they changed the reasons, I doubt they'd update the indicator.

Comment: That's because it would be impossible to "update" the reasons. The reasons that were chosen are no longer available as options. You can't just "convert" the actual reason the voters chose into a new reason that is now available. If you could, there wouldn't have been any point in *changing* the reasons that are available. In this case, however, they didn't change the fundamental way in which the question was closed. They just added an indicator. The indicator should have been retroactive, applying to all questions that were closed with the dupe-hammer ability. I still think it's a bug.