# Should my question be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440477/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-html-table-related-elements

This (older) question of mine was closed for supposedly being off-topic. It has almost 100 views and 2 upvotes. It is marked as favourite for 2 people. I still think it's interesting and on-topic. Its single comment is the bud for a good answer even.

By the way, I don't agree how a single user has the power to close a question all by himself, at least when it's not obviously garbage or so (the upvotes vouch for that).

Comment: Will was still a moderator at that time. He had the power *then*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, but everyone makes mistakes. Moderators probably only rarely do, but that's why I ask here if he did.

Comment: The question looks for an external resource, a link. That type of question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it tends to attract spam. It doesn't matter if your post received upvotes; popularity is not the same thing as being on-topic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't necessarily want external resources. If someone writes an extensive answer, it'd be great.

Comment: Then edit your question to remove the external link requirement. It may still be too broad in that case, but if you were to edit the post it would be automatically added to the reopen review queue. It may or may not pass muster in the eyes of the reviewers in that case. Add a comment below the post explaining what you changed and why you think the post is worthy of reopening.

Comment: Watch the meta effect kicking in on the voting...

Comment: Regarding the single user thing you might be intrested in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers too

Comment: @MartijnPieters Posts only go to the reopen queue when they are edited while on hold.  This question was closed much longer than 5 days ago.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I edited it, removed the need for external resources.

Comment: As you state on the original question and in your comment here, an answer could be "extensive" to the point of it raising new questions. So I guess it could also fall into the too broad region at one point as well, as it doesn't address one specific issue, but many theoretical ones

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester It's now very clear, particularly after your edit, that this question is primarily opinion based, and therefore not appropriate for the site.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: no, it was not marked as a duplicate using the dupe hammer. It was closed *by a moderator* over a year ago, because it was simply off-topic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I know, I was merely giving him a hint on what might be interesting for him, given that he generally seems to disagree that single users should have such powers.

Comment: @Servy: ah, yes, you are right. I forgot about the age requirement. No matter, the question is too broad and primarily opinion based. There is no official way to build a table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can see his point - your question is fairly open ended and not something that can be answered precisely. It invites opinion rather than a technical answer and you are not asking for a solution to a fixed problem.

Not everyone would agree with the moderators decision, but "with great power comes great responsibility" and a moderator has to have the wisdom of when to use that power. Like a referee, a moderator has to make judgement calls, and like a referee, sometimes those calls will fall into a grey area and be disputed by others.

I've had a few questions booted myself, and whilst in some cases I didn't like it, in other cases it encouraged me to rephrase my question into something much more specific. Perhaps you should do the same....

Comment: +1.  Definitely off topic. A great post for a forum, not a good topic here.

Comment: The meta question is probably getting downvotes because meta is different. Here people tend to use voting to agree/disagree with a post. They think "No, this question should not be reopened" and press downvote.

Comment: Which is not the point of the upvoting or downvoting system imho. It is to indicate the *quality* of a question, not to measure consensus.

Comment: @Nallah: [Meta is different.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @kapa, Deduplicator: I stand corrected and deleted that bit :-)