# I voted to close as "unclear" but it shows up as "duplicate", why?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I voted to close [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100258/sort-a-list-according-to-another-list-in-python#comment37173816_24100258) question as "unclear", but is shows up as if I voted to close it as duplicate, why?

This is besides the point, but I do not feel that the question was a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that @senderle used the [gold badge duplicate hammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589) to close the question, which only requires the single vote of that gold badge holder.

However, that doesn't mean that you voted to close it as a duplicate. The close reason is selected based on the majority of reasons it was closed. It will list all users who cast a close vote, but only display the close reason used most for that question.

Comment: Oh, and binding close votes take precedence. If there are four, say, duplicate votes on a question, but then a moderator closes it as off-topic, it will show as everyone closing it as off-topic.