# Please don't pretend I voted to close for another reason

Tags: feature-request, bug, close-reasons

A question was closed, and this was displayed:

[image]

This looks fine, except that I disagree this question is a duplicate, I voted to close because there was no MCVE, the code failing to produce the desired output wasn't shown, and I don't like to guess what exact bug was the reason of OP's problem.

Could we please have this message changed ? If this question was gold-hammered as a duplicate, only the name of the hammerer and of people who had the same opinion matter. People who wanted to close for another reason shouldn't be listed (or it shouldn't be written that they voted to close for the same reason but as it might be hard to put simply I have no problem with only the hammerer name being present).

Related: [I voted to close as "unclear" but it shows up as "duplicate", why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258782/i-voted-to-close-as-unclear-but-it-shows-up-as-duplicate-why)

But this isn't the same question: what I'd like is the text be clarified.

Comment: In the related post, I found "_It will list all users who cast a close vote, but only display the close reason used most for that question._ ". I am not a fan of this approach. I am active in the SO chat room. Assume that the OP shows up there, he might ask me why I voted it as dupe and could ask for clarification. My first reaction would surely be "_uhmmm_" ...

Comment: see also: [After question is closed expose close votes distinguished by reason in the timeline page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284886/165773)

Comment: Yeah, this has always pissed me off. It's embarrassing - heck, maybe even slightly defamatory - when the close reason wrongly attributed to me is something obviously nuts. Many countries - including the UK, where I live - have [laws against false attribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_rights_in_United_Kingdom_law#Right_to_object_to_false_attribution); while these probably don't apply to falsely attributing a selection of a boilerplate close reason to me in the way that they would apply to falsely attributing a comment or answer to me, the same *moral* principle applies here, I think.

Comment: I agree with this closure here... My question or feature request *is* a duplicate... But... [I can't say that "solved my problem"](https://i.imgur.com/sYO8Ias.png)...

Comment: If the gold hammer overrides, the gold hammer is responsible.

Comment: Gosh, I got a "nice question badge" for a question I myself voted to close as duplicate :)

Comment: @DenysSéguret That's Meta for you. Votes and badges flow like water here.

Answer (score -12):

StackOverflow has decided, long ago, to simplify the presentation of answer closure into one message; but, to honor multiple votes in deciding to present that message.

This mans that while five people may have mostly closed an answer for "Exact duplicate" but a minority within that five closed it for "needs improvement" the message will be closed for "Exact duplicate"

Little review of the closing process is done, the preferred means of reopening a question basically break down to:

1. Attempting to gather enough votes to reopen.
2. Appealing on Meta that a question was closed unjustly.
3. Direct appeal to a moderator

All of these repair processes do nothing to train the people who close posts, so odds that they eventually form a consistent set of values to close a post is small.

This means that posts that seem close-able, but are bad in a variety of ways will get a variety of closure reasons, or people who read less (or more) carefully will close the post in a divergent-from-the-group manner.

So we could appeal to the developers to fix the message, but in asking for a fix, it is unclear how we would fix the message without:

1. Listing the close reason for each voter
2. Assuring that sufficient close reasons are present that each voter can pick a high-fidelity closing reason.
3. Putting in a text box asking the closer for a high-fidelity reason.

The first puts a lot of negative feedback to a person.  Negative feedback tends to drive people away from the site, or at least makes them less likely to contribute.

The second actually makes the problem of unifying closure more difficult.

The third can capture the intent perfectly, but imposes no strict closure policy, requiring even more policing.  For example, I could close a post with "You're a cakesniffer!"  Which would certainly be personal attack instead of constructive feedback.

Comment: This still feels like a rant against closing.

Comment: @fbueckert I do not agree. For me it reads as an argument against the question's request. And a good one, IMO.

Comment: @yivi If it is, it's lost in the first part, which does nothing to actually answer the question, but criticizes closers.  Don't get me wrong, I agree with how it currently works.  But I don't think the parts about how to get something reopened belongs in any sense.

Comment: @fbueckert Maybe I'm having an overly slow day, but where does it criticize closers? I agree that the previous answer was an ill suited rant, but this one, I can grok.

Comment: We do have number 3 though. It's ONE of the close reasons (and not the only one, of course), but it exists.

Comment: Having an option that perfectly reflects your intent still does nothing to the line the five intense into one message or condense the five messages

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't say it solved the issue. It was just to point out that this piece of your suggestion is somewhat already there.