# Canonical duplicate for "floating point is inaccurate"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

The question of "why is my floating point operation coming up as 0.0999999999999784" comes up **really** frequently. Usually we just leave a link to [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf) and attempt to close the question somehow.

Here's a recent example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153243/python-floating-point-calculate-error

Now that I [wield the mighty Mjölnir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/1204143), I've been thinking that it would be far more efficient to just close these kinds of questions as duplicates of a single canonical answer. Is this a good idea (I hope so)? What question should I use as the canonical answer? The best I could come up with was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1089018/1204143) but I'm not convinced it is the best choice yet.

If there's no clear winner, I wonder if we should consider making a question and answer for this purpose. Something along the lines of "Why do certain floating-point operations produce answers are are slightly wrong?"

Comment: What other questions/answers did you have in mind?  Sure, this one may need a bit of polish to get rid of lower quality answers, but it's one of those that ranks pretty high in my mind.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a better question or answer. That's the best one I could find with a cursory search, but it feels like there should be a more beginner-friendly one (especially for a question that gets asked so often).

Comment: If I may, such an answer might consider including at least a good link to some techniques for comparing these properly (e.g., last place unit).

Comment: Jon Skeet's answer on that canonical question just got its 242nd upvote due to the attention this question is giving it... proving once more that the community does not understand how voting works.

Comment: Any canonical question would pretty much need to summarize the material in [WECSSKAFPA](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf).

Comment: @RobertHarvey, And nobody understands how Jon Skeet works.

Comment: Possibly, but a good summary would beat referring people to a 90+ page treatise (which, while excellent, is potentially beyond what many SO askers are willing to read).

Comment: @RobertHarvey The community is too afraid to edit further information into Jon's answer (assuming you use his answer as the starting point).

Comment: WECSSKAFPA is a **terrible** page to link to. If only that it's 93 pages long, with some amusing TeX mixed it, and your average new programmer who's thrown by floating-point numbers will never get far enough into it to do any good. I wish people would stop linking to it on SO. To get started, [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) is much better.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: All the better reason to have a nice canonical duplicate on SO for us to link to.

Comment: You can also use [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), though that was originally a JavaScript-specific question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What's wrong with upvoting a good answer? Even if linked from meta.

Comment: I think the canonical question's answers should include links to both [WECSSKAFPA](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf) and a simpler, more superficial, introduction. Some people encountering floating point for the first time are computer scientists, used to reading academic papers. Others are beginning programmers with limited ability to read mathematical notation. The canonical duplicate should cater to both.

Comment: @user000001: I know that's a Jon Skeet answer, but seriously, does it deserve two hundred and forty two upvotes? Ten or twelve, maybe.  Not two hundred and forty two.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It depends. If that many people have found it useful, then I guess it does. That's the thing about the voting system - it's about how many people like the answer rather than how wonderful the answer is. A highly detailed, beautifully written answer on a niche topic that only a couple of people care about will get a smaller number of votes than a simple answer on a popular topic. Comparing the number of votes on different answers doesn't compare their quality, but it *does* potentially compare their universal usefulness.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's not trying to claim my answer is of particularly high quality, of course. I'm just trying to explain why it *is* understandable that a "reasonably helpful" answer gets a large number of votes. Put it this way - I think it's more useful for that answer to have a high vote count than [my most popular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479), which has a practical benefit to almost no-one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - might be interesting to see how many more votes it gets now that you've said that we shouldn't...

Comment: While the answer to that canonical question will surely answer all of the duplicates you have in mind, you need to be extra careful that the question actually matches enough. Asking "why is floating point inaccurate" is not going to be a good duplicate for "why is this calculation returning 9999 instead of 10000" because to transfer that to "why is fp inaccurate" you would already need to know that it *is* inaccurate.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: My answer to the question "How can I write a switch statement in Ruby?", also from 2009, has more than 1000 upvotes. And I'm not even the slightest bit Jon Skeet. Decent answers to common questions from the early days of the site can garner an absurd number of votes over the years.

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up says *"Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!"*, I guess 247 (and counting) people find the answer useful. How is that proving that the community does not understand how voting works?

Comment: While a language agnostic canonical question and answer may be useful, it should not supplant established language specific ones such as http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/892313 for the [tag:r] language which contain language specific techniques for managing this.

Comment: @JonSkeet Obviously wrong answers also gather quite a number of several occasions.  The upvotes that you get aren't possibly because of your _answers_, but because of the rep.  Several (who wouldn't understand either the question or the answer) would think that this has to be the most useful answer.

Comment: @devnull: That may well account for some of it, yes. But Robert's suggestion that the answer might deserve 10 or 12 votes but not 242 seems to go way beyond that.

Comment: Within [IEEE_754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) are specifications for decimal floating point formats.  Should languages start main-lining decimal formats like [decimal64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format), a canonical answer about floating point inaccuracy may need serious updates.  Could foresee questions like, "why is my floating point operation _not_ inaccurate?".  The point being canonical answers age and their votes often reflect their _history_ of usefulness, but not their validity in light of recent developments.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta `WECSSKAFPA is a terrible page to link to. If only that it's 93 pages long` I agree. Let's not treat them like children, linking to material scarcely long enough to entertain for more than a short bathroom break. Link them to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) and tell them it's time to get serious. If you read that all at once, it won't be a bathroom break you'll soon forget.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Those 242 (now 390) votes don't say anything about whether the community does or doesn't understand voting.  What they prove is that the social media [network effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect) is real.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would suggest that if your desire is to close these questions as duplicates of a canonical Q&A, you should take advantage of the fact that such a canonical Q&A already exists in the form of [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/2359271).

Whether it's a "good" canonical Q&A is beside the point given that its explicit purpose is to be that canonical Q&A, and editing existing content into shape is strongly preferred over duplication.

That being said, the question and its comments are full of conversational cruft - it definitely needs work. To that end, you could flag the question and ask a moderator to wikify it. Many questions and answers that have come to be regarded as canonical on SO are community wikis - though given the recent move away from automatic wiki creation, one could question whether that was appropriate to begin with.

In my mind, the existing "canonical" attempt's biggest strength is its `language-agnostic` tag; and accordingly, all references to Python in the question and its tags should be removed. That being said, there are many different questions that ultimately lead to this fundamental question, and some of these bigger questions may be more appropriately answered in a language-specific fashion; e.g., one that includes a pointer to standard library resources.

---

I would further suggest that a truly "canonical" Q&A on this subject should have the following qualities:

- The canonical question itself should be stated in as concise a form as will effectively tell inexperienced readers: "Yes, this **is** what you're asking." In other words, it has to capture "why is my value displayed wrong" questions but also "why aren't these values equal" questions, and so forth.
- The canonical question should be followed by a single, high-quality, prominent (i.e., upvoted and accepted), **language-agnostic** canonical answer, containing **at most** one brief example, and providing links to further reading. (Why not a long, detailed answer? As many have pointed out, such resources exist all over the web already. Our job is only to convince the inexperienced user that we've identified the root of their problem, and *here's* what they need to understand, and *here* are the hundreds of places where they can acquire that understanding.)
- The canonical question should additionally have language-specific answers **as appropriate to identify specific resources or quirks** of particular languages.
- Language-specific answers should be **community wiki** and there should be **at most one** for any particular language. (There doesn't need to be a separate answer for every language in existence, and languages that behave similarly might be addressed together.)
- The **canonical question should contain internal links** to the available language-specific answers, to help users who understand the basic concept locate the bit that's relevant to their use case. (Maintenance requirements of this table of contents would be a good reason to make the question community wiki.)

---

One alternative that's been suggested is to have a number of language-specific "canonical" Q&As. The only advantage I can think of there is better tags. Since answers inherit the tags of the question, anyone searching *only* language-specific tags for a solution to their floating-point problem might have trouble locating the combined Q&A that has no language-specific tags.

That being said, I think this issue is a corner case. How many users who don't know about floating-point arithmetic are using SO's internal search, versus Google et al.? Of those, how many explicitly filter by tags as a first resort?

This marginal benefit to internal searches would mean inevitable errors and inconsistencies between the various language-specific Q&As, lots of duplicated information, more work to maintain all the dispersed links, more work to close duplicates since you have to find which canonical question has the right canonical answer... That doesn't really fit with the spirit of the OP's suggestion, in my opinion - it feels a lot like the status quo.

Comment: I have flagged my post for CW conversion

Comment: Done, @mhl. Start cross-linking the hell out of this and it'll show up more easily in dup-searches.

Comment: Wonderful! This definitely looks like the kind of canonical question I was looking for.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit @mhlester's answer to make it more language-neutral. Let it be a canonical answer for any language, but with examples in Python. Also, the question has been set as protected.

Comment: @mhlester I've done some more substantial edits to the accepted answer, now that it's CW, but please do check that I haven't significantly altered your original meaning or introduced any errors. IMO, the further examples under `Representing as a Fraction` should be omitted for brevity's sake, but I hesitate to make such a large deletion even if it is CW...

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I do get notified when you change it, but not other people. Maybe because you're <2k? Either way I'll keep watching it. Thanks for the improvements! Maybe that last section can be made more concise, with fewer line breaks or something... Dunno, I guess it could go away

Comment: @Shog9: It doesn't appear at all in the close-as-duplicate dialogue for questions where it would be appropriate.  Is it perhaps better to give a less godawful answer to the "is floating point math broken?" quesiton that always appears on top?  Y'know, instead of you all improving the dupe search?

Comment: The linked to question covers the machine format of numbers. It does not cover mathematical operations and why their order and final rounding for display puposes again change the result from the expected outcome. A canonical Q should also have the best answers. [This Q has two excellent answers to add](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). And [this A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21874981/923794)

Answer (score 9):

Regardless of whether we pick an existing question and add/edit answers, or start a new question with carefully written answers, there are a couple of points that I think should be covered, either directly or through references:

1. Floating point representation is a compromise giving good expressiveness for approximate values across a wide range of magnitudes in a very compact format suitable for fast hardware implementation of basic operations. Other formats are better for some purposes. We should identify some of those purposes and formats.
2. I think we should refer to some of the ways of viewing and manipulating exact values of doubles. For example, in Java I use `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d));` to see the exact value of a double `d`.

I am not sure whether there should be a single canonical answer for all languages, or different answers for different languages. The basic problem is language independent, but the best way of handling e.g. exact manipulation of currency amounts is language dependent.

=================================================================================

The more I think about this, and read the various answers and comments, the more I feel that we should have separate canonical answers for different languages and very common special cases. The answers can all reference some common document for the theoretical background. The most immediately helpful answer for e.g. an R user is going to be the existing R answer. The most immediately helpful answer for a Java user will be based on the assumption of JLS conforming floating point, touch on the effects of strictfp, and mention the use of BigDecimal for exact handling of terminating decimal fractions, including currency calculations.

Even with the scatter that will cause, I think the canonical pages for the common languages will rapidly become highly referenced.

Comment: I would advocate language specific questions and answers (or at least answers). In the R language, we already have http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/892313 which covers the theory briefly (and mostly by reference to other sources) and spends most of the answer discussing R specific workarounds for the cases where this often comes up. To date, 40 questions have been closed as a duplicate for this one. Perhaps as a domain specific language for statistics, this comes up more often in the R tag and this is how we have dealt with it.

Comment: Re: language agnostic versus language specific: why not both? An agnostic answer to identify and explain the fundamental mathematical issue, followed by a variety of specific wiki answers to track resources, quirks, etc. of specific languages. I've expanded on this in an answer.

Comment: @AirThomas: R has a considerable base of users who need to do statistics but aren't necessarily interested or experienced in programming for its own sake.  A single language-agnostic answer risks alienating that crowd, since they may be unable to map R concepts to and from language-agnostic concepts.  Also, if we were to adopt the (excellent) R answer Brian linked to as canonical, some things don't reproduce in other languages that attempt to paper over floating-point's inexact representation of some decimal constants during output.

Comment: @tmyklebu Yes, absolutely - the language-specific answers should be indexed in the question, so that someone skimming the page understands there's more than just an abstract mathematical discussion. (Thanks for the reminder!)

Answer (score 6):

We've done this over at Super User a few times now ([example1](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for), [example 2](https://superuser.com/questions/224515/how-do-i-troubleshoot-hardware-issues-related-to-a-computer-freeze-crash)), and I believe that it's a successful tactic if used correctly.  From reading the comments, other answers, and looking at the example linked questions, I think a canonical question/answer **should** be put in place.  However, let me give some guides to the person that is going to make the post:

- **Make the question language agnostic.**  While specific languages may have specific issues, the overall concept of floating point *should* be the same across all languages that implement the IEEE definition of floating point.
- **Keep it simple.**  Summarizes the concepts, while linking to trustworthy, and sound sources (i.e. sites that more than likely won't get shut down).  Having a really long answer makes it more difficult/tedious to read.  You'll lose readers and end up right back where you were with questions continually coming in.  As an alternative, you can also place a summary at the beginning and delve deeper below that summary.
- **Don't go on a closing spree.**  Focus more on new questions that have come in or are coming in.  When you do close older questions, make sure they're asking specifically regarding the topic of floating point "inaccuracies" and not specific to a language.

Comment: "Don't go on a closing spree" - good point. A canonical answer is valuable as more than a target for duplicate flags; it makes the integrity of links to *external* resources much easier to maintain if used as an *internal* reference in answering related, non-duplicate questions.

Comment: The basic issue is not quite language-agnostic. Some languages require floating point to behave like the IEEE 32 and 64 bit binary. Others are designed to allow for other formats and arithmetics. For example, more behavior is defined in Java than in C.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan that may be true, however the canonical answer should approach more of the *theory* of floating point values rather than their actual implementation inside a language.

Comment: The canonical answer need to have sample code for the languages the duplicate question is asking about, so maybe one canonical question per language, that has an answer with the practical solution and points to a language Independence canonical question.

Comment: That's a lot of canonical questions/answers. And any new language would then bed to be added. The point of a canonical question is to prevent that very thing. In this case I don't believe that we need to show an example of each language but rather talk about the concept.

Answer (score 4):

I might suggest that a lot of questions that get that link-and-close-as-duplicate aren't actually duplicates of that question.  There are a handful of boring floating-point questions that come up over and over:

- I accidentally converted a `double` literal to a `float` to a `double` and I got something weird past the sixth decimal place.
- Even when I print out a number to 50 decimal places, round-to-Java makes it look like I got exactly `0.1`.  Yet that isn't how arithmetic seems to work.  What's going on?
- I'm adding `0.1` to itself 100 times and not getting what I wanted.
- My system's `pow` is garbage, and when I square `10.0` I don't get `100.0`.
- I want to recover information that I lost by converting my number to floating-point.

Perhaps these deserve canonical answers.  However, I do not think the usual answer, which usually boils down to "I, the answerer, harbour unjustified superstitions about floating-point arithmetic," is helpful, so I don't think there should be a *single* canonical answer to boring floating-point questions.

Comment: There should be a single canonical answer. Each of these is a sub-issue, which can be addressed individually - pretty much as you have done here - in the canonical answer

Comment: They're five fundamentally different issues, though.  In order, an initially invisible loss of precision, a devious standard library, accumulated roundoff, a buggy standard library, and PEBCAK.  A "floating-point can be counterintuitive" question/answer doesn't strike me as much more useful than a "programming can be counterintuitive" answer of which most SO questions would be "duplicates."

Comment: I agree that there are many flavors of floating-point question (+1), but disagree that this justifies multiple "canonical" answers. There are really only two flavors to be concerned with - display issues and calculation issues. Sometimes we can only take the user so far before telling them, "Go forth and eat of thy documentation and drink of thy standard library."

Comment: @AirThomas: I can see a canonical answer hitting three of the five classes I listed.  (Say points 2, 3, and 5, and even that would be a meandering answer.)  Points 1 and 2 are language-specific.  Point 4-like questions concern an implementation bug that isn't even addressed in Goldberg's paper.

Comment: I may have misspoke. It seems to me that you're suggesting multiple canonical questions and answers. I'm fine with the idea that there should be multiple answers, but why not take advantage of the ability of the SE platform to collect them under the umbrella of a single canonical question?

Comment: @AirThomas: I'm suggesting that the five questions above are all specific enough to have clear, concise answers and that this approach is better than having a single, extremely broad question with either a single long and meandering canonical answer or multiple answers.  This is because the single canonical question would necessarily be extremely broad and people would reflexively close even interesting FP questions as duplicates of it.

Comment: @tmyklebu The one thing that all of these questions have in common, is that the asker has not realized that there could be something counter-intuitive about floating point operations. So the answer to any of them will boil down to "here is how floating point operations work and why they go wrong"

Comment: @Benubird: You can hit points 2, 3, and 5 with an answer like that.  Point 1 is a language use whoopsie.  Point 4 is insidious---it's a bug in the `pow` implementation they're using.  It's not helpful to say "here's what a compiler is" to someone who stumbles on a wrong-code bug, and it's not helpful to say "here's what a floating-point number is" when they're using a broken `pow`.

Comment: @tmyklebu I agree with you about point 4, but I think that it is sufficiently different that it warrants a separate question anyway. The bug in pow might (possibly) not have anything to do with floating point math, and even if it does it isn't relevant. I'm not so sure about point 1, it might be similar enough to count as a general floating point issue, but it might also be a bug in the compiler (depending on just how strange it is).

Comment: It's not a compiler bug.  It's `float f = 1.3; if (f != 1.3) printf("StackOverflow, here's another duplicate question.\n");`  This is legitimately confusing if you aren't used to C's data types.  The root cause here is the loss of precision when converting `1.3` to `float`; a generic introduction to floating-point isn't called for here.

Answer (score 2):

It is up to you to decide if you want to write a canonical question + answer.

Do however keep in mind that perhaps the *real problem* is that there are too many answers.  Adding yet another one doesn't solve that issue.  Ideally SO has none, this general problem has been covered extensively on many existing sites already.  "Floating point accuracy problems" has 3.15 million Google hits.

Comment: Posting another Q&A, in itself, doesn't solve anything, but if you're closing a few dozen posts as a duplicate of it, that's at least a step in the right direction. If [so] has none, that's not very ideal, because we don't have an "answered on another site" close reason.

Comment: @Duke - try that Google query.  The 3rd hit is an SO question.  The answer is not a very good one.  Avoiding diluting existing content was once a strong SO goal.  Not sure what happened to it, I missed the memo.

Comment: The real problem with this issue is that there are so many different questions. There is an enormous family of results that yell "floating point rounding error" to anyone who already understands the issue, but that look like unique and strange behavior to anyone who does not. If we wrote or picked a canonical question it would rapidly become one of the most referenced answers in SO, and very high in Google's ranking.

Answer (score -2):

Write a canonical answer. Make it big, with plenty of detail to explain the issue even to someone who has no understanding of what "floating point" even means, and make an effort to address all of the different cases, maybe with a list of similar questions like tmyklebu has described.

Then make it community wiki - specifically writing a question/answer so that a bunch of other questions can be closed as duplicates of it seems unfair. Especially as most of the answer can be copy/pasted from other sources, such as the wikipedia article on rounding error. Open it up for other people to contribute.

Close all the questions as duplicates of it, leaving a comment suggesting that if it is not clear how the canonical question is a duplicate, they should edit it (community wiki!) to make it clear.

Ultimately, this would hopefully build up into a big floating-point-error FAQ that covers all the basics, and rises to the top of the search results so that people can easily find it. There can, after all, only be so many different formulations of the problem.

Comment: "Make it big, with plenty of detail to explain the issue even to someone who has no understanding..." *Oy gevalt* would that be big.

Comment: @AirThomas Yep. Hence the community wiki - encourage people who come across one of these questions, to contribute a paragraph to the canonical answer. Everyone adds a little bit, it will grow comprehensive quickly.

Comment: I am not sure about community wikis. Do we really need yet another wikipedia?

Comment: @FinalContest Not if wikipedia covered everything we needed, but it doesn't. Wikipedia is fine for theory, but it doesn't do very well at application, and is definitely not search-friendly for phrases like "why does my addition not work". Just an opinion though, I can see why you might consider wikipedia enough, in which case we should still have the canonical question - it would just have a bunch of links to wikipedia articles instead.