# "Floating point is broken" duplicates

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions

This is a mild rant with the seed of an idea inside.

There are frequently questions about floating point arithmetic and why 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3 (and innumerable variants thereof). These questions can be readily identified using a regex such as `(0{12}|9{12})` because the asker usually includes a result such as `0.30000000000000004`.

This type of question almost always has the same resolution: Mark as duplicate as (one of the) canonical "floating point is broken" questions. In the interest of giving people help in the shortest possible time, might it be possible to identify this kind of question *before* it is posted on the site, and simply give the user the answer straight away? That would save everybody the time and effort of closing the question, and save cluttering up the site with the same question over and over and over.

To be clear, the seed of an idea here is to present the suggested answer (accepted answer from canonical question) on its own page *after* they click "Post Your Question", and then follow up with a yes-no question such as "Does this answer your question?" If yes, great. If no, then (accept defeat and) post it anyway.

Comment: i have the link to http://floating-point-gui.de/ stored for this

Comment: Regex is not the right tool to solve duplicates :)

Comment: @pathDongle Why not?

Comment: How would your scheme handle [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251606/double-data-type-not-returning-desired-output-in-java) question (which has been marked as a "floating point is broken" duplicate)? I've flagged this as a "wrong" duplicate since [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) is a **better** duplicate as it matches a particular concern of the op **If the program is dealing with sensitive information such as precentile/money or cents**

Comment: And I've just realised that Greg Hewgill marked it as the "wrong" duplicate :/

Comment: If the suggested answer does not in fact answer the question, then the user has the option to click "No" and post their question anyway. In the specific case you mention, yes the question you linked is probably a better duplicate but I'm unconvinced that the effort required to change the linked duplicate question, as little as it is, is in fact worth it at all. A better outcome would be for us to never have seen that question in the first place, no?

Comment: @GregHewgill ok. that works for me.

Comment: Is this a feature request?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Sure, let's call it a feature request.

Comment: OK.  How would one generalize such a feature?  Will we also automatically detect NullReferenceException questions and "headers already sent" questions?  Surely we're not talking only about the "floating point is broken" questions.

Comment: There are indeed a handful of very commonly asked questions. Perhaps they could be identified with a combination of specific, targeted regex along with the scores from the auto-identified duplicates that show up as the question is entered. I'm afraid I don't know how that back end works, so I'm unable to offer additional specific ideas.

Comment: Questions about if statements and while loops not working in Java almost always resolve to [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1288) I think what's needed is a search that's seeded with the top [frequent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) questions in the most popular language tags.

Comment: There was a recent thread on meta about picking a canonical duplicate for this.  I seem to recall that people agreed on a solution, but I can't find either the agreed solution or the post.  Pretty sure this is a symptom of SO's search not being up to snuff.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Perhaps [Canonical duplicate for “floating point is inaccurate”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260130/canonical-duplicate-for-floating-point-is-inaccurate)

Comment: I've got some candidates for this feature on Physics SE, too. And I am sure that there are other sites with there "we've got a dozen versions of this @#%(@)%$(@) question, already!" questions.

Comment: I note that Greg is suggesting we use regex to identify this his particular target. That's not going to work as well with all possible targets. Not sure what other tool would be better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I'm a bit skeptical that this'll work - folks seem to find ever more creative ways to be confused about floating-point numbers. But, what the hey...

[image: Having some issues with floating-point numbers? Make sure you've read...]

This is based on some quick'n'dirty text analysis of duplicates and a hellacious regexp, so don't expect it to magically identify everything - here's the pattern if you're interested / see room for improvement:

```
(float|double|decimal|number|math).+(wrong|work|bug|broken|round|strange|odd|equal|accura)|(wrong|work|bug|broken|round|strange|odd|equal|accura).+(float|double|decimal|number|math)|(precision|rounding)|\.\d*[09]{5}[1-9][^0-9a-f]
```

It only matches on titles, both for efficiency's sake and because I'm skeptical about discouraging folks from posting their questions if they get as far as writing the body.

Comment: If this does appear to work, is there any chance that it could be extended to other topics?

Comment: Yeah, like the annoying 'i++ + ++i' UB homework 'question' that pops up every other day.

Comment: Wow, awesome! That's a little more subtle than I was envisioning, but hopefully it will help. Now, what's a good way to measure the performance of this? Since it's just a regex, it can be applied retroactively to (original, unedited) question titles to discover whether the frequency of these particular questions decreases after today.

Comment: We log each time a question is submitted after seeing the warning, @Greg - therefore, a reasonable test might be to see how many questions are submitted after the warning and later closed as duplicates. We might also be able to compare this to the number of times the warning is shown in total.

Comment: Cool. I look forward to seeing the performance numbers.

Comment: @Shog9 just out of interest, do you have any of the numbers? How well did this work?

Comment: "discouraging folks from posting their questions if they get as far as writing the body": This happens to me all the time. As a a matter of fact I often fail to find things with the search field. But when I start typing the body of the question I get better search results listed and often find what I'm looking for.