# Why is [floating-accuracy] less accurate than [floating-point]

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

[floating-accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-accuracy) has [this info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-accuracy/info) (is there a shortcut to link to a tag's info page?):

> Floating point numbers (typically meaning the IEEE standard) are inherently inexact and errors can compound, leading to edge cases in some decision processes, or numerical instability in certain algorithms.

To the point if perhaps rather densely-worded, but when compared to [floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point)'s [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info):

> Many questions asked here about floating point math are about small inaccuracies in floating point arithmetic. To use the example from the excerpt, 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 might result in 0.300000001 instead of the expected 0.3. *[...]*

And so on for a whole page. This anticipates and answers a common question, so assuming people actually read the tag wiki, should we have at least a pointer in [floating-accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-accuracy) to either [floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) or a canonical answer?

I can edit the tag myself, but I'm not sure what the best solution is, so I'm throwing the question to the masses on Meta.

BTW, I notice that the [tag-wiki](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki) says:

> A "tag wiki" is an editable page that briefly summarizes the topic of the tag and that **may provide links to existing questions** that are often useful to many people.

(My bold) Why doesn't [floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) point to a canonical answer on `0.1 + 0.1 != 0.2` instead of/along with off-site resources?

Comment: Suggest an edit for the wiki.  It's good that you feel that it needs to be updated, but the rationale as to "why" may be that it was missed.

Comment: Why doesn't it? Because no one has added it yet. The tag wikis aren't exactly a visible feature, so they aren't terribly well maintained. A few of them are; the [tag:x86] tag wiki is one I'm quite familiar with. There are other popular tags that are similarly maintained, like [tag:c++]. You could become the de facto maintainer of [tag:floating-point], too, if you're up for it.

Comment: The other question that needs to be asked is, *is* there a canonical answer on `0.1 + 0.1 != 0.2`? If so, why didn't you link to it here? Do you mean [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate), [as previously discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260130/canonical-duplicate-for-floating-point-is-inaccurate)?

Comment: @CodyGray Hmm, that gets a bit dense a bit early; I prefer [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) referred to on that Meta page. I'll try writing up something better and we'll see if the tag reviews like it or not.

Comment: Wow, I don't think we need *two* canonical questions about floating-point accuracy. Maybe we should get a moderator to merge those.