# Update Help Center to include the mighty Mjölnir

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, help-center, dupehammer

The [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) topic in the help center states:

> - It takes 5 close votes to reach the closing threshold.

But of course, this is not strictly true and may lead to confusion. Anyone with a gold tag badge has [superpowers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers) and can close a question as a duplicate within that tag with a single vote. The help center should be updated to reflect this.

<sup>Of course moderators also have the power to close questions unilaterally, but I feel this is not as confusing to new users.</sup>

Comment: Dat title. Also: Yea, I agree!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Updated!

> It takes 3 close votes to reach the closing threshold. (A question can be closed as duplicate with a single vote from a moderator or a user who has earned a gold tag badge in one of that question's original tags.)

Comment: Did you also update the tooltips? When I hover over the gold diamond I see, "*Users with the [tag] gold badge can single-handedly mark [tag] questions as duplicates*". I don't remember seeing that before.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I think the tooltips were added very shortly (within a day) after we rolled this feature out; I haven't touched them recently.

Comment: @Laura also in that section there's *The original question must have an answer; you cannot mark a question as a duplicate of an unanswered one.* - I can't find the post on MSO/MSE now, but I think the having an answer requirement isn't necessary if it's the same person asking the question. (Can't find the exact details as I say, and probably not really needed information in the help centre, but thought I'd mention it before I forgot)