# Help Close Duplicates of "Revert to previous Git commit" question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

**I'm looking for help closing questions as a duplicate of a canonical question** about "reverting to a specific Git commit". This is the canonical,

- [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit)

and these are the duplicates,

- <del>[Revert to a commit by a SHA hash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895059/revert-to-a-commit-by-sha-hash)</del> (closed)
- <del>[How do you roll back (reset) a Git repository to a particular commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616957/how-do-you-roll-back-reset-a-git-repository-to-a-particular-commit)</del> (closed)
- <del>[Reverting to a specific commit based on commit id with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639115/reverting-to-a-specific-commit-based-on-commit-id-with-git)</del> (closed)
- <del>[Removing unwanted files from local and reverse commit/merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443502/removing-unwanted-files-from-local-and-reverse-commit-merge)</del> (closed)
- <del>[Checkout old commit and make it a new commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380805/checkout-old-commit-and-make-it-a-new-commit)</del> (closed)
- <del>[git revert back to certain commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794110/git-revert-back-to-certain-commit)</del> (closed)

### Why Are These Duplicates?

All of the questions revolve around "reverting to a specific commit", but there are a lot of instances of the askers and answerers not clearly explaining what they mean by "revert", so **a lot of the answers address the different possible meanings of "reverting to a commit"**:

```
git checkout <commit>
git reset --hard <commit>
git revert <commit>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/456814) to [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit) **does the best job of explaning all three of these different ways to "revert to a specific commit"**, and it's also the most comprehensive answer (for example, pointing out that you can pass a commit range to `git revert`). The question also has the most answers to it.

**It would be great then if the other questions could be closed as a duplicate of the canonical I picked out, and also possibly have the other answers merged into it.**

I've previously tried to close most of these questions as duplicates, but I don't have the [mighty Mjolnir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/456814) yet, and my previous votes aged away many weeks ago.

### Downvoting?

So I noticed that the questions I picked out as duplicates have recently been getting downvotes. It's often said on Meta that, with the exception of sockpuppeting and user-harrasment/revenge votes, users are allowed to vote any way they please. So I'm not going to tell people that they **shouldn't** downvote these questions, but I would **suggest** that many of these questions are **not downvote worthy**, since they were asked *before* the canonical question was asked. The canonical just happened to get better answers.

For most cases, I also happen to find downvoting duplicates a little counter-productive, since they serve as useful signposts to a canonical question. You'll notice that all 4 questions phrase their problem in slightly different ways in the title. They now all point to the canonical question, so why would you want to encourage the askers to delete them? **The duplicates serve a *useful* purpose now.**

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/q/3380805/41071?

Comment: @svick hey, that's a good find, I didn't even know about that one. Yeah, go ahead and close it as a duplicate. While you're at it, I'm looking for more close votes on [Removing unwanted files from local and reverse commit/merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443502/removing-unwanted-files-from-local-and-reverse-commit-merge) too.

Answer (score 2):

[git revert back to certain commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6794110/1369473) also looks like a duplicate to me.  I'll try to look for more possibilities and update this post as I come across any.

Comment: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-the-last-git-commit) also?

Comment: @BartoszKP: probably not the exact same situation but this one can be related.

Comment: @BartoszKP yeah, I left that one alone because it deals with undoing just the very last commit, which is a special case of undoing any commit...so maybe you could argue it's a duplicate? I'm not sure. You can go ahead and close it if you really feel that it's a duplicate, I don't really care either way.

Comment: @Cupcake The answers look almost the same. I guess "merge" would ideal in this case :) I voted for closure though, I think no essential information would've been lost if only the canonical would existed (sorry for probably broken tense-grammar ;v).

Comment: With the number of votes on that post,  it is highly unlikely that any other mod would want to close it or even merge it into other post.  At the most,  all other similar questions can be linked to this one.