# Where did the use of the name Mjolnir come from?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

Often The Dupe Hammer, aka The Mighty Mjolnir is talked about.

Obviously this is named after [Thor's hammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir) in Norse mythology.

But when did the name start being used in StackMythology and why?

Comment: Because we couldn't take "The Waffle Hammer" seriously.

Comment: [I executed a query for MSO](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/217383/posts-containing-mjolnir) and based on that, it's [oldest usage is in this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/2982225)

Answer (score 10):

First wide public use at Meta Stack Exchange was in May 8, 2014 announcement in [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/165773):

> we're going to be rolling out a change that gives you more power when it comes to handling duplicates, a chronic source of pain...
>
> ...if a question goes through two iterations of being opened and closed where this new **'Thor's Hammer'** was used, moderators will get a flag alerting them to a contested duplicate...

For the sake of completeness, this announcement also refers "PHP 'hammer":

> To show my commitment to this, here's **my** version of the now famous PHP '[hammer](https://www.flickr.com/photos/raindrift/sets/72157629492908038)':
>
> [image: php-duplicate-hammer]

Comment: Is there a way to gain enough reputation for a tag to delete incorrect answers for that tag?

Comment: I wonder who first used the proper name for it.

Comment: @DanDascalescu No, thank goodness. Shog9 has written before that that's not how the site should work; users should get credit for good faith contributions. If you see an incorrect answer, downvote and/or comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would venture to guess that it comes from internet moderator lingo such as "the Ban Hammer", which usually refers to when a moderator uses his mod powers to ban a misbehaving user from a site:

[image: Screenshot]

<sub>From [Want To Play Halo 4 Early? Prepare To Meet Microsoft’s Banhammer](http://www.ripten.com/2012/10/15/want-to-play-halo-4-early-prepare-to-meet-microsofts-banhammer/).</sub>

In the context of Stack Exchange, moderators do much more than just ban users, they also heavily moderate content quality, such as closing duplicate questions, with only 1 binding close vote (vs the usual 5 close votes required from non-mod users).

Because moderators wield such unilateral powers, it's fitting to refer to the act of closing a duplicate "with one mighty blow" as an instance of using "the Dupe Hammer", Mjolnir, etc.

#### See Also

- [Banhammer — Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banhammer)
- [Banhammer — Know Your Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/banhammer)