# Is it possible to know who single-handedly reopened a question?

Tags: support, dupehammer, vote-to-reopen, revision-history, timeline

When closing a question (using [Mjölnir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268608) or not), you get to know who closed it; this information is displayed in a notice below the question.

Now when the question is reopened by five people, it is not an issue *not* to know who reopened it. Five people are very unlikely to be wrong, especially on reopen votes (which are even more rare than close votes).

**But** when a user uses the dupe hammer to reopen a question without leaving any comment, how do I know who reopened it? Should I flag the post for moderator attention (seems a little overkill)?

<sub>This question was triggered by [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48110641) (post deleted, 10k+ reputation only), which is clearly abuse (I saw a lot of other examples). Thanks to the answer, I found that the guy who answered the question was the one who reopened it, without leaving any comment. (A classic. Sad, though.)</sub>

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Is there a way to see who reopened a question and who had previously closed it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131353/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel this comment would fit well in your answer now that it exists.

Comment: How did you know that only one user reopened it and not five users if you didn't know who reopened it?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Perhaps the speed with which it was reopened. And I guess OP already suspected that the new answer was provided by the re-opening user - but was looking for proof.

Comment: Did...did the gold badger 1. reopen the question, 2. answer it, 3. cast the last delvote on the question?

Comment: @AndrasDeak yes, that's what happened. Weird right? I suppose that he _knew_ that if _he_ didn't delete, someone else would have. Not even needed to call SOCVR on that one! too bad for him (and the other answerer): hadn't he reopened, all this fuss would have been avoided and everyone would have kept his rep.

Comment: "Five people cannot be wrong, especially on reopen votes" You must be new here

Comment: everyone can be wrong, but reopening is so rare, so if 5 people agree to it, then it must be ok, that's what I meant.

Comment: And yes, i'm rather new. Less than 2 years. But I'm a quick learner... and 2018 SO cannot be compared with 2008 SO.

Answer (score 34):

Yes, you can find who re-opened a question in the revision history of the question:

[`https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<questionId>/revisions`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48110641/revisions)

I use a userscript called "SEModifications" ([github](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/)) to automatically add a link to the history (and timeline) in a question's footer:

> [image]

These links aren't available normally (a history link is only shown when a question has edits), but their pages always work.

Comment: You can also get to that page by clicking the “edited X ago” link next to the OP’s user card, if the post has been edited.

Comment: @JF yes, I knew that part, but in my case, the post hadn't been edited.

Answer (score 27):

You can either use the revision history of the question, as mentioned by Cerbrus, or use the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36303/295232): [https://stackoverflow.com/posts/**<POST ID>**/timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48110641/timeline)

[image]

Comment: Also: very professional of you to hide the guy who reopened. That won't prevent others to navigate and see the name though :)

Comment: I know it won't help much, but I felt I had to do it.

Comment: very professional was not ironic. I mean it.

Comment: And it is only available to under-10k users anyway so the majority of people can't see it on the original post.  +1

Comment: @dalearn thank you, now that the question is deleted it's really effective. It was still alive at the moment this answer was posted.

Comment: when you say "alive" you meant "wild" right?