# Am I justified to answer a question which I have closed as a duplicate earlier but was reopened later by another gold badge holder?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed, dupehammer

Am I justified to answer a question which I have dup-hammered earlier as a duplicate to a discussion bearing a bounty, but was reopened later by another gold badge holder?

This question have a reference to the question [Download box is popping up after setting download.manager.showWhenStarting to 'False' and selecting correct MIME type while downloading .xls file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860004/download-box-is-popping-up-after-setting-download-manager-showwhenstarting-to-f) which I have closed as a duplicate to [Python: Unable to download with selenium in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072022/python-unable-to-download-with-selenium-in-webpage) which had a bounty.

Now, the current question being reopened again by another gold badge holder am I justified to answer the question?

Comment: Do you still believe the question is a dupe? Will your answer apply both to the question at hand and to the dupe target?

Comment: @yivi Just like the way I answer a question after the much needed research and effort I follow the same principle while dupe-hammering. Inshort, the answer is **Yes**.

Comment: Anybody is justified to use SO **sensibly*.*  Repeating an answer makes no sense whatsoever.  The link to the dup got lost when it was re-opened, the sensible thing to do is add a comment to the question that links to the previous question.

Comment: Is it *sufficiently* obvious from the duplicate that the problem is that the correct mime type has not been included? (If that is the problem - I know nothing of Selenium.)

Comment: Honestly, [the dupe you selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072022/python-unable-to-download-with-selenium-in-webpage) seems like a pretty poor choice, given that the OP's code there apparently has multiple issues and the answers are basically code-reviewing it. A good dupe target generally (one major exception being exact dupes posted by the same user) asks a single clear question and has a clear and definitive answer. If a user finding the question via the dupe link has to sift through a bunch of unrelated distractions to (maybe) find their answer, it's not really a good dupe.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Specifying the correct mime type was possibly one of the issue which was causing popup to surface. Apart from that there were certain _preferences_ which could have optimized the automatic downloading process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could ask why the user reopened, unless you figured it out yourself.

If the user reopened just to answer the question, and it's still a blatant dupe, then it's clearly abuse (I already stumbled on that once at least: [Is it possible to know who single-handedly reopened a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361469/is-it-possible-to-know-who-single-handedly-reopened-a-question), also handy if you don't know who reopened the question), so comment / downvote accordingly or get help from meta or chatrooms to get it closed again.

If you realize that it's not a duplicate after all, then it's perfectly okay for you to answer. Gold badge owners sometimes get so obsessed by closing questions as fast as possible to avoid answers to duplicates that they sometimes choose the wrong duplicate or see duplicates where there isn't one. It happens (well, happened to *me*). No sweat.

BTW I've done "worse": closed as duplicate, got comments "it's not a duplicate", agreed, then reopened and answered.

Comment: As I side note for dupe hammer reopeners: please ask why a question was closed as dup or if there is a better one instead of instantly reopening. In that case, you can simply edit the list of duplicates instead of having to find 5 new users to vote to close as another duplicate.

Comment: good point. That's not the main point here, but yes. I have created a meta Q&A some time ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355666/what-should-i-do-as-a-gold-badge-holder-if-i-feel-the-duplicate-target-isnt-the

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre By now I also have reopened a couple of questions which I had marked as duplicate earlier. But when OP edited the question with finer details to make the question unique I have reopened them immediately. But in this case neither OP came back nor the other gold badger asked for any clarification.

Comment: And it was the right thing to do. The problem with just reopening is that it doesn't notify the OP IIRC. And it doesn't give a chance for reviewers in the reopen queue to see it... You can post a comment to notify them.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your closing it as a dupe was an incorrect action and with a second look you can now see your previous error in judgement, then it's not a dupe so answering is perfectly legit
2. If you believe it being re-opened was an incorrect action then it's still a dupe, so you shouldn't answer it should be closed.

There's now a debate between dupe hammerers, one says it is and the other says  it isn't. One of you has missed something in it being or not being a duplicate of something else.

If you still feel it's a duplicate then given you've already voted it'll have to be a comment, hopefully someone else will vote to close and it can be debated amongst more users this time.

Comment: I thought you could not chose to "vote to close" instead of dup-hammering?

Comment: That doesn't work. You can't vote to close twice, and hammering counts.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Did not know that, thanks. I have edited thanks (although it entirely dilutes/deflates my answer, but never mind)