# Is there a way to know who voted to close my questions?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, users

I want to know who voted to close my questions.

My two old questions were voted to close yesterday. I think there is a stalker who voted to close all my questions.

Comment: Don't you get a notice on the question with that information? In either case, you can click the clock looking icon on the left to see the timeline.

Comment: @KevinB The notice doesn't show _who_ voted to close _to post owners_ (even if you have the 3k privilege).

Comment: @OP Although it is available in the timeline as Kevin indicated, why do you think you need that information?

Comment: They should change the order of the text on the notice so that, *"Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege"*, is above the list of close voters. Right now it reads as if the OP can see everything in the notice.

Comment: If you want to ask them why they closed the question, note that you cannot ping them (the only time you can is if it was a dupe hammer closure). If you disagree with a closure, raise it on meta (which you have done). Don't retalitate against the close voters.

Comment: Yep, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67881673/timeline. May I ask what you are planning to do with that info? I believe it is deprecated to [pay users a house visit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/158100) so what others option had you in mind?

Comment: My two old questions were voted to close yesterday. I think there is a stalker who vote to close all my questions.

Comment: I don't know why this natural question got so many downvotes. Don't you want to know who voted to close your question?

Comment: @PONPON I haven't voted yet, but your question probably received downvotes because this information is already given in the Help Center and other Meta questions (so it is not likely that you searched very hard, or at all, for it), because you didn't include any information about which questions you are referring to, and because you have issued an unlikely claim (someone is stalking me) without giving any evidence whatsoever to back up the claim.

Comment: There was only one person who vtc both your questions, they almost certainly just clicked on your profile and looked through your questions and happened to find one they wanted to vote on. That person is a gold badge holder in Azure so they probably know a good question from a bad one.

Comment: @PONPON Actions on Stack Overflow are not personal; separate content from author in order to have a good experience. Information on who closed your questions is hidden by default *for the exact reason* that you have asked here: to prevent witch hunts and targeted retaliation.

Comment: @TylerH *"this information is already given in the Help Center and other Meta questions (so it is not likely that you searched very hard, or at all, for it)"* - You say that, I'm having an awful lot of trouble finding a dupe :p, a combination of: [Is it possible to know who single-handedly reopened a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361469/) and [Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340703) is the best I could come up with

Comment: @KevinB [the post author is not shown who closed their post in the notice](https://i.imgur.com/WPZTr7i.png). That holds true [even if they closed it themselves](https://i.imgur.com/WSUbP1J.png)

Comment: @PONPON - A single user cannot close a question unless they have a gold badge in a tag you used.  It doesn’t sound like you want to have this information for a positive reason. “I don't know why this natural question got so many downvotes.” - Unfortunately, based on your own words, you are giving the impression you want to retaliate against the user who voted to close your questions

Comment: @TylerH can you link where in help center is this information given? Couldn't find it.

Comment: @Warcupine: Isn't that against the rules though? The old saying was "vote on content, not on users".

Comment: It's not against the rules, per say, @user000001 , but it is strongly discouraged. However, how Warcupine "knows" the user clicked the OP's profile and voted to close both questions is beyond me; I assume they have access to some of the statistics on SO that many of us don't.

Comment: @Larnu Warcupine said "almost certainly" which indicates a guess, not a statement of fact.

Comment: @eis It looks like it isn't in the Help Center topics after all. I thought it was supposed to be added when they made all those changes to the close reasons and banners.

Comment: I would suggest that still means that they have a strong indication that it happened, @TylerH , meaning that have access to information we don't. Or it's pure conjecture, and thus "almost certainly" isn't true at all; it's a guess.

Comment: @Larnu It's *almost certainly* the latter.

Comment: Then Warcupine  can't be "almost certain", @TylerH . A guess is a guess; it's not an indication of certainty.

Comment: @Larnu Perhaps you missed the cue from my added emphasis in my usage. It's fairly common to hear someone unscientifically *guess* (albeit, often based on deliberation and examination of evidence) by saying "almost certainly [...]" in informal conversation. They do not mean the scientific measurement of certainty.

Comment: No, I saw it, and why I state again, **guessing** isn't *certainty*... Of this I am **certain** @TylerH, I am not *guessing*. If Warcupine was *almost certain* that the downvoter was the same, they must have *something* to suggest so (for example, seeing the IP for the 2 downvotes were the same, which could suggest the same person, but doesn't confirm as people can have the same IP address). If not, then there is no certainty...

Comment: @Larnu then you just don't understand that there are multiple uses of the same terminology depending on context.

Comment: Or you don't understand that guesses and certainty are different things, @TylerH ? Clearly we aren't going to accept the other's definition.. But I won't be, personally, changing my mind that they are effectively opposites.

Comment: I don't have special access but know that someone looked my profile and chose questions to close. There are several such people. After I posted this question, three old questions were closed.

Comment: @PONPON That's just the meta effect: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect

Comment: Were they closed incorrectly, or correctly?

Comment: @KevinB Almost all of their closes are incorrect. You can see that this question has been incorrectly closed twice and reopened twice. I think they don't think about correctness of close reason.

Comment: @larnu we aren’t talking about downvotes, I can see who voted to close a question. This person who vtc a recent question also vtc an older question. Seems likely they found it through the profile. I cannot be certain but I can be fairly certain. I’m not accusing them of voting out of line they didn’t vtc everything just the two question as far as I can tell.

Comment: I can see why people would vote to close this question @PONPON . The title is on topic, the the contents is a different matter. To me it doesn't read like you want to know the answer so you can reach out to them in the comments of the questions, but to be able to retaliate yourself. I haven't voted to close, as I hope it's just poor wording and youre the bigger person, but it does have that vibe. Wording the question more constructively would far more likely have avoided the VTCs.

Comment: Who voted to close this question isn't interesting or important. Were your Stack Overflow questions incorrectly closed? You seem to be confusing these two distinct questions. It would not be out of the ordinary for someone who voted to close one of your questions to check your profile and review some other recent questions of yours if they got the impression that you are not familiar with the sites rules.

Comment: @tripleee I just proved that there are many people to vote to close incorrectly. If you  check my profile, you can see other examples.

Comment: I don't think anybody here needs more proof that questions are occasionally closed incorrectly. Reading between the lines a bit, I think we can conclude that you are not trying to claim that this is what happened to your Stack Overflow questions then.

Comment: I did look through your recently closed questions before I asked that, and found that I personally agree with most of the closures. I don't agree with going through someone's profile and casting close votes, but, if the closes were valid, there's nothing to contest. If you disagree with a particular one, ask a question about it specifically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can see the close voters of a question in the question's timeline. This is accessible from the clock icon on the left side, under the voting buttons.

See screenshots below:

[image]

[image: The list of close voters will be in the row that has 'Closed' in its 'what' column.]

I've used [red freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775) in the above images to highlight the information you want.

Comment: I changed "need" to "want", since I don't feel this information is "needed" particularly, though being curious about that information is fine. It's just my opinion, so feel free to revert that wording if you prefer it.

Comment: This answer could be improved by noting the reasons why the names of close voters are hidden by default, and drawing that out to hint very strongly why the asker doesn’t, in fact, need this information. The answer should further point to better options, like editing the question to get it reopened. And, finally, it should be mentioned that, if you suspect someone is targeting you (or any other pattern of abuse), you should raise a flag for moderator intervention so that we can investigate.