# What "details or clarity" are needed in this case?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, close-reasons, meta

I think the meaning of this question is clear:

[Is there a way to know who voted to close my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408450/13087034)

It asks if there is a function on Stack Overflow to do this, or not. I don't know what "details" the users who voted to close it need to answer this clear question.

Comment: IMO it's a bad closure, it's blatantly obvious what you're asking: How to check who closed a question (the _exact_ question isn't relevant to the post so that couldn't be the supposedly missing details). That said I don't think the post is worth reopening

Comment: @Nick Doesn't this site reopen incorrect closures? The rules aren't working.

Comment: The site is run by a community of volunteers, none of which are under any _obligation_ to open or close particular questions. You've done your part and posted a meta question asking what details you were missing, wait for the community to do their part, some will vote to reopen, others won't, you only need 5 reopen votes to get the post reopened.

Comment: FWIW I voted to close it as does not seek input and discussion. Knowing the names of the close voters is not constructive, why would you need to know that? It's mostly hidden from you on purpose. Asking about how to get the question reopened would be constructive.

Comment: The edit makes things a little clearer and literally changes the tone and the purpose of the question. You really need to take care how you phrase questions; people can only judge what you provide, they can't judge what you keep to yourself.

Comment: Oh, cool. We're going to close this one for the same reasons? Come on, folks. You're self-satirizing...

Comment: **ALWAYS edit the question** and **NEVER post a new one**. If you post a new one you are vulnerable to downvotes for deleting a question and or for posting a duplicate question. I tried posting a new one and ended up with 4 downvotes in the process.

Comment: I suspect the q-ban algorithm has a good memory because some of the downvoted questions (which were deleted) that likely contributied to my q-ban are from 9 years back.  Although to be fair I haven't added many questions since then.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know why that question was closed as Needing Details or Clarity. Your question is completely clear, and requires no further details to be answerable. It's also definitely about a functionality of the site. A brief search also doesn't show a reasonable duplicate. I've voted to reopen it.

I can't speak for the users who used the Needs Details or Clarity close reason (which was at least 3 of them), but it's possible that they wanted clarity on *why* you want this information. This is not unreasonable, since unlike the main site, your intent does matter to some extent on Meta. Still, assuming good faith, you could just be curious about how to find that information, and that's perfectly fine.

It's also possible that the close votes were cast because they found the question uninteresting, or because there is no indication that you've done any research yourself, such as reading the help pages, or related Meta posts. These are just reasons to downvote however, and not a reason to close. I do agree with at least the second point though, so I will probably downvote at the same time as I cast a reopen vote.

Comment: FWIW I voted to close it as does not seek input and discussion. Knowing the names of the close voters is not constructive. Asking about how to get the question reopened would be constructive.

Comment: The user who  asked and 3 k users can see who closed it. We don't understand which question he refers to so it was closed for clsrity

Comment: @nbk the OP obviously didn't know that the post owner and >3k users can see those names, otherwise the question wouldn't have been asked. Which question they refer to is irrelevant, since the question is about the general case (which happens to be exactly equal, as per the rules you just mentioned)

Comment: yes, but here was asked why the close votes, as i voted ti close it, because it waws unclear, what question he was talking about, it is unclear and so closed correctly. If he asked this question and why can't i see who closed it, ok simple answer for that

Comment: @RobertLongson That's true, the question is not seeking input and discussion, but it's more a [support] question, i.e. how to get some specific information about something on the main site. I agree that knowing the identities of close voters is not generally useful, or relevant to the OP, but I don't see anything wrong with the question being asked.

Comment: What cigien says is truth. So is what @Robert says, of course, but that should have been posted as *an answer* to the question about how to see the names of the close voters.