# Which privilege is required to close a question as duplicate by yourself?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, privileges

Some questions are marked as duplicate after votes of 5 different people. Sometimes I see a question is marked as duplicate (and closed) by only one person. Which privilege level does one need to do this?

I looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges, but did not find the answer there.

Comment: Those users will have a [gold tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) badge

Comment: Also, [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/298072)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No particular privilege applies here.

This is an ability that a person who has earned a gold tag badge in a tag that the question has been tagged with has.

Also known as the dupe hammer:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/1583

Comment: _"Also known as __Mjölnir__"*_