# JavaScript tag - low quality questions overflow?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, duplicate-questions, low-quality-posts

I'm getting more and more involved in Stack Overflow, and the fact is I only know a few languages (C#, C, CUDA, LLVM IR, and... JavaScript) well.

As such, I try to answer and moderate questions in those tags. While most of them are pretty well maintained, leaving only a low quality questions, the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag appears to me as the language is: unchecked and unsafe.

It looks to me that people there are less experienced, and tend more to quickly answer, because it's fun to write code, even on duplicates and (very) low quality questions.

This is an understandable behavior, but maybe experienced reviewers tend to skip more JavaScript questions the way I tend to skip assembly questions, because I don't know anything about it and think it's boring anyway.

Maybe there is just too many questions asked, and not enough people to flag all the duplicates / low quality.

Many times, the questions are about:

- Undefined objects on which a user tries to invoke a function, such as [.hasClass not working inside a onclick function but remove and add class functions do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067004/hasclass-not-working-inside-a-onclick-function-but-remove-and-add-class-functio)
- Messing around with promises and asynchronous behaviors, such as [Return value from an async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066266/return-value-from-an-async-function)
- Just big bunches of code posting with: *I get an error*, which should be flagged as MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
- or just a "do my work" request which generates many answers (because it's easy) such as this wonderful example: [How to multiple (a*b) two input text value and show it Dynamicly with text change in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114583/how-to-multiple-ab-two-input-text-value-and-show-it-dynamicly-with-text-chang?noredirect=1#comment61770561_37114583)
  I'm just wondering what could be done against that...

Comment: As a sub 3k user, you can still downvote bad posts. You can also leave a comment with a link to duplicates to make it easier for the question to be closed.

Comment: indeed, and flag as much as I can, but I feel doing that 10 times for one "answerable" question

Comment: actually most questions could be answered by "use a debugger first", which would dramatically reduce the flow of questions

Comment: That is absolutely not limited to JavaScript...

Comment: Downvote, vote to close, vote to delete. Do the ones you can, and move on to better questions.  Don't burn yourself out on crap.

Comment: We could put a BIG welcome message on the site that says:  Welcome to Stackoverflow, the Q&A forum where everyone is a moderator.  Think your javascript question is good?  That's cause you're dumb.

Comment: I'm active in JS tag and lots of times I hope I had a "lacks MCVE" hammer. Without usually actively looking for duplicates, I'm the 34th user with most dupe hammer closes the past 365 days. Lots of users in [the top list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315158/1529630) are also active in the tag, that's probably the reason.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think describing the JavaScript tag as a mess is accurate. It is just very active. As a result, some of the attributes of scale start to show up including duplication.

I am fairly familiar with the tag, I have a gold badge for it, as well as jQuery (because, well, needs more..). This is not a new phenomenon, as the core of the issue is

- Users not considering or not caring to search for their issue
- Users wanting a quick fix

These issues are constantly addressed one way or another with new features or community outlook and are certainly not localized to the JavaScript tag. I think the overall behavior you are seeing fits into a broader problem - one which has existed for a long time.

There is even a "SE-quality-project" whose sole purpose is to increase post quality through control metrics or features.

tl;dr; This is a broader issue, and not localized to one tag. A more constructive conversation would be to look at solutions to these types of "symptoms" if you will.

Comment: Agreed. I have the feeling it's even too active... Maybe there is not enough reviewers?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a correlation between the quantity of reviewers in a specific tag and post quality in that tag to be honest, that would be an interesting angle to address.

Comment: edited the question to highlight that

Comment: there are probably metrics somewhere about that

Comment: I'd add a third list-item: _"users looking for quick rep enabling users in categories 1 & 2"_

Comment: @canon - I think that is tangential, because that facet is on the answerer spectrum. Also, to be honest, the whole [Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) issue has also been discussed to death and I don't really feel like reiterating the history of that here. This answer is specifically addressing the claim that the JavaScript tag itself drives low quality questions.

Answer (score 6):

This does not sound as a problem unique to JavaScript. Your list of "*too* frequently asked questions" can be applied to the majority of language tags.

Example: Only very recently I subscribed to the Python tag, as it is an interesting language and I wanted to learn it. As I know, SO is not a good resource for teaching so I started out with the official documentation - which is extensive and exhaustive, and contains *lots* of examples, how-tos, and possible problem cases.

Imagine my surprise to find out that, first, I was quickly able to downvote and/or close-vote a serious amount of questions due to *lack of research*, second, close as *duplicate* because a casual search for the issue at hand popped up 10 existing answers on SO alone, and third, downvote and/or close-vote for *lack of basic understanding* (not a real close reason anymore, but applicable in the case of simple typos and basic misunderstanding of how syntax, logic, maths, file systems, or Computers In General work).

What causes such an influx of bad questions for JavaScript? Because the Stack Overflow Survey 2016 lists JavaScript as *the* language of choice, for the up and coming year:

#1 in Most Used: https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#technology
#5 in Most Wanted: https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted

It's the badwagon everyone wants to join, and hey, why spend any effort on learning it properly when you can just ask "fix my code plz".

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers do a good job of explaining *why* you are seeing this happening: JavaScript is the biggest tag, and there are a lot of people who just jump right in without any experience. (And yes, I also hear that other tags, such as [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) have this problem too.)

But I want to propose a solution to combat this. I think that we could use more canonicals to close against. And maybe it will stop some questions from even being asked, too (not that anyone's getting their hopes up for this).

There's this one error that I keep on seeing questions about: "cannot read property ______ of ________". I think I could do a bit of research and produce a question answer pair that would be helpful, and a good candidate for closing dupes against. I don't have much JavaScript experience, but neither do the users asking generally about the error. I think that my perspective would be valuable because my experience level is close to theirs. (As a bonus, I will gain some JS experience, too.)

There's clearly a lot of people who ask about this error, because I don't even follow [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). There's currently no one good question about the error to close duplicates against, anyway.

Comment: With regards to your canonical suggestion, a very large amount of questions that get asked in JavaScript are essentially the result of users not understanding asynchronous process when using AJAX. There is an epic canonical for that by Felix Kling, and it is used to close duplicates on a daily (hourly?) basis. However, even with that coverage the questions themselves are still asked. I like the idea of posting this as a solution because solutions are always welcome - but I do think we have canonical coverage and I just don't see that necessarily hampering the *creation* of these questions.

Comment: @TravisJ Well, I did say that nobody's getting their hopes up. I looked at all of Felix's questions, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959) seems similar to the error I was thinking of doing a canonical for. It doesn't have the exact wording I was searching for, so I'm not sure if it is the same as the error I was thinking about.

Comment: As long as the content quality is high, canonicals are always an option to create; although it is hard to make a good one. With regards to the specific issue of "cannot read property of undefined" this seems to be the canonical of choice for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property I could post a separate answer or you could request from someone else that a more in depth answer be provided, but in general I do not think that users get hung up on trying to access an undefined variable for very long - it tends to be an XY problem.

Comment: @TravisJ That post provides *preventative* measures (and it doesn't even mention the error, which is the most that most people have anyway). To clarify - I think we need a post that **actually mentions the error**, and gives some reasons it might be happening (with a link to that post for future preventative measures). When you don't know a language, you're not going to have the insight to go beyond what the messages are telling you.

Comment: If you wish to create a canonical post for that and want an answer let me know. Otherwise, not sure what else to say :)

Comment: @TravisJ I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something obvious, like an existing canonical. If I do decide to start writing something like that, I'll let you know.