# How do I give up the mighty Mjölnir?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

I have the dupe hammer privilege and I don't want it. I don't want it because I prefer the democratic processes set up by the site to gather consensus. And there are [too many mistakes made with it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315158/608639) and there are [no checks and balances or auditing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315155).

How do I opt out of the privilege?

Comment: In my experience, simply leaving a comment with a possible duplicate is enough to get people to close vote it. Yeah, you lose out on your vote, but it's as close as you're going to get, really. If you are not confident enough to dupe hammer it, are you sure you are confident to leave a close vote? You shouldn't leave close votes that might be wrong simply because you hope others won't follow suit in that event you did make a mistake.

Comment: @Rob - its not really about me being *"confident to leave a close vote"*. The Mjölnir Hammer does not affect that decision. Its about consensus and avoiding unchecked mistakes.

Comment: Just because you can't downvote a closure (whether dupe hammered or not) doesn't mean there are no checks and balances. People can still comment and/or vote to reopen if they disagree and the OP can still edit to clarify how they think their question differs. The stats aren't much use either, maybe the dupe hammer reopens seem higher because those who wield it can also reopen on their own and are, as high rep users who want the site to work well, more likely to go back and revise when the question is edited.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - its not really about me being able to *"downvote a closure"*. The Mjölnir Hammer does not affect it. Its about consensus and avoiding unchecked mistakes. Also, your claim about the check and balances is tenuous at best. If a regular Stack Overflow user made as many mistakes as hammer wielders, they would get banned. Hammer wielders don't suffer any consequences, as if they somehow don't make mistakes or their mistakes are less sensitive.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the premise that *too many mistakes [are] made with it*. Even the post you linked to justifying this says the opposite quite clearly: ***You'll note that the most avid user of the hammer (by a wide margin!) has an error rate comparable to that of normal voters.***

Comment: @Tunaki - this question simply asks how I can opt-out of the privilege. If you want to debate whether 5% or 10% and 20% or 25% failure rate is acceptable, then you should probably open another discussion.

Comment: I am questioning your use of words: you explicitely say *And there are too many mistakes made with it and there are no checks and balances or auditing.*. If the question isn't about that, you could remove it since it is not relevant.

Comment: @Tunaki - right; I don't want to be part of the statistic pool of mistakes. Can you make the edit that suits your taste? (By the way, as soon as I remove it, then folks will ask why I would want to do it. Its the reason I try to provide a brief explanation for the action).

Comment: Right so it _is_ relevant. I am merely commenting on the question about the links and assertion you make (which kind of contradict themselves), not starting wars...

Comment: @Tunaki - change it to whatever you'd like or whatever makes your heart content.

Answer (score 30):

[As I wrote elsewhere:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231504/how-do-i-opt-out-of-privileges)

> We've no plans to make "opting out" an option. This is in keeping with existing behavior: once you gain the ability to vote to close, you can no longer *flag* for closing. The system trusts you more, and there's no way to tell it to trust you less.
>
> To be perfectly frank, I've never liked the attitude toward closing that [turning it into a voting system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/i-move-to-close-this-question/) brought with it: too many people vote without much thought, expecting other voters to keep their carelessness in check. If that *doesn't* apply to you (and I don't think it does) then you're exactly the sort of person we'd all appreciate having a bit more say in what gets closed.
>
> And if you *do* make a mistake, you have the ability to immediately re-open the same question you immediately closed. Reopen votes on duplicates are binding for badge holders in the relevant tags as well.

Don't make the mistake of treating normal close votes as somehow impervious to abuse or error, and *especially* don't think that 5 votes on a site with millions of users is a much better sample than one vote. Questions get closed that shouldn't be all the time, while scores remain open with one or two votes that would be better off removed. Use your privileges wisely, whether they take immediate action or otherwise.