# Opt out the dupe hammer via flagging a post

Tags: feature-request, flags, close-reasons, dupehammer

Sometimes it's not really appropriate to close a question using my dupe hammer, but I just want to make a proposal as it would have been done by a regular user choosing the flag menu.

When I'm choosing the flag menu, this is what's actually presented to me:

[image]

If I choose any of these, the question is immediately closed. It goes the same way as if I had chosen the close vote option

[image]

I'd like to have an option, to just use my dupe hammer, or make a proposal (the latter might be implemented via using flags).

There are (edge) cases, where I'm still unsure if the dupe actually matches the question, but if I'm going to add the dupe proposal manually, it doesn't carry any weight (close vote or flagging point), or push that question to a review queue. Also I'd like to see some backup from peers to confirm that the question matches the duplicate answers.

---

So my request is:

Let dupe hammer holders decide to

- either propose a duplicate
- or actually mark (and close) a question as being one

The decision could be made by distinguishing the choice of the *close* or *flagging* path.

---

This older [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231504/how-do-i-opt-out-of-privileges/276050#276050) is apparently related here.

---

You should notice that I'm not asking about the judgement or semantical level, but just for a technical feature that gives me the choice which path the question should go in review.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm doing so, no problem. There are edge cases when I want to have backup from other users though. And composing the _possible duplicate_ link by hand is just tedious, that's all of my point (not so much semantical, but a pure technical matter).

Comment: The _possible duplicate_ is an interesting idea. Maybe something like `[mcve]`.

Comment: I expect this to get slapped with a status-declined [How does one relinquish his/her right to close questions without review?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3231) BTW, check the comments on the question, it has many related posts.

Comment: @Braiam I don't get on the spot how this is actually related, other than shog9 was involved? Though he's quite respectable and reputable, he's well known to make unpopular answers like that one.

Comment: "I'd like to have an option, to just use my dupe hammer, or make a proposal" basically to have a flip whenever or not you want to use the hammer. The next phrase strengthen this "There are (edge) cases, **where I'm still unsure if the dupe actually matches the question**" both are addressed in Shog's answer

Comment: @Braiam I think I've explained my concerns well enough, and I'm pretty sure I'm not the only user holding a dupe hammer, who's bothering with this.

Comment: Also: [Allow user to choose between an ordinary close vote and the mighty Mjölnir](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255064) A possible workaround would be to edit the tags, vote quickly, then re-edit. I think that would work, and would be similar to editing to undo a up/down vote, although I'm not sure I'd actually encourage it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell clipboard flipped on you, you pasted the same link twice.

Comment: @JoshCaswell While coming from the same background seemingly, your proposed dupe doesn't make any concrete proposals how that should be realized. I think I gave some of these.

Comment: Thanks, @Braiam. The second link was meant to be [How do I give up the mighty mjölnir?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323155)

Comment: If you're not sure, then... Just post a comment. "Hey, I think this might answer your question: ..." If you're right, you can always come back and close; if you're not, no harm done.

Comment: @Shog9 I mentioned in my question, why a comment doesn't really have the same impact.

Comment: A comment doesn't put the proposal in front of 5 unknown people, sure. But, it does put it in front of at least one person who has a vested interest in the question, which counts for a lot. If you need more than that, well... You have it.