# With a gold tag badge can I still just *vote* for 'closed, duplicate'?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, dupehammer

More often than not all I want to do is *vote* for duplicate rather than close as a knee-jerk reaction, and occasionally I forget that my vote is no longer a vote but a 'hard no'.

Would it be possible to have the option to cast a vote like normal *or* summarily close as a duplicate?

Comment: Casting a normal vote is even more useful now that the asker is now prompted to approve the duplication or edit their question.  If it's closed, it didn't require four other close voters, and if it's edited, the gold-badger doesn't have to reopen.

Comment: Also: [How do I give up Mjölnir?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323155/how-do-i-give-up-the-mighty-mjölnir)

Comment: aww man, why you guys gotta be foisting all this *responsibility* on me? :( [also, I dig these Mjölnir references]

Comment: The point is that the responsibility *has not changed*. You were responsible for your close votes before, and you're responsible for them now. If you aren't sure that something is a duplicate, don't vote to close it. Simple. Maybe leave a comment, instead, so someone else who is sure can pick up where you left off.