# "Nominate this question for reopening?" message misleading

Tags: bug, dupehammer, vote-to-reopen

When I try to reopen a duplicate question where I can use my dupe hammer, I still get the same message:

> Nominate this question for reopening?

The word "nominate" here suggests that the question will become a "candidate" for reopening and so will be voted on. But because of my dupe hammer, I will actually reopen the question, instead of letting people vote on it.

This misled me the first time I saw it. I think it can be changed to

> Reopen this question?

Or as anatolyg suggested in the comments, this message can be changed to:

> Reopen this question? Votes by other users may be required.

for all users.

---

Note that this question is not about [opting out of the dupe hammer when reopening a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323155/how-do-i-give-up-the-mighty-mj%C3%B6lnir). It is about correcting a piece of misleading text.

Comment: [feature-request] questions that ask for an expensive dbase query never have much luck.  You are almost surely much better off tagging this with [bug].  This change is most likely part of the [welcoming] hacks that nobody asked for.  It achieves the exact opposite of that intention, given that you might reconsider.  Surely they always prefer you opening the question.

Comment: the same problem exists with voting to close, i dont see a reason for this.

Comment: The wording can be the same for all users. "Reopen this question? Votes by other users may be required"

Comment: @anatolyg Oh that's a good idea! Will edit.

Answer (score -4):

Well you *are* nominating it. It just so happens that your nomination causes an automatic acceptance of the proposal, just as if you had the final/binding non-hammer vote. To be honest I think it's fine the way it is and if you're voting differently depending on whether or not your vote is binding then you're voting wrong.

Comment: Yes I understand that if I vote depending on whether it is binding, I'm voting wrong, but the behaviour still surprised me.

Comment: I nominate myself for going to the pub. And, since there is nobody here to stop me, that's all that's needed _and_ it was still a correct statement! Cya later!