# When a post is flagged with more than one label, what label wins?

Tags: discussion, flags

Last week, a question was flagged as duplicate.

The OP asked one of the people commenting to post a link to the older question. The person posting comments said he did not flag the question as a "duplicate," but rather as "too broad."

So when multiple flags are thrown, what is the process to decide which one wins, (ie, is publicly posted)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's either the user with the [mighty mjölnir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers/254590#254590) who wins, or the majority of the (5) close voters selecting a particular close reason.

Comment: And ties (in cases of 2 vs 2 vs 1, or 5 different votes) are broken by which one was used first

Comment: @psubsee2003 Fair point.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.