# Can this paper be beneficial in dealing with duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I've come across [this paper](http://papers.www2017.com.au.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/proceedings/p1221.pdf) from about a month ago titled *Detecting Duplicate Posts in Programming QA Communities via Latent Semantics and Association Rules*. It features Stack Overflow as one of its test subjects and claims to have improved the way to find duplicate Q&A.

From its abstract:

> Programming community-based question-answering (PCQA) websites such as Stack Overflow enable programmers to find working solutions to their questions. Despite detailed posting guidelines, duplicate questions that have been answered are frequently created. To tackle this problem, Stack Overflow provides a mechanism for reputable users to manually mark duplicate questions. This is a laborious effort, and leads to many duplicate questions remain undetected. Existing duplicate detection methodologies from traditional community based question-answering (CQA) websites are difficult to be adopted directly to PCQA, as PCQA posts often contain source code which is linguistically very different from natural languages. In this paper, we propose a methodology designed for the PCQA domain to detect duplicate questions.
>
> ...
>
> Experiments on a range of real-world datasets demonstrate that our method works very well; in some cases over 30% improvement compared to state-of-the-art benchmarks. As a product of one of the proposed features, the association score feature, we have mined a set of associated phrases
> from duplicate questions on Stack Overflow and open the dataset to the public.

I didn't read most of it yet, but considering the queue we have on Close Votes, the direct application of their method on Stack Exchange site and their claim for results, would it be worthwhile to look into and attempt to implement their method?

Addressing comments:

> Are you going to be able to override the robot, or are we going to be slaves to a robot?

From the paper:

> A high quality duplication detection system will considerably improve user experience: for inexperienced users creating a new question, it can suggest
> a related post before posting; for experienced users it can suggest potential duplicate posts for manual verification.

The robot just gives suggestions, there's nothing to override, just to decide.

Comment: possibly related: [Project Reduplication of Deduplication Has Begun!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286329/165773) (at MSE)

Comment: Interesting note: the paper from this question cites a paper from one of the co-authors of the paper mentioned in the discussion gnat linked to. So, there is definitely some overlap here.

Comment: @Chloe The robot will bring you better duplicate proposals and the human decides if they are really duplicates or not.

Comment: Better duplicate proposals are acceptable.

Comment: SO community would certainly benefit from having mechanisms to detect dupes! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343382/would-so-community-benefit-from-an-ai-mechanism-to-help-moderators-identify-dupl/343395#343395

Comment: @BhargavRao Can you nudge this to the people in charge?

Comment: Welp, we the users of SO, are in charge of the community. :|

Comment: @BhargavRao I was under the impression that this needs to be implemented on the server level.

Comment: You've added a meta post, so the SO devs will have already taken a look at that and might implement it in 6-8 weeks. As community users, we can try to implement this on our side. There's a project in [SObotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) which was to predict dupes, I've pinged the dev of that community project.

Comment: The thing that you're missing here is that they _are_ looking into it. This isn't something that can just happen over night. This will take a lot of training, research, and development to implement.

Comment: @TinyGiant Don't think I'm missing that, there was no evidence that they are aware of the paper. If you're talking about gnat's link then it's based on a paper from well over 6 months ago. Looking at the post is something that can happen overnight, though I never expected anything to happen at such a short duration. At best I expected  maybe a response like "we'll look at it" or "we know about it" or "we don't want this".

Comment: "for inexperienced users creating a new question, it can suggest a related post before posting" The problem here is a lot of users either don't care or don't understand that their questions are duplicates.

Comment: _"I not-so-briefly alluded to a collaboration we're kicking off with the University Of Melbourne."_ (quoted from the first line of the post gnat linked). They _are_ looking into this and have been since well before they posted that. It is going to take a _loooong_ time before there is something viable that can be put into production. They are likely to be fiddling with knobs and flipping switches for 6-8 somethings.

Comment: I think it's a great idea! In fact,there's a data science competition created by Quora and hosted on Kaggle to build such a tool. https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-question-pairs

Comment: @TylerH Yup, but unless you add something like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions) for asking then you can only improve the computer, not the human.

Comment: Don't hold your breath. We were promised that they were "working" on a redesign of the "Ask Question" page, but there's been absolutely no public activity on that front in *months*. That would be a bigger-impact, shorter-term change, not to mention would require a lot less research and speculation. Frankly, though I don't have time to read the whole paper, I wonder how much difference there really is between this and the list of "related" questions that gets auto-generated when you type in a title. Even if so, no evidence users pay attention to those; why would a new algorithm change anything?

Comment: @CodyGray Because you can display that list to users going through the close vote queue and to users with voting rights on just about any question asked. So many questions are dups but even seasoned users don't feel like starting searches themselves. The algorithm can just give them better matches to look at.

Comment: Why not just [prevent duplicates before they are asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280668/178816)?

Comment: @TravisJ It's part of the algorithm, from what I read.