# Duplicate questions display experiment

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, user-interface, a-b-testing

My name is Jane and I have been working at Stack Overflow for almost six months. I started out as an apprentice last year and now I've graduated to developer. I was the lead dev on this project.

One of the most vexing problems with Stack Overflow getting old is that our repeated question problem is getting worse. It's frustrating for question curators and answerers and also for people new to the site. One of the common worries we hear is accidentally asking a question that is already answered on the site. The hypothesis of this experiment is that the way we currently display possible duplicate questions isn't helping as much as it could:

[image: Current state]

This is the title search. There is also a right sidebar box that sometimes loads based on what the asker enters in the body textbox. Since the title of a question isn't usually enough to go on and since the numbers can be confusing, we're going to try out a new display:

[image: Experimental duplicate question display]

For half of users (randomly assigned) this box will appear between the body and the tags after the user starts typing a title. As they fill in the body, the list of questions will be regenerated from time to time based on that new data. There is no sidebar box to be ignored or confused by. (Ironically, the sidebar often duplicated potential duplicate questions.) Taking a page from the ask wizard, the new display is more prominently placed which increases the odds askers will see it. Clicking on a question opens a new tab so that the asker can evaluate it without risking losing their work.

Normally we wouldn't pre-announce an A/B experiment, but in this case the change is visible enough we're certain to get people asking about it anyway. The primary metric we are looking at is click-through rate on similar questions. But we also are monitoring:

- Question volume
- The volume and % of duplicate questions (closed within three days of creation)
- [Question grades](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests)
- Whether users scroll through the list of similar questions

A small decrease in question volume is to be expected if users really are finding answers in the similar questions list.

As usual, please use the answers below for bugs, concerns, and suggestions.

Comment: Is there a way we can force this to be visible for bug/userscript testing?

Comment: Will this appear to those using the wizard or only to those using the /ask 3 boxes?

Comment: @Braiam: It will be the same UI for both. (So if you are part of the experiment group, you'll see the new version there.)

Comment: @ErikA: Our A/B test system isn't designed to support that sort of thing. (But if you insist, there's always [this method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685).)

Comment: does that mean that the search engine was improved? big thumbs up for this anyway.

Comment: You probably want to monitor the % of questions that are abandoned.  (An increase could be a sign that people found an answer in a suggested duplicate.)  That's likely to be a better metric than measuring numbers of questions asked, as that's affected by more variables.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: We did make a minor optimization to the algorithm this time, but there was a bigger improvement back in October. It showed something like a 20% increase in click-through to similar questions.

Comment: This should be featured.

Comment: I doubt the location of the duplicate suggestion box is the culprit. It's the quality of its  content, not showing the questions that are actually relevant.

Comment: @Bergi I agree, but to be fair, if you're writing a long question, the suggestion box can easily fall out of view. So you wouldn't see it update while you're adding to the question body, at least.

Comment: @jpmc26: Because it's a test, we want more people to encounter the change while they are asking a question rather than this announcement. But if people start asking duplicate questions of this one, I let the mods know they can feature it.

Comment: @Bergi: Obviously this is part of why we are doing this test. That said, many potential duplicates have pretty undescriptive titles, so including a bit of the body is potentially useful. Even more useful is incorporating the body into searches that show up in the center column rather than the sidebar. (I honestly forgot that was a thing until I saw the discovery for this project.)

Comment: The fact SO is doing *anything* about duplicates is simply groundbreaking! Really welcome that.

Comment: My problem with this is that the suggestions now appear **below** the new question body meaning it isn't in your face.  I have a feeling that users are going to ignore it more now that it isn't in your way.  I just don't know that not seeing a portion of the potential question duplicate body is the issue.  I think it's just the old issue that posters would rather do as little work as possible and get their answer.

Comment: @zero298 The bigger issue is they still are prompting users to put in a title first...

Comment: @zero298 indeed. Not only that but there is very little incentive for users to find a dupe, either. The incentive is to *answer the question*, so you have some people simply responding, especially when a question has a fast answer. A very common pattern is - somebody asks a question, gets *multiple* replies and accepts one, and if anybody close-votes for a dupe the answers/accepted disincentives more users to come and look at the question, possibly adding enough votes for closure. If a gold badge user happens to stumble upon the question, that might help but it's not a given.

Comment: Related: [“Possible duplicate of..” be given prominence for answering users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352450/could-possible-duplicate-of-be-given-prominence-for-answering-users)

Comment: On sites with MathJax enabled the size of previewed part of the question might differ considerably even if the number characters are the same. Should such problems be reported here (even though it has nothing to do with SO) or is there similar thread on Meta Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 130):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

**Include the chosen tags in the search criteria for "Questions that may already have your answer."**

---

Please include the tags (when present) in the list of suggested duplicates. Without the tags, the titles are rarely relevant even when direct matches of what would be viable solutions.

I have also mentioned this in the ["Ask Question Wizard" post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381698), in the [post on improving the Ask a Question page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327047), in a [post discussing why high profile users answer duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357027), and [in an FR at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280668)

Comment: One particularly common occurrence is getting suggestions from unrelated languages. E.g. asking a Python question and getting suggestions for Java.

Comment: I'd really like to be able to upvote this several times. Showing suggestions that are not relevant is counterproductive (i.e. if the first couple are completely off-base, then people often won't click-through to others). The suggestion results would be significantly improved if the primary tag (i.e. the most popular tag, usually the language tag) was taken into account when showing these suggestions. Having these suggestions be relevant would make a big difference to the effectiveness of showing them.

Comment: Agreed with this 100%. I can't count the number of times I've tried to search for something either from Google (where obviously this wouldn't help as much) or from within Stack Overflow and come across a question that looks exactly like the one I have, and then click through to find out "oh, this is in Java, not .NET" or something similar.

Comment: What about [language-agnostic]?

Comment: I definetly second this. One of the biggest canonicals of [tag:excel]-[tag:vba] is https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/ with a score of 472. Typing as title "How to avoid Select", with tags excel and vba in the tagbox, yields this suggestion in 18th place. Taking account of the tags couldn't result in anything but this question in the first place.

Comment: On occasions, I've used answers that are in languages other than what I know and use. For example, once I found a Python question about something that I wanted to do in Java, I think. I did find it useful but I still agree that's not usually the case. And a dupe *usually* is about the same language, so two different languages can both have a canonical dupe target for the same concept. There are some exceptions like [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004) but those are rare and the community can handle them.

Comment: Note that this should be somewhat flexible since very often new questions aren’t properly tagged. But yeah, there should probably be some intelligence that prevents a question being tagged with `language-X` to receive suggestions from `language-Y`.

Comment: @poke you bring up a good point, but I'll come at it from a different angle - I think the tags section should be moved. The reason is that tags are about as important as the title, when you think about it - the title is the essence of what your question is *about*, while tags are who the question is *for*. Having the tags section in the end makes them more of an afterthought, since it's the last thing you'd encounter after you've written your title and body. So, users should really start with a tag before even asking. They should also be able to quickly add more tags.

Comment: @VLAZ Sure, absolutely, I’m just saying that even then, users may not exactly know what tags to use when. For example, I’m very active in the ASP.NET Core framework right now, and sometimes, questions do have the `asp.net-core` tag but not the `c#` tag. And this being a framework used by C# beginners as well, often there are framework-unrelated questions that fit a broader C# context. But if we now only look for `asp.net-core` duplicates, then we might not find a duplicate for the problem which may actually apply to all of `c#`.

Comment: @poke uh, correct tagging is such a pain to be sure. I'm very active in `javascript` and we get a ton of questions tagged both `java` and `javascript` where the users only use one language and seem to think the other is related. Other times I've seen people ask questions tagged `typescript` only which are literally just about JS, as they use nothing specific from TS. But I think having tag relations improvement is a different matter together - getting people to tag at first should help, not the least because it would provide better dupe search.

Comment: @VLAZ, poke: Here's the conundrum, to make it explicit: SO wants to suggest good tags based on the content of the question. SO _also_ wants to suggest good dups based on the the content of the question _and the tags._ Lastly, the asker wants (good) dups to be suggested as early in the process as possible.

Comment: @Michael didn't get into that becaues 1. content limit 2. it's a comment but these are not mutually exclusive goals. You should add at least one main tag first (e.g. `java`, `c++`, `python`, etc) and the system can still suggest more tags as you're writing the content. Not sure on the best implementation here but it's definitely possible. You can both be non-obtrusive about the suggestions and try to make the users consider those before posting. A simple-ish way is to split the tags into "main" (one mandatory, above body of question) and "extra" (after body) where suggestions go to "extra"

Comment: All I am saying is that the tags shouldn’t be a hard filter for otherwise valid duplicate suggestions. Make tags add weight but don’t filter explicitly for questions with matching tags.

Comment: If its not in the same set of tags, then it is probably not going to solve the problem. We have 10 million questions here, so sure, you can find one that will prove there is a chance... it is just ridiculously slim. The goal here is to offer users a way to see canonical material for their questions since it exists. The way to do that is to include the tags in the search.

Comment: Interestingly, rather similar feature request was marked status-completed in January: [Questions that definitely do not have the answer to my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360337) Nick Craver said in a comment that tags "are considered and weighted, but they are not required to match". I suppose this might have changed again since then.

Answer (score 52):

First let me preface by saying welcome, and that I like this change!

This has been mentioned before *somewhere I'll unlikely find* but please do not display closed questions (unless closed as dupe) or questions without answers. It appears I'm not a part of the trial group, but looking over your screenshot one of the questions it links to is "WD my passport ultra 1tb not showing" (note I couldn't find this question), but that question has no answers and is therefore not likely to be any use to the OP.

[image]

Although I have sometimes found an answer or a hint in a question itself, more often than not it's just frustrating.

---

I agree more with Jon's comment below: rather than not showing altogether, I think they're acceptable to show if there aren't any other better results, so closed/0 answer questions could still get shown but have very little priority.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: I tend to agree we should de-prioritize questions with no answers or no upvoted answers, it isn't entirely useless to show similar questions with no answer. Sometimes just having another person's wording of a question can help. It's almost certainly better to show an exact duplicate with no answers than an unrelated question.

Comment: I'm not clear how *not* showing unanswered dupes is good. A dupe is dupe even if it's not answered. Unless you're saying that asking dupes is ok because it might generate a better answer but in that case that would argue all dupes are okay for the same reason.

Comment: @gman OK, so if we take that a dupe is a dupe and you have a question. Turns out it was already asked, say, three years ago but didn't get any answers for whatever reason. Are we then stuck? The question shouldn't be posted because it's a dupe but the dupe is literally no help at all.

Comment: I agree that while a dupe is a dupe, suggesting people _not_ to post a question because there is another maybe-similar question that is unanswered will simply not work. The idea is to prevent people from posting questions completely, but they won’t do that when they can’t solve their problem while looking at the suggestions. – I would leave the dupe-closing with unanswered question to users that clean up afterwards and attempt to increase the quality and helpfulness in the suggestions for the user to have them be less frustrated.

Comment: @VLAZ I mean, yes.  If the question has not received enough attention, add a bounty to it.  It's still a duplicate.

Comment: @zero298 I don't think new users can add bounties. I'm not even sure when you're allowed to but if you don't have enough rep to ask your question, you now have to spend time to collect it and only then be able to *offer it* for somebody to *maybe* look at an old question. That's a high barrier of entry and sure to turn away anybody below bounty limit from asking when a new answer might be what's needed. In fact, if any and all dupes are discouraged, then self-answers attempting to generalise and make a better canonical Q&A wouldn't happen which would lead to MORE dupes.

Answer (score 48):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

If the similar questions contain code (either inline or code block) in the body preview, the content is all escaped meaning it becomes pretty difficult to read. E.g.

> [image]

Answer (score 13):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can we also apply this new algorithm to the "Similar questions frequently linked or suggested as originals:" dialog box when closing as a duplicate? The current list it provides is next to useless for most questions, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56031958) when a google search on the exact title (even with the typo) yields a duplicate (more when you correct the typo) in the top 5 Stack Overflow answers.

[image]

Is there a reason Stack Overflow doesn't use Google search (i.e. [Custom Search](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4513751?hl=en&ref_topic=4513742)) internally?

Comment: Probably something to do with Google not liking it when bots scrape their search results. Something something cease and desist something.

Comment: Using the new UI, I did find several of those questions after typing just the title. [One of the duplicate targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505612/php-array-map-callback-parameter-scope) was in the third position. (The actual question you linked to was at the top.) The [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891888/php-error-why-is-variable-undefined-inside-array-map) Google prefers is about halfway down. I don't know if the algorithm is different, but  it sure makes sense to use the more understandable interface in the close dialog.

Comment: @CodyGray actually I was talking about google [Custom Search](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4513751?hl=en&ref_topic=4513742)

Comment: @JonEricson that's good to hear - let's hope the new UI makes it to the close dialog too.

Answer (score 10):

This is probably helpful — the experiment is certainly worth trying, and I applaud that it is being tried.  I certainly think it is helpful to offer better possible duplicates as the question is being asked.

However, beginners (and, let's face, many of the people asking question on SO for the first time are beginners) are not necessarily able to judge how well another question is a duplicate of what they're asking.  And questions that are duplicates are going to slip through the gateway, no matter how hard you try.  And those questions will then be fielded by regular (experienced) users of SO.

What I'd really like to see is SO providing help to the experienced users of SO to close incoming questions as duplicates of others.  This will, in my opinion, help even more than helping those who ask questions to identify the duplicates before they ask the question.

I don't know what SO would be willing to provided in the way of support to people.  In my fantasy world, I'd be able to popup a personalized list of possible duplicates, primarily ones that I've previously marked as being eligible for being the 'authoritative answer' (AA) for the class of questions.  These would be grouped by tags; maybe the method would know that the question had 4 tags and would show the possible AA options for that set of tags (singly and in combination).  I'd be fine with some of the suggestions being from SO AI technology; I'd still want to be able to specify those questions I think are important.  I'd like to be able sub-classify them.  Maybe even have private tags.  Maybe have influences from other people who are high-rep users in a given tag.  But a mechanism that would allow the creation of lists would save me having an incomplete list of bookmarks for possible duplicates in a limited list of tags.

As things stand, it is frequently much easier to simply answer the duplicate than to find a suitable AA for it.  Providing more or less the same information again is easier than pointing out where it was provided before.

See also:

- [Reputable people keep answering duplicates - What's the solution?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution/357037#357037)
- [Would SO community benefit from an AI mechanism to help moderators identify duplicated or related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343382/would-so-community-benefit-from-an-ai-mechanism-to-help-moderators-identify-dupl/343580#343580)
- [A long list of possible duplicates — C memory allocation and overrunning bounds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254782/a-long-list-of-possible-duplicates-c-memory-allocation-and-overrunning-bounds)
- [What to do with all the questions about scanf?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357845/what-to-do-with-all-the-questions-about-scanf/357861#357861)

Comment: I think our duplicate handling system is [due for an overhaul](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384812/1438). One problem you mention here is that it doesn't matter so much if the _questions_ are the same as it does that the answer to one question provides a solution to another. If we had some way of identifying AAs, we could prioritize showing those to askers. As a stop-gap, do you think it would help to prioritize [frequently-linked-to questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=MostFrequent&uqlId=177)?

Comment: In general, "frequently linked to" is a plausible surrogate for "experts think this is a good Q&A combo".  It's certainly an obvious one to try/use in the context of SO.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The Similar Questions section doesn't seem to scroll, instead showing the 25 questions in one go, and having to scroll through them all to get to the Post Question button. Scrollbar is visible, but disabled in appearance.

Seems to be because of the `.grid--cell12` class which has `flex-basis: 100%` style. Removing this in inspector makes the questions scroll properly.

> [image]

Latest version of Firefox, 66.0.5:

> [image]

Comment: I got the impression this behavior was entirely intentional as a way to encourage users to look at all of the potential duplicates.  Sort of like the "Scroll to the bottom of the ToS before you can accept" behavior some programs have.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler I doubt it because there is another class which sets the height to 450px (on mobile so can’t see exact details now)

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler whether it's intentional or not, it's a bud UX choice (if it was intentional) and an average user will not sift through a list of that many question and answers, if the UI is not welcoming

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler: It really is intended to be a list users can (optionally) scroll through. It's one of the thing we're tracking. So this is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Suggest to complement this experiment with an "embedded" A-B test. That "sub-test" is not necessary to make public because it won't be as noticeable, since it doesn't involve UI differences.

Specifically, I propose that half of users (in both groups of your test) would be getting results based on search limited only to questions having at least [10-20 thousands views](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A10000). You maybe can try even harder cut-off, like 50-100 thousands views if you are curious to observe a more pronounced difference.

My assumption is, people are primarily frustrated with duplicates of well known, popular questions. If system ignores and misses some obscure dupe with hundred views, people will hopefully understand.

But in exchange for dropping millions of low view questions out of sight we will get much better chances for remaining high view questions to pop up in search results. Proposed "sub-test" is expected to find out whether this would make people happier or not.

---

As a side note, similar A/B test can be done for [related-questions](/questions/tagged/related-questions). Make half of the questions show these picked only from high viewed ones and investigate the difference compared to the other half which would show related questions selected indiscriminately, as it is done now.

Comment: In my experience, the related questions tend to be way too generic garbage already, at least for C++. ("What is the difference between pointers and references?", "Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted one?" and all these million-view questions that are never really related). I agree that it might help for showing relevant duplicates in the original context of this question though.

Comment: @MaxLanghof because how the related question list decides how it's related (only via tag). This one instead take into account the body and title of the list.

Comment: Interesting proposal. However I wonder how many Q's there will be with 50k views in for example the [tag:vba] tag. So this should probably be a percentage of the total asked Q's within a certain tag.

Comment: I'm not sure views is the right metric here. While that does give us an idea of what people find via Google (the source of most of our views) it doesn't really say much about how often the same question has been asked. I'm thinking we might be better off giving preference to [highly-linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=MostFrequent&uqlId=178) instead. A hard cutoff seems wrong for the reasons @Luuklag suggests, but adding weight to particular questions based on what we know seems appropriate.

Comment: @JonEricson I also had this idea about highly linked questions but dropped it because I couldn't figure how to make it work in a way that's easy to understand for regular users. Thing is, for it to work right it would better count links from deleted questions, but these aren't visible to most users. That's why I have chosen number of views, it is probably less accurate but much easier to understand

Comment: @Luuklag search shows [over 1K questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A50000+%5Bvba%5D) in vba tag with 50K+ views. To me this tag looks big enough to survive an extreme modification of proposed test. A more interesting question would be I think if smaller tags could survive such a dramatic cut-off. Though frankly I am most interested in more moderate experimental value laid out in the beginning of my post, 10-20K views

Answer (score 4):

I think we need more clarity in 'What constitutes a duplicate question?'.
People ignoring warnings is the real issue here and you see people blatantly ignoring a question, answered, that will help them because 'My system is slightly different', and even worse, 'Oh I'll just ignore the warning and post mine anyway to see how people respond to *my* question'. People should get a warning about how this applies and that *if the answer exists anywhere else, and it will solve your problem no matter what, it is a duplicate*.

There needs to be stricter controls on what happens after you post a duplicate question too, and potentially it should even reduce your reputation or give you some flag against your account, and this warning should be shown in this redesign, to make people think twice in the first place.

Comment: Meta has often pined for this and for penalties for answering off-topic questions, but such avenues have never been pursued because they *discourage* participation in the gamified system. Of course, now that we have a different CEO at the helm, the direction may get to change a bit...

Comment: We've got the ask question wizard which already discourages participation, albeit more passively.  Extending that to potential duplicates is likely to discourage more.  I'm perfectly okay with that, whether it's for duplicates, or just asking in general.  It's far too easy to ask right now.

Comment: @TylerH: There certainly has been pressure to increase participation, but not around asking as far as I know. Asking off-topic and duplicate questions is not an experience most people come back from, so it'd be really short sighted of us to encourage it. Our interviews with new and non-users suggest helping them find duplicates quickly is important. The trouble is people have wildly varying abilities to identify whether existing questions will help in their situation. Relatedly, [we automatically block about half of all attempts to ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358412/1438).

Comment: @JonEricson the issue is increased participation in *answering* dupes. If simply close voting as a dupe was common enough *instead* of answering, that would be OK, but as it stands, a lot of people find it preferable to simply answer the question instead of close voting. At worst, they'd get one or two downvotes for a net -4 rep. But if they get a single upvote or an accepted answer (which they can get even after a question is closed), that's a net positive. And the system *encourages* this behaviour with reputation. One can often leave 2-3 answers in the time it takes to find one dupe.

Comment: @VLAZ: I'm starting to think people [_should_ be answering more duplicate questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384812/1438). At the very least, if it's hard to find the duplicate that indicates the titles of the canonical questions could be improved.

Comment: @JonEricson that's actually quite reasonable. In fact, I've been recently thinking about something along those lines and my thinking was that people tend to answer instead of dupe voting (when they know there is a dupe) because dupe voting doesn't get them anything. And on the other side askers are often irritated because their question was *closed* which implies it's *bad*. Yet, I do see dupe voting *as* an answer, if it solves OP's problem. By making dupes actual answers with extra text that will invite more people to use that answer, as it's even less effort to get rep. OP is happy, too.

Answer (score 3):

On smaller screens the Similar Questions list may not be visible until after the user has spent time entering their question body and scrolled down the page.

To improve the UX a little, I think that the Similar Questions list should be moved so that it is displayed between the **Title** input area and the **Body** input area.

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem while trying to reproduce some of the potential bugs listed here. I prefer short and wide windows, so there was no indication I had a duplicate suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not a concern*, just two interesting questions.

1. Based on your experience how will you guys visualize the results?
2. Will you all consider measuring the variation in your variables too? I am wondering if you all might find that you have a lot of volatility or heterogeneous behavior day to day changes in the duplicate questions.

Also, good luck, and I hope this experiment is fruitful.

*This user is really excited to see the results already.*

Comment: We have an A/B test framework that gives us some basic visualization. We can also export the results to a database that would let us look at a wide variety of variables. For this first pass, I think we're mostly interested in the click-through rate, which tells us if the possible duplicates are helpful.

Comment: @JonEricson Cool, I love to see what the click through rate will be(1) when you feel that they are ready to share. Best of luck!


(1)You could make it teachable moment :D

P.S. Maybe some day post the data on kaggle

Answer (score -4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Show bad questions as a warning.

If your search finds ill-received questions that are similar to the one being typed (let's say vote count < -1), show these questions in a separate place as a warning to the user. The questions should be reviewed by the user to avoid making similar mistakes.

Comment: This might be nice but I think it's a dream; I don't foresee most askers reading other questions and heeding a label showing them as bad; I think instead they'd just say "well I will ask my question anyway" or "if it's still on this site it must not be bad" or some other justification.

Comment: I like the idea in a vacuum, but an average person asking a question on SO doesn't think that way. If anything, I'd think this would only create more confusion and hassle

Comment: The devil is of course in the details. If it's framed in terms of "save yourself some heartbreak", I'd like to hope it will sell some people... No way to tell without testing...

Comment: SO could even show complaints about our heartless attitude towards new users to encourage people to review bad questions :)

Comment: @TylerH SO *already* sometimes displays a warning message that similar questions have been badly received. This suggestion is proposing a means for making that functionality better.

Comment: @Raedwald I haven't seen such a message, but this mechanism wouldn't be better than such a message, in my opinion; it would be worse, because it would be muddling the message. "This question is similar to these poorly received questions, so you have to look at them before you can ask yours" is a worse experience and less clear signal than just saying "similar questions to this were poorly received"

Comment: Ah yes. The heads-on-pikes solution. ;-) One of the things we are looking at testing is whether new users can identify poor questions. (Our hypothesis is they have a harder time than people who are active in a tag.) Showing examples of bad questions only helps if people can understand what makes them bad. My experience suggests @Rawrplus has it right: this will create more confusion.

Comment: First time ever a negative score makes me smile :). "Heads on pikes" forsooth!