# Provide similar questions only for relevant programming language in the Ask a question interface

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way to somehow filter the "Similar questions" suggestions in the "Ask a question" interface by programming language or tags? I make these steps:

1. Insert `python` and `python-3.x` tags for my question.
2. Enter the title of my question.
3. Review all of the provided similar question suggestions. However, sometimes most of the questions are not relevant for me, because they are for different programming languages.
4. Submit the question.
5. Get my question marked as duplicated, because there actually was a similar question asked with `python` tag, but it was not provided in the suggested questions.

It would be great if the step 3 was improved somehow. E.g. by automatically filtering the "Suggested questions" by tags entered or allowing to apply tags for suggestions manually or at least allowing to see more question suggestions.

Comment: Related: [the answer under Duplicate questions display experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384716/4642212) requesting tags to be shown and included in the duplicate question display.

Comment: I don’t think that’s necessarily a good idea. General programming issues can easily translate between programming languages. Yes, there are issues specific to one specific language or framework or API but that doesn’t make it so for all issues. And knowing the difference is not something an algorithm can do yet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Its probably hard to automate, however if a user is sure that his issue is language specific, there should be an option to manually filter the suggestions by custom tag.