# Do profile views matter on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, profile-page, views

Just as reputation and badges have their importance, does profile views also considered to be important?

If yes please share how.

Comment: They do not matter. They only matter if they matter to the profile owner, or the observer.

Comment: @yivi Isn't that true of reputation and badges as well?

Comment: @kabanus Reputation can grant you privileges on the site. Badges are as useless as profile views, but they are at least displayed more prominently.

Comment: @yivi I see, useful for contributing to the site then, thanks.

Comment: @yivi badges have some influence on moderator elections, don't they?

Comment: Yeah, maybe @Gimby. Modration is such an exception that I wasnt really considering it anyway. On the other hand, it's entirely possible that most moderators are robots anyway.

Comment: There are also the gold badges for dupe-hammering @yivi. And atleast one moderator is a tree :P

Comment: You are right on that score as well, @André. So we go back to the original point: profiles views are irrelevant.

Comment: They absolutely matter to people who think they matter.

Comment: I think that the "profile views" also counts views from yourself :)

Answer (score 13):

In the immortal words of the late Freddie Mercury:

> Nothing really matters
>
> Anyone can see
>
> Nothing really matters
>
> Nothing really matters to me
>
> Anyway the wind blows

No.  Profile views are not important.  They don't signify anything about the user except that other people are curious about them for some reason.

Comment: the legendary Freddie and his Bohemian Rhapsody (RIP)

Comment: Nothing really matters to meee. Nice illustration. Haha.

Answer (score 6):

The number of profile views is purely informational, there are no privileges attached to it. [All privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) are earned through reputation.

Badges are also mostly informational. They matter for two things:

- when you want to be a candidate for [a moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election), certain badges are required to be eligible and some other badges increase your candidate score
- a gold tag badge gives you special powers: [When did I get close-vote superpowers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers)