# What to do about question with multiple low-quality answers?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, fastest-gun, low-quality-answers

I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77252159/why-does-pip-give-me-an-error-message-even-though-i-have-it-installed#77252176) on SO that lacks certain details like the OS that the OP is using. The question has multiple low-quality answers all of which have been upvoted. In fact, the highest voted answer is literally a link-only answer. What should be done in such a case? Should I vote to close the question or just flag the answers?

Comment: Given that *It's a quite frequent error* as the top answer suggests, sounds to me like the question should be close-voted as a dupe. I'm just not enough of a subject-matter expert in the topic of the question to find a good canonical.

Comment: @user16217248 Thanks for the reply. I will vote to close it then.

Comment: ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23708898) should work, no?

Comment: "I noticed this question on SO that lacks certain details like the OS that the OP is using." **It actually doesn't**; the error message shown is specific to Powershell, which is Windows-specific. While it could theoretically be run under WINE or something, there would be little to no good reason to try, and it wouldn't really change the answer anyway.

Comment: That answer you're talking about is not link-only. It is still an incomplete/bad answer, but not link-only.

Comment: @Tom The answer's been deleted now, so I can’t tell if the answer was edited after I posted this question. At the time of posting this question, that answer only had a link and a single sentence saying that the article in the link was the solution.

Comment: @Dinux The original text (in addition to the link) was "It's a quite frequent error. It's because it's not in your system path.". The second sentence is enough to not make link-only anymore. It is still not a good answer, though.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel [PowerShell's GitHub page](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) says it is available on Windows, Linux, and macOS.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: I hadn't tried it until now, but I have now installed it on Ubuntu 20.04 (yes, I know) with `snap --classic install powershell` (ignoring the scary warnings): *"powershell 7.3.7 from Microsoft PowerShell✓ installed"*. It was launched with `pwsh` and `Get-Alias | select Name, Definition, DisplayName | Sort-Object Definition, Name` resulted more or less in [the expected result](https://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2019/10/powershell-aliases-and-missing.html).

Comment: I stand corrected, although I am still confident that the OS is not actually relevant to the specific issue with Powershell asked about. Other OSes have an analogous concept of the PATH which works in nearly the same way, and it is often appropriate to work around the path issue anyway (e.g. `python3 -m pip`). Granted, there are some OS-specific details (e.g. the Windows-specific optional use of `py`, and different path separators in the PATH environment variable), but this is a case where *an OS-agnostic understanding of the problem is more important* than OS-specific help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I noticed this question on SO that lacks certain details like the OS that the OP is using.

In this specific case, as I already commented, that information isn't actually missing/needed: it can be inferred from the specific error message. The problem is a (very) common duplicate, and it has now been closed as a duplicate of the canonical for that problem. (The canonical has been viewed 2.5 million times and has probably over a hundred duplicate links; that isn't a huge number of dupe links compared to some others, but I would guess that a lot of questions on this theme get closed - inappropriately - as "not reproducible or caused by a typo" instead, and a lot get deleted as poor signposts.)

Please make an effort to look for duplicates for this kind of question even if you aren't especially familiar with them or think that such information might be needed - there could be a platform-agnostic canonical duplicate already that includes information for all major platforms, for example. Duplicate closures are usually faster than others (because [some users can fast-track the process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589)), and it's important to close questions like this as quickly as possible.

However, you would be perfectly within your rights to suspect that the OS information is missing, if you don't have that kind of experience with Python and the mistakes that Python beginners make. If you are reasonably confident that there is a specific piece of missing information, and you don't already recognize a common problem, please flag or vote to close as "Needs details or clarity", and feel free to comment to tell OP specifically what is missing.

> The question has multiple low-quality answers all of which have been upvoted.

There are a ton of users of Stack Overflow - perhaps the majority of active users by now - who seem to have no concept of how the site is intended to work, and will vote blatantly against policy. Cast your own votes according to your understanding of policy; if you think something's amiss with votes, use your judgement in taking it to Meta, commenting about it or holding your tongue (according to the details of the situation).

> In fact, the highest voted answer is literally a link-only answer.

These are not just "discouraged" per your comment there, but against policy; please flag as "Not an Answer" (unless they appear to be intended specifically to promote the site being linked to as a source of information, in which case they may qualify as spam).

> Should I vote to close the question or just flag the answers?

Only flag answers that would qualify for flagging regardless of the question quality.

[In my personal opinion and interpretation of policy (this is by no means settled)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459), it is perfectly appropriate to downvote and delete-vote answers on questions that should be closed. After all, the purpose of the closure is to prevent those answers in the first place; being proactive is better than being reactive, but justifications for a proactive action are justifications for a corresponding reactive action when the former fails.

If you recognize a reasonably high-quality answer on a new duplicate, and you don't think an existing Q&A includes the material in that answer, consider commenting to ask the author to re-write that answer for the proper question.

Of course, now and then it could happen that a new question is just a much better phrased version of a Q&A we've been using to close a FAQ. It's possible for curators to fix these problems. In extreme cases please come to Meta and explain the situation.

If you see high-reputation users answering questions like this, you may also consider commenting (politely) to remind them about the purpose of the site and the role they can play by helping to find duplicates or improve question quality. In my experience, it doesn't accomplish anything, however.

Comment: This link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459 only mentions down-voting. In your answer, in addition to down-voting answers to bad question, you also claim that whether delete voting them is acceptable is open to interpretation. But that's not what any of the answers on that meta post talk about. I'm also not aware of any consensus that delete voting such answers is allowed. In fact, I thought delete-voting an answer just because the question is bad is considered an abuse of the delete-vote privilege. Do you have some links to back up your claim that it's an open question?

Comment: "But that's not what any of the answers on that meta post talk about." It's certainly included in *my* answer there, because it follows from the same reasoning that I used for every other curation action - plus the fact that undeleted answers interfere with the Roomba. I don't consider it abusive because my stance is that such answers **are ipso facto bad regardless of their content** - their mere existence worsens the site, even if they are brilliantly written.