# Possible UI bug?

Tags: bug, design

I noticed a bug (maybe) in the UI, specifically in the 'Related Questions' pane:

[image]

Notice the '1' right under the '17'. I don't know if this is a bug, but it is quite ugly. It should reproduce itself in this question's 'Linked' pane to the right.

[More effective closing / downvoting of junk questions to help with the signal-noise ratio?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no?rq=1)

I am using Google Chrome FWIW. It goes away if you lower Chrome's zoom to 90%.

### This bug is on the side pane, not the actual question itself

## Bug fixed good job!!

[image: fixed]

Also props to Jin for designing such a slick theme!

Comment: Oh I see the problem: the UI doesn't handle question with more than 99 upvotes (or less than -99 XD) very well. It places the last digit on the next line.

Comment: already reported here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277208/578411

Comment: The UI should be made so that it remains "zoom independent"

Comment: @KhanPower: the SE devs have long stated that any zoom setting other than 100% is not supported.

Comment: And I don't see this on Chrome on Mac. But that just means the Mac font is *just* a little narrower. Then again, the 'negative' post linked from the 'more effective closing' post has its 1230 votes neatly fitting in the box too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "the SE devs have long stated that any zoom setting other than 100% is not supported". This bug only shows up when the zoom *is* 100%

Comment: @KhanPower yup, realised that later, but only because I cannot reproduce this on Mac.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

all.css:1:54735:

```
width: 20px;
```

Should be:

```
min-width: 20px;
```

Comment: Checking it now it seems that this is now the case.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine on my machine:

[image]

What size screen have you got? Have you got the web page running at a decent size?

Comment: It goes away when you lower chrome's zoom to 90%. However, the default is 100% and other webpages look funky at 90%

Comment: @KhanPower I have it running at 100% in FFox. Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: No I have not. This may be a Chrome specific issue

Comment: No, it's not just Chrome. I'm running FireFox, and I'm seeing the same thing.  In fact, like [nhahtdh reported](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277208/20938), it's messed up at 100% or 90%, but it's okay at 110% or 80%.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. Mozilla SeaMonkey on Debian. Zooming also helps in this case

Comment: For me (Win7, Chrome 39) this happens, when using ctrl+scroll to zoom, only at 100% and 33%, and at 25% all three digits are below each other. All other zoom levels are fine and this is consistent for every resolution.