# Should I edit on-hold questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, vote-to-reopen, on-hold

Should I ever edit a question if it is on-hold?

The OP is supposed to edit the question anyway when it is on hold, so an edit by another user is bound to be overthrown by the OP's new edit. And if he does *not* edit the question, the question will be deleted. Will my edit be of any use, or will it just be lost?

Many below have stated that a new edit by another user (only for "on-hold" questions) will push the post to the reopen queue. If the OP edit's the question after another user's edit, will reviewers see the OP's edit?

Comment: [the fact is the OP will rarely actually make any effort at salvaging the question no matter how many requests in the comments for them to do so. I have a question from a few years ago that does the stats and shows that single digit percent questions ever get edited by the OP much less get reopened because of it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no)

Comment: [Closed/ReOpened after last edit was by owner after being closed](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/186827/closed-reopened-after-lastedit-by-owner-after-closed) and [Questions Never Edited By Owner After Being Closed](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/186892/questions-never-edited-by-owner-after-closing)

Comment: Solution proposed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350063/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If I understood the mechanism correctly this would be counter-productive:
An edit pushes the question to the reopen-queue, but only the first edit does so.

So let's think this through:

1. Question gets closed.
2. You edit to correct some typos.
3. The question gets pushed to the reopen queue.
4. Every reviewer votes "leave closed" since there is no substantial improvement.
5. The OP edits improves the question, but it does NOT appear in the reopen-queue again.
6. The OP has a hard time getting the question reopened.

Comment: So by this logic I should not edit the question, unless it is very substantial?

Comment: @theProgrammer101 only edit the question if your edit makes it eligible for reopening. This is _almost never_ the case, because the usual close reasons don't include "your question is an ugly mess". Perhaps some cases of "unclear what you're asking". By default: don't edit closed questions. See also the polishing of fecal matter.

Comment: @AndrasDeak That's helpful Andras, thank you. So I usually shouldn't edit on-hold questions.

Comment: @theProgrammer101 Apart from fixing up broken English, it's rarely possible to make a sufficiently substantial edit that doesn't involve reading the OP's mind; such edits may be rejected as conflicting with the author's intent. Sometimes there's enough info from the OP in the comments to make a good edit, but in that case be sure to mention that fact in the edit comment so that reviewers know that you aren't just making stuff up.

Comment: @theProgrammer101 (cont) IMHO, it's better to encourage the OP to fix the question themself, preferably while it's still open, and only edit it for them if they need help with the English or formatting. As others have mentioned, once a question is on hold it's rather likely that the OP will abandon the question.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. Why do we even push the question to reopen queue when someone else than OP did edit it ? Shouldn't there be a message when we try to edit a question currently on-hold to let us know about it ?

Comment: @Kaiido Interesting concept, and I suspect it's been discussed here in the past. One problem with your proposal is that someone may propose an edit while the question is open, the question gets closed, and then the proposed edit gets approved, pushing the question to the queue.

Comment: @PM2Ring, well this pitfall would concern only editors who need approvals. I mean, I guess I read the help-center (*got da badge*), but I didn't know that if I ever came to edit an closed question, it would push it, **for the last time**, to the reopen queue. A reminder on such cases might be worth it, even with this pitfall, but I am unsure this happens so often for it to really worth the dev work.

Comment: @Kaiido I agree it would be good if that info was more visible, I only learned it myself from reading Meta. Third-party edits to closed questions do happen fairly often, but it's only really a problem if the OP does actually make a subsequent edit that warrants re-opening the question. More often, the closed questions isn't worth saving, but it will get a suggested edit to fix code formatting or minor grammar errors because the person who suggested the edit wants the 2 points from having the edit approved, and they aren't too concerned with the overall quality of the question.

Comment: @PM2Ring, Personally, when I vote to close and there is a pending edit, I will almost always force the pending edit to be applied or rejected by using "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit" (or forcing an edit, if for some reason I'm not permitted to review). I do this specifically to avoid the case you describe where a pending edit exists at the time the question is actually put on hold in order to prevent that edit from kicking the question into the reopen queue.

Comment: @Makyen Me too. I guess "Improve edit" is generally the better option if the editor has tried to do a good job: it must be confusing in that case to get a "No improvement whatsoever" rejection message. Pity we can only ping editors if their edit is accepted, it'd be nice to be able to explain why their nice-looking edit is actually a waste of time.

Comment: @PM2Ring, After closure, I write a custom reject message to (very briefly) explain that the edit, if approved, would have kicked the Q into the reopen queue, which would usurp the OP's one free entry into that queue via edit, which I consider causing harm (except in the *extremely* rare case where the edit would make the question pass reopen). Prior to closure, I'll pick whichever of Improve/reject I feel is appropriate for the edit. Sometimes, I'll go to another question to ping the editor with such, or other, info (then delete the comment once it appears they've seen it).

Comment: Best would be to change the system so only edits by the OP put the question into the reopen queue. In my estimation, it's a *much* more rare occurrence for a non-OP edit to be both sufficient to make the question be on-topic (i.e. pass reopen) *and* the editor not have the ability to manually nominate the question for reopening (i.e. <3k rep). If desired, this could be alleviated by having a checkbox in the suggested edit queue that allows reviewers to indicate that the edit is sufficient to put the question in the reopen queue. My expectation is it's rare enough not to need that checkbox.

Answer (score 20):

> The OP is supposed to edit the question anyway when it is on hold, so an edit by another user is bound to be overthrown by the OP's new edit.

While the OP is usually the one supposed to edit the question, that's not necessary, and not enforced by the software at all. If you can fix the problems that put it on hold to begin with, go ahead and edit. (If you *can't* edit to make the question worth reopening, editing will indeed be counter-productive for reopening the question.) If the OP gets around to editing as well, that's fine, but not essential.

The OP's edits (if any) won't automatically override yours in any way; in particular, if they edit before the question has finished making its way through the Reopen queue, their edits will be combined with yours in the diff view shown by default to reopen voters. (Of course, if they roll back your changes or manually edit to reverse them, those will be lost.)

Answer (score 15):

If a question that's clear to you was put on hold as unclear by others, you can help the asker by editing to clarify their question.

> an edit by another user is bound to be overthrown by the OP's new edit

If the asker edits over your edit, that's not something that can be reliably prevented unfortunately. You'll just have to resubmit your edit and hope they don't overwrite that one too. Since you don't have full editing privileges either, this does make it a little more cumbersome. For what it's worth, this sort of thing doesn't happen *too* often.

If the asker decides that they don't want your help and either rejects or rolls back your edit leaving their original, unclear question, then you can either let it fester, or ask a moderator for assistance.

Comment: Also if the question ends up going for deletion the edit and its rep gain will be lost. So OP has to be sure that the question is worth improving.

Comment: @suraj: Yeah, that's true.