# Reopen of "on-hold" questions on editing can be improved

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen

If I understand the existing SO logic correctly, currently the first edit to the question throws it into reopen queue. And then we get reopen reviews like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/16294284

where some format changes triggered a reopen review.

I suggest we should tighten the rules for reopen on editing as follows:

- An edit by the OP can trigger reopen review.
- The OP is prompted to submit the question to reopen review after edit. The prompt emphasizes that it's the only chance they will get to reopen the question.
- All other editors are prompted to use a reopen vote to trigger a review

Comment: Off-topic: wow, that's a terrible edit. Inserting signed commentary into someone else's post? `All quoted text is code` formatting? I'd revert it if the question were remotely on-topic.

Comment: Since only 3K+ users can reopen vote would this mean we need reopen flags?  If not a lot of editors would not be able to push the Q into the queue(not sure if that would be a bad thing).

Comment: Edits by OP or approved by OP should trigger the reopen. Substantial edits (lots of green/red) by third parties should trigger the reopen vote. I don't know why it has to be only once, the reopen queue is mostly empty.

Comment: @Braiam That's the same mindset that's put the suggested edit queue into a rough place.  Just because the queue can handle the number of items it *currently* gets doesn't mean it's okay to radically increase the number of items it would get, or that it would be able to handle it.

Comment: @NathanOliver - this is a feature. Putting the order into reopen queue if you don't have a 3000 rep is an opportunity we extends to OPs to salvage their question regardless of the reputation. This opportunity needs not cover third parties who have no rep to reopen a question.

Comment: @Braiam "approved by OP" - OP can "approve" a third-party edit by making her own small change and confirming that the question should be sent to review. Or we need more UI.  "Substantial edits" - let OP be the judge of that - it's his opportunity to reopen and his question. "has to be only once" to make OP think before submitting and not waste her opportunity, and to discourage reopen/close tug of war. Maybe permit another attempt in a month.

Comment: @Servy the fact that reviewers gave up reviewing because robo-reviewers is what put the suggested edits into a rough place. The lack of rapid response when the users were complaining is what pushed away conscientious reviewers.

Comment: @Braiam That might be part of the problem but I've notice a definite change after the nav bar UI change.  Per [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349118/is-the-top-bar-redesign-the-sole-cause-of-the-suggested-edit-slowdown/349125#349125) it looks like all queues have had less reviews after the UI change

Comment: @Braiam Bad reviewers are certainly *a* problem with the review queues.  They're not specific to suggested edits, nor are they recent.  They've been a (significant) problem with *all* review queues for their entire history; in fact, it's been *much worse* in the past (notable around 2012 when the queues were re-done).  But that's not the *only* issue; the whole point is that you need to consider *all* of the factors contributing to how items go in, and out of, the queue.

Comment: If you start pumping lots more items into the queue, it may or may not handle it, and even if it can, it will mean that any future problems that increase content, or decrease reviews performs, will be that much more likely to be the straw that breaks the camel's back and moves the queue from being able to handle the input to not.  That doesn't mean you never increase items, but you *do* need to be careful about it and consider if the queue is actually able to take more.  That it's current at 0 isn't enough, on it's own, to say.

Comment: Lets be serious, @Servy. Do you actually believe that if we had motivated and conscious reviewers we would need audits, rubber-stamping, rollback and review overrides? REALLY? No. Obviously. We wouldn't need any of that, and the queues would be manageable at all times.

Comment: In my estimation, it's a rare occurrence that an edit by a non-OP will change a question sufficiently such that it goes from being off-topic to being on-topic (i.e. will be reopened). It's an extremely rare occurrence that such an edit will be by a person with < 3k rep. (i.e. someone who can't manually vote to reopen). The *vast majority* of questions which are closed require changes by the OP in order to be on-topic. IMO: It's better to error on the side which gives the OP the most opportunity to enter the reopen queue with a version of the question that will actually be able to reopened.

Comment: Yes, this proposal makes it such that <3k rep non-OP users can't put questions into the reopen queue. I view this as better than having a much larger number of trivial, or formatting-only, edits squander the question's one free-by-edit entry into the reopen queue when the vast majority of such non-OP edits *can't* change the question sufficiently such that it would be reopened.

Comment: I presume *ceteris paribus* on my statement, @nathan. Truth is, that posts passing trough the queues have enough unnecessary cruft if the human reviewers were more conscious. Improve the human to improve /review.

Comment: @Braiam You're right that those systems that are in place to prevent abusive reviewers from causing harm wouldn't be needed if there were no abusive reviewers.  Of course, there being no abusive (or just bad) reviewers does *not* mean that you'll necessarily have enough reviewers to review all of the items you'd like to review.  In fact, the opposite is true. The more you restrict reviewers to only people that can review *well*, then less items you're able to review.  The fact remains that there's more stuff to be reviewed than people qualified to review it.

Comment: @Makyen Just FYI, not that I disagree with your assertion, but that was how it worked when the reopen queue was first created, and it was changed due to complains that posts were being edited enough to merit reopening and weren't being put in the queue as the OP wasn't the one to edit them.

Comment: @Makyen which is why I put "Substantial edits" on my proposal: only lots of red and green would be able to modify questions enough that it would be acceptable (but lets not forget that a simple 3 character edits can do the same like [revision 4 of this post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/1178/revisions)

Comment: @Servy, Interesting. I wasn't aware. I don't know if it's that the criteria for closure/reopen has changed, or if the number of non- off-topic➞on-topic edits has increased, but my impression (i.e. not backed by any statistics) is that the vast majority of suggested edits/edits by <3k rep users on closed/on-hold questions don't come close to changing the question from being of-topic to being on-topic. Frankly, my impression is that in the vast majority of cases, an edit by a non-OP is not possible (w/o drastically changing the meaning of the Q, which is something we discourage).

Comment: @Makyen Like I said, I wouldn't disagree that most edits to closed questions (period, honestly) don't make close worthy questions reopen worthy, I'm merely informing you that it *used* to be the case that only the OP's edits put questions in the reopen queue, and it was rather quickly changed because people didn't like it (whether their concerns were well founded or not).

Comment: @Braiam, I agree it's *possible* for a non-"substantial" edit to change a question from being off-topic to on-topic. I just think it is *rare*, and extremely rare when that edit comes from a <3k rep user who isn't the OP (i.e. someone who can't otherwise put the question in the reopen queue). While the example (on [skeptics.se]) you provided was a very small edit, it's one that was made by a (now) 58.5k rep moderator. Even at that time, that user probably would have had the ability to put the question in the reopen queue, if that had been needed (at the time, the Q wasn't closed).

Comment: **The OP is prompted to submit the question to reopen review after edit. The prompt emphasizes that it's the only chance they will get to reopen the question.** I did not know that a question was placed into the review queue *only once* based on edits, namely the first edit. I think it would be good to at the very least make this more obvious.

Comment: I can't support this in it's current form. I would much rather just switch the logic to say "First edit **by the asker** on a closed question will trigger a re-open review". Much simpler to read and understand, and removes the need to add entirely new functionality to the codebase.

Comment: @TylerH - this is indeed the "meat" of the proposal. The prompts are just there to help the OP if they want to split edit int multiple steps and to link reopen vote to the edit (rather than simply showing "reopen" in the review queue). Without the OP prompt they are likely to waste the opportunity.

Comment: @Arkadiy It should be automatic - no prompt needed. Right now there is no prompt; the first edit simply automatically submits the question to the reopen queue. This is what should happen still, except make it the first edit *by the OP only*. That will solve the problem of passing trivial edits submitting a question to reopen review that isn't ready for it, and also prevent the problem of OP not being able to edit the question and have it submitted to the reopen queue, simultaneously.

Comment: @TylerH, that first edit by an inexperienced OP may be just cosmetic change - and it will waste her opportunity to submit for reopen. I am trying to avoid a "hidden" action - the OP thinks he is just editing the question, but in reality he is doing SOMETHING ELSE. That's what the prompt is for.

Comment: @Arkadiy So at most then the prompt should just inform the OP that their first edit after the question is closed will submit the question to the reopen queue for editing. My point in suggesting this narrow change is twofold: **1)** It's already quite a large change in how the process works, and the devs are loathe to make changes to the Q&A codebase that are large - they never know what unintended impact a change might have. **2)** While this prompt may ultimately be beneficial, per the reasoning in point 1, the team is probably more willing to make smaller, incremental changes than a big one.

Comment: @TylerH Sure, the informational message in the edit screen is a good enough solution - as long as it tells the OP not to commit the edit till they are sure it's worth reopening.

Comment: *If I understand the existing SO logic correctly*: Do not be so naive, there in logic on any SE website.