# Reopen Votes queue overrun due to poor approved edits/rep farming

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

Recently the Reopen Votes queue has been overrun with questions that have been closed, then edited by a user who is not the asker after the closure, and their edit has been approved.

95% of the time this happens, this approved edit does nothing to attempt to fix the question's content, but consists merely of formatting tweaks - which has the sole effect of (a) gaining rep for the editor (b) pushing the question into the Reopen Votes queue where shmucks like myself have to take a look at it to confirm that yes, it is still terribad and should never be reopened.

My procedure so far has been to go back to the stupidly-edited question and mod flag them with a comment that the edit is bad and whoever approved it should be review-banned, but seriously... that isn't instant, I have better things to do with my day, and I'm not the one who approved the bad edit and caused the problem in the first place, so why should I have to suffer?

I haven't thought long and hard about this, but I feel that some ways this could be mitigated (aside from review-banning the a**hats who are accepting these useless reviews) are:

- If a question was closed as a dupe, don't nominate it for reopening if it's edited by someone other than the asker.
- If a question is closed, and someone who is not the asker edits it after the fact, show a warning banner on the edit screen - something to the effect of "This question was closed due to serious problems; please do not edit it unless you are certain you can materially improve its content to make it answerable".
- If an edit in the Suggested Edits queue is for a closed question and was not performed by the asker of the question, show a warning banner on that suggested edit for that particular question to reviewers.

Please proceed to shoot holes in my suggestions and/or tell me I'm a terrible human being. You could also provide your own thoughts and suggestions on how this can be addressed, if you're feeling constructive. ;)

Also if there is a better way to deal with bad suggested edits than mod-flagging the offending questions, please advise.

Comment: I can definitely see value in notifying edit reviewers when accepting the edit would mean the question goes into the reopen queue.

Comment: Or just notifying edit reviewers not to approve edits that fail to substantially improve the post. Which is already the guidance.

Comment: Maybe the reputation minimum for reviewing edits on closed questions could be raised?

Comment: Another question: Should we flag such edits for moderators?

Comment: @Cody I just went and reviewed a few edits so I could re-read the page and the advice isn't really that clear - it just says "edits that clearly improve the post". So if someone edits the all caps title and corrects grammar but it remains as a "Please post the code to make a social network site" type question it's not that clear on what to do. I'd almost like to see a reject option like "fails to make the question of an acceptable standard".

Comment: @BDL Yes, you may raise a custom moderator flag if you see a pattern of abuse from editor, reviewer, or both sides, but this really doesn't scale very well. It takes us a non-trivial amount of time to investigate these cases and decide on an appropriate course of action, so if everyone flags every invalid edit they see, we are going to drown. So please be smart about it. Prefer to handle what you can yourself, by rolling back or fixing.

Comment: Only the OP should be allowed to edit the question once it's been closed. If the OP cannot edit the question into something worth-while, it's hard to believe anyone else can. - *this approach may have limitations that escape me at the moment.*

Comment: @Ihazkode should be possible to remove irrelevant tags so that they do not bug in listings

Comment: @Ihazkode this is a bad idea because... I have nothing.  It should be implemented.

Comment: This comes back to the idea that, if a questions is bad, 'someone else' has to fix it, provide advice, reviews etc. etc.  Just no.  If a question gets held/closed, the OP is the ONLY user who should be putting in a lot of effort to get the issue fixed.  Not other users, not mods, not SO employees. The OP's have the responsibility, and they should handle it themsleves.

Comment: @MartinJames about 45 reasons why this is a bad idea [are listed here I think](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341987/839601)

Comment: @gnat how much effort was requied to salvage those questions?  Was it worth it?  Would the effort have been better spent on answering good questions that did not require a salvage-posse?

Comment: Related on MSE: [Requesting a "stop polishing turds" edit suggestion reject reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260302/requesting-a-stop-polishing-turds-edit-suggestion-reject-reason/260329#260329) (/cc @PeterJ)

Comment: Some bad questions have good answers, and I don't think it's a good idea to discourage editing those to improve the formatting. I suggest that users who edit closed questions should be asked if they are turning it into a good question or just making a minor edit, and only put the question in the reopen queue if the user specifically says that the edit is supposed to turn the question into a good question.

Comment: @MartinJames You're assuming any given editor can easily find some good unanswered questions that they can actually answer, and that they don't have a preference towards either editing or answering. Turning a crappy question into a good question is almost as good as posting a good answer to a good question (if not better).

Comment: What if the first edit to a closed question **by the OP** sends it to the reopen queue, with a warning message they have to click through saying that it’s their only chance to get it reopened?

Comment: @MartinJames editing part there was easy, I often do such edits myself (150 of 200 questions where it was hard were simply deleted). Hard part in that posse was deletion of answers invalidated by edits because only diamond mod can remove historical post sitting at +5/+10 saying "here is the link (article, tool, library) you asked about"

Comment: Let's fix the *real* problem. Make it such that non-OP edits don't auto-push the Q into the reopen queue. Your suggestions that either the banner be placed the edit screen for non-Op's editing closed questions, and/or a warning banner on the review screen just put a band-aid over the *real* problem: that edits from users other than the OP auto-push a question into the reopen queue, which you cover in your first point [Note: your second and third bullet points don't address situations where the edit is suggested prior to the question being closed, but not reviewed until after it's closed.].

Comment: Related/near duplicate: [Reopen of "on-hold" questions on editing can be improved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350063)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I approve a suggested edit fixing a broken link in an answer I have flagged as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308139/should-i-approve-a-suggested-edit-fixing-a-broken-link-in-an-answer-i-have-flagg)

Comment: @CodyGray Formatting and spelling can be a substantial improvement. The problem is that it is possible that even after a substantial improvement the question is still terribad.

Comment: Surely this is just a red dot side-effect.  It noticed that it, unwisely, also flares up for the CVQ.  So users that never reviewed before now think that they do something useful with a lame edit.  Which in turn is killing the RVQ, nice going.  But should not be a problem, these kind of small UI changes stop being effective quickly.  Otherwise necessary to try to keep up with the excessive attrition rate, 2500 new reviewers are needed every week to keep 7000 of them active, they don't last more than 3 weeks on average.  It is the site's worst feature.

Comment: What do you mean by "overrun"? The Reopen queue usually hovers at around 75 to 200 questions. Did it double in size? Triple?

Comment: @TylerH I think you have a couple of typos there, you pressed 7 and 5 instead of 0. ;)

Comment: @Ihazkode Not allowing edits on closed questions means that questions and answers marked as dupes will never get updated, if this site (per the meta posts I've read) values legitimate dupe questions (as in, **"valid" yet completely different** approaches, on a similar *concept* that just so happened to have the same answer), that means that questions (with research effort) with broken links and answers with issues (e.g., broken links) that got posted before the question was duped will never get updated, seems like this will result in a net decrease in post quality on this site.

Answer (score 37):

> *meta note: I originally provided data for only 14 days here; I've since found myself referencing this post with some frequency, so I've updated it to reflect a full year of data; some of the original commentary may seem odd in light of this.*

Here's how reopen review outcomes break down by [creation triggers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078) over the 365 days between September 3rd 2017 and September 3rd 2018:

```
CreationReason        ReopenTasks % Reopened % Leave Closed % Edit % Task Invalidated % Questions now open 
--------------------- ----------- ---------- -------------- ------ ------------------ -------------------- 
OwnerEditCreated      37734       4.49 %     76.85 %        0.21 % 18.44 %            7.25 %               
ThirdPartyEditCreated 12284       1.28 %     88.51 %        0.07 % 10.14 %            2.43 %               
Popularity            8746        4.71 %     82.38 %        0.16 % 12.75 %            6.69 %               
VoteCreated           8127        6.77 %     81.97 %        0.17 % 11.09 %            13.65 %
```

The second column is the total number of tasks created for that reason during that time, the next 4 are the % of those tasks that were resolved in various ways ("invalidated" just means the review couldn't finish for some reason - including both the question being deleted or reopened outside of review).

Note that when I threw this together last night, I made two big mistakes: I ignored audits (which inflated the popularity trigger - though this also varies wildly over time, so also suffers from a small sample size) and didn't correctly account for edits that happened prior to the question being closed - those ended up skewing the results considerably.

So, yeah 3rd-party edits have an even worse success rate than you predicted; in two weeks, only 5 of them got reopened via review. OP edits - which account for the majority of all questions in reopen review - are a little bit better, but still mostly terrible. Even reopen votes from folks with 3K+ rep leave reviewers cold the vast majority of the time.

OTOH, the primary reason for putting this logic in place was to require a bit more work than simply [flagging to reopen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186722/can-we-have-the-ability-to-flag-for-reopening/186728#186728). In light of that, at least there's potentially *something* to work with, vs. an endless stream of folks asking for questions to be reopened where nothing has changed since they were closed.

As for bad edits... Don't forget that you can leave a comment on any edited post that @-pings an editor - if you haven't *told them* why their edits are lacking, you might want to try that first.

Comment: Wow, today I learned "popularity" is a metric that can put a question into the re-open queue. And apparently it has been such a thing since 2013...

Comment: The poor success rate of reopen votes at actually pushing a question through to a successful reopening completely matches my experience. I've gotten questions reopened successfully when I cared enough to make Meta posts specifically about them arguing for their reopening, but have otherwise failed ~100% of the time. It's pretty rare that I stumble across something closed that I think doesn't deserve to be, but every time I do my attempt to fix it ends in failure and frustration.

Comment: @MarkAmery so, more reopen audits for the reopen queue?

Comment: @Braiam perhaps, but I'm not sure how *possible* that is; the trouble is that our close reasons are so broad, and the community's interpretation of them so diverse, that you can make an argument for why almost any question should be closed. When I vote to reopen stuff, I usually don't mean "there is an absolutely ironclad, 100% objective argument for why closing this is incorrect", I mean "my judgement on this differs a lot from that of the close voters". But if reopen voters are heavily skewed in favour of closure, such subjective cases (IMO most questions) are unlikely to be reopened.

Comment: @Braiam to illustrate my point: if the site's [top-voted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/1709587) were asked today, closed before any answers, and nominated for reopening, would it be reopened or left closed on the basis that it doesn't provide information about the architecture the code was run on that is necessary to reproduce the behaviour? If [question #4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/477816/1709587) had been closed unanswered as "opinion-based", would the reopen queue vote to give it a second chance, or leave it closed? Personally, I expect both would be left closed.

Comment: @MarkAmery that's the thing with the reopen queue, people (and I can see that you) don't understand it. It isn't "closing this is incorrect", it's "this question is answerable by the site standards". That's why the queue is so inconsistent. If Shog adds the average of "reopen" votes those that ended closed and "leave closed" those that got reopened it would be more visible.

Comment: This still supports my casual observations: tasks on the reopen queue are more likely to be OP edits than any of the others *combined*.

Comment: There was even a podcast that covered this once upon a time, @Cody - though I believe it was the "show has officially ended, time for David to rant" part.

Comment: Why a Third Party edit is adding a question in a reopen queue? There is almost nothing that a third party edit will be able to do to get an invalid question valid, otherwise it means that the question shouldn't have been closed in the first place and shall have been edited directly. So the way this feature is designed (_queuing for reopening on third party edit_) is flawed. At least it should be conditional on the state of the closure: ON HOLD, closed as OFF-TOPIC, as DUPLICATE, as UNCLEAR, as TOO BROAD, as OPINION-BASED, edit by 2K user... some of those should stay unaffected by third party

Comment: Doing re-open reviews right now and I get a lot of the superfluous minor edits by 3rd party, that didn't even pass suggested edit review, because they were approved by the OP.

Comment: Oh this is funny, you claim that "I get a lot of the superfluous minor edits by 3rd party, that didn't even pass suggested edit review, because they were approved by the OP", yet out the 12, only 1 was edited by suggested edits and two by 2kers. That leaves us with 10 edited by OP. Confirmation bias is real @lundin ...

Comment: @Braiam And how do you know which ones I skipped? Go stalk someone else.

Comment: @Braiam What's the difference between "this question shouldn't be closed" and "this question is answerable by the site standards" WRT a question's close/open status?

Comment: @TylerH why would one close a question? Because it isn't at the moment up to our standards. Why would one reopen the question? Because it's now up to our standards.

Comment: @Braiam "this question shouldn't be closed" is implicit in "this question is answerable by the site standards" A question that is answerable and up to our standards shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @TylerH I explicitly used that because it doesn't accept anyone point of view without any measurable metric. That's why I prefer "is answerable by the site standards" because it tells you that it should be compared to the site standards, not any person criteria.

Comment: @Braiam there isn't an objective set of "site standards" though. There's a bunch of contentious, woolly, and contradictory positions asserted by staff, mods, and community members on Meta, with various numbers of upvotes, and with no clear means for judging what is The One Objectively True Set Of Rules and what is just a popular opinion. Faced with that state of affairs, we can - and must - all individually make subjective decisions about when we think that a position we've read on Meta constitutes a *rule* that we are beholden to and when it's an opinion we're free to ignore.

Comment: @MarkAmery oh, but there is: the help center and the tooltips on the entire site. That's what should be followed on any circumstances. There are contradictory guidance? It's more likely that anything that isn't the help center is wrong (except on triage). Those site standards aren't popular opinion, they don't change with time, the vision which created a collaboratively edited library of practical programming questions is still there, since inception.

Answer (score 31):

Here's a better suggestion: edits should only cause questions to go into the reopen queue if the OP is the editor.

Let's consider every possible close reason, and then decide who is more likely to make an edit that makes the question reopen-worthy:

- Duplicate: If the question is not a duplicate, the OP is the one who is most able to disambiguate it from the dupe-target.
- Off-topic/General Computing/Hardware: If the question is not hardware-related, the OP is the best person to be able to explain why this is not the case.
- Off-topic/Server: Ditto
- Off-topic/Recommendation: If a question looks like a recommendation question but is instead a "how to achieve X" question, it is possible that people who aren't the OP can explain the difference.
- Off-topic/MCVE: The OP is the person who has the code; therefore, they are in the best position to provide the code.
- Off-topic/No-Repro: Such questions usually don't get reopened. But if they do, it is usually by the OP providing further information/clarification. Which the OP is uniquely suited to do.
- Unclear: The OP is the person most likely to be able to provide sufficient information to clarify the problem. Others may be able to guess sometimes, but only the OP *knows*.
- Too Broad: The OP is the *only one* who can narrow it down. They're the only one who knows exactly what they're looking for.
- Opinion-based: The OP is the person most capable of finding a more objective form of their question. If someone else has a more objective form, they can ask it anew themselves.

Note that there are a lot of "most likely" equivocation in the above statements. Yes, I recognize that it is *possible* for other people to provide that information in those cases. So what?

If the OP is not engaged enough to fix the problem with their question themselves, then they're not really in a position to ask someone else to do it. Therefore, only edits by the OP should be considered when putting something in the reopen queue.

Furthermore, the OP already failed once. We need to teach the OP how to fix their question's problems. And that's not done by fixing them for them. By only considering OP edits, we make sure that other people coming along to fix it won't get the same effect. This rewards OPs who actually work to improve their questions.

Comment: This concept ignores the fact that a question could be wrongly closed.  If a question is wrongly closed every argument you make is wrong.

Comment: @psubsee2003: If the question is wrongly closed, then it doesn't need editing. It needs someone to *vote to reopen* it. Which should be sufficient to put it into the queue.

Comment: But <3K users can't vote or flag to reopen.  Editing the question is the only way

Comment: @psubsee2003 that sounds like an XY problem. In other words, a workaround for a missing feature: flagging to reopen. I would be very surprised if "*oh, I have <3k rep but this post needs to be reopened, I should edit it*" was a regular (or even significant) course of action by users.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I don't really believe that users with <3k rep care about reopen queues mechanism.

Comment: Note that when the reopen queue first came out this was the behavior.  A little while after it had been out it was changed so that edits from people other than the OP would put questions into the queue, because people felt that too many questions were being fixed to merit reopening by people other than the OP.

Comment: Probably not, but there is a bit of text (and a link) under every closed question encouraging edits for that purpose, @xenteros. When it was added, edits increased.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350063/reopen-of-on-hold-questions-on-editing-can-be-improved

Comment: @xenteros Well...  I am interested (rep = 186). I am not particularly thrilled that an edit automatically puts a post in a reopen queue, but I am not really sure what a better alternative is. Really when I edit I just want to fix the post for the sake of cleaning up the site, I have never edited with the intent to get something reopened, and I probably never will. I've flagged to reopen posts when I couldn't find any sense at all in the close reason, but that's rather rare (e.g., embarrassingly bad fortune telling on a 2010 "Too Localized" question with 10k views and some votes).

Answer (score 5):

I think suggestion #2 has some merit as it somewhat attempts to educate users. Along those lines, I am pretty sure most <2k users do not understand that the +2 rep they get for editing the closed post will go away when the post is deleted.

So how about something like this?

- If a question is closed, and <2k user who is not the asker edits it after the fact, show an info banner on the edit screen - something to the effect of:

  > "This question was closed due to serious problems, please do not edit it unless you can materially improve its content to make it answerable; if it ends up being deleted, your +2 edit rep will be removed".

Comment: The problems I see with the addition are 1) it implies that the potential rep loss is why we're asking them not to do it, which isn't true, and 2) this won't work with questions that can't be automatically deleted. They are likely to see an edit to a closed question with answers as 'safe' because we still aren't telling them that their poor edit cheats the OP out of getting their question reopened. Of course, I'm assuming users will be swayed by an appeal not to cause harm vs self-interest.

Comment: Hey @Stephen, you should have just gotten an email from me inviting you to a pre-screening session hosted by Stack Exchange. We've got dates this upcoming Monday and Tuesday, so if you are interested, could you let me know what times might work best for you?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe when a question is edited the person doing the edit should be asked if they wish to “vote to reopen”.    Often even as the OP I may edit a question (for example a duplicate) to make it clearer, but not wish it to be reopened that that point.

So prompt for “should be considered to be reopened” on an edit, but don’t automatically assume it.   The reviewers of the edit should get the same prompt and the question put in the reopen queue only if they also agree.

Comment: The argument has been put forward many times on meta that closed questions should not be edited unless they ought to be reopened. Otherwise, what's the point? It doesn't belong on the site and likely will be removed in a day, a week, a year, or whenever a few users cast delete votes on it.

Comment: @tylerh not if its a duplicate that is a good googol target

Answer (score 3):

> My procedure so far has been to go back to the stupidly-edited question and mod flag them with a comment that the edit is bad and whoever approved it should be review-banned, but seriously... that isn't instant, I have better things to do with my day, and I'm not the one who approved the bad edit and caused the problem in the first place, so why should I have to suffer?

This seems like wrong/harmful behavior to me for several reasons:

- First of all, it's not your job to request that moderators take a *specific action* against a user or users; moderators decide what punishment a rule breaker gets. Flagging a user for problematic behavior is one thing, but telling moderators to perform the most severe action on the user because their actions are merely annoying to you, personally, is a bit of an overreaction.
- You can't possibly know for sure in every case when the first close vote hit the question, vs when the suggested edit hit the review queue. In some cases you can tell if the suggested edit hit the queue *after* the question was closed, but a lot of the time, those edits are sitting there pending while the question is still open.
- To segue from my second point, users suggesting edits can't even *see* if a question is accruing close votes. You need 3,000 reputation to see them on others' questions. You gain the privilege for automatic edits 1,000 reputation *before* that.
- If you are concerned about your limited time being wasted in the queue, and you are getting frustrated with the stuff that enters the queue, perhaps *don't spend so much time in the queue*. The queue exists precisely to put reopen candidates under scrutiny.

Editing a post to clarify it, fix code that someone forgot to indent or tag (I see a lot of HTML/CSS posts that look nonsensical because someone added a lot of `<div>`s and `<p>`s in their prose and didn't put graves/backticks around them, so they don't show up in the post), or fix some other issue is one of several valid ways to get a question reopened, and it's working as intended when such edits land the question in the reopen queue.

*It's your job as an editor* to review these; that's the whole point of the queue! If you don't like those edits, or edits by someone other than OP, it takes but a second or two to hit "skip".

Comment: "You need 500 reputation to see them on others' questions." - I don't think that's the case.  You can't see anything except on your own questions until 3K

Comment: You can see CV's on your own post at 250 rep.  Otherwise you need 3K

Comment: You're both right; I was thinking of the access-the-queues privilege. Thanks, that further validates my concern.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that such edits were made by a person without edit privileges, each such harmful edit would have ended up in the suggested edit review queue. If so, the root of the problem lies there.

When doing suggested-edit reviews of questions, the reviewer needs to consider if the question makes sense in the first place!

There do exist rare cases where an edit from a 3th party could save a question from being closed. But apart from that exception, there is never a reason to edit a question that is closed/should be closed.

Editors who "polish crap" are a huge waste of everyone's time. In addition, they send out a signal to the OP that: "the question was fixed, so it is fine now". And also such edits could indeed spawn re-open reviews.

What I do when I encounter minor edits to bad/closed questions, is to reject with a custom reason, something along the lines of: "This question is `<close reason>` and cannot be salvaged by anyone but the OP. It should therefore get closed, not polished. Instead of trying to fix it, flag/close vote instead."

Answer (score 2):

How about a ban on users that edit questions that get review rejected for:

These should be strikes for sure and count very heavily,

- No improvement
- Conflicts with authors intent

things like

- attempt to answer
- me too
- other (comments as answers)

should count towards a ban but with less weight than the others.

With an appropriately aggressive ban threshold this would automatically resolve the problem without any human intervention and dis-incentivise/degamify the behavior.

Answer (score -14):

You know what? I'm not seeing it.

Out the 10 I've reviewed, not all where pushed to the queue with edits. The 6 which were, are done by users which fall in one of these two categories:

- Are the OP
- Have >2k reputation

My guess is that my filters rock (only reviewing off topic or primarily opinion based).

Comment: Seems you had luck. Out of my 20 reviews today at least 5 had this problem. ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770041/unity-doesnt-know-jsonobject), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756164/how-to-display-the-image-from-a-specified-directory), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762938/storing-array-of-struct-in-core-data), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768980/incompatible-types-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-string-shows-an-erro), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757724/how-to-get-current-year-in-vue-js)).

Comment: Almost all had been edited afterwards by other users too, to a large portion to correct the edit done by a <2k user.

Comment: @BDL number 2 is definitively a good edit. The editor extracted the information from comments and put it into the question. Or are you saying that such edits are discouraged also?

Comment: Agree. Didn't see the deleted answer and "improved formatting" as editing comment doesn't sound like that.

Comment: How can you possibly draw conclusions from only 10 reviews?

Comment: @Stijn if it was as "overrun" as the OP claim, I would expected to see it in a handful of observations. I didn't.

Comment: @Braiam So, how can you possibly draw conclusions **from only 10 reviews**?

Comment: @Mistalis "if it was as "overrun" as the OP claim, I would expected to see it in a handful of observations. I didn't." Aren't you reading the previous comment? Oh, and btw, see Shog table.

Comment: I remember you. You're the guy who ranted in comments over how one of my meta posts wasn't good because, quoting "Understand, **you are not a representative sample!**". Original formatting was preserved in the quote.

Comment: @Lundin and I said I was? The claim in the title was "Reopen Votes queue overrun due to poor approved edits/rep farming". My test was simple. If it was overrun one expects >50% of the same kind reopen task. The sample is as random that one can expect from the queue (it's random, but not quite) and given that I skew my own sample (with filters), following geometric distribution, one would expect 1 success in the 7th observation. I wasn't able to get one up to 10. So, the claim that the queue is composed over 50% of third party approved suggested edits is unlikely.

Comment: @Lundin Now Shog numbers put that number in 23%. That's not overrun either. **So my casual observation aligns with reality**, yet I was never claiming it is reality, just that the claim of OP is not likely.