# How to deal with suggested edits on questions put on hold?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've gained access to the suggested edits queue lately and I'm wondering how to deal with suggested edits on questions that were already put on hold. I find it hard to decide **what to do with edits that clearly improve a question but still not make the question worth to be reopened**. A good example might be this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17578955).

What is the right way to deal with such an edit?

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349988/should-i-edit-on-hold-questions

Comment: I bumped that one back out of the Reopen queue. You were right to be concerned about that. It's a decent edit under normal circumstances, but nowhere near good enough to nominate the post for re-opening, which is what happens when you approve it. Whether that's a flaw in the system or not, it's something to keep in mind when reviewing edits on closed questions. If they aren't a *substantial* improvement, consider rejecting on that basis. Or, do as your heart calls you. Ultimately they won't be re-opened anyway, so it just wastes some reviewers' time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just vote on the edit like you would on one on a open question, but keep in mind that editing the question will push it into the re-open queue.
If the edit doesn't make the question worthy of re-opening, it may be better to reject it as too minor / no improvement.

Does the suggestion make sense? Does it improve the post (enough)?
Then approve it.

Comment: I'm curious why I got this downvoted. Iirc, there are no rules against suggesting edits on closed posts. In fact, an edit _might_ just be what the post needs to be re-opened.

Comment: AFAIK: An edit automatically puts the post in the re-open queue fyi: I didn't downvote :)

Comment: @AshleyMedway: That's correct. Maybe that should be taken into account when reviewing.

Comment: @AshleyMedway That was one of my worries: I think the example edit shouldn't go to the re-open queue...

Comment: Didn't DV, but wouldn't an edit like this qualify as "polishing a turd"? Personally, I'd skip it. Doesn't fix all the existing issues nor moves the post into "useful" territory.

Comment: @yivi: Depends on how much polish is applied to what kind of turd...

Comment: In the case posited by the OP, certainly not _enough_ polish for that kind of turd, IMO.

Comment: @yivi: Yea, that one is quite bad.

Comment: @yivi: That is now addressed by the additional last sentence: "If the edit doesn't make the question worthy of re-opening, it may be better to reject it as too minor / no improvement."

Comment: The first part of your answer says to approve it but then the last half says "reject unless it makes the question worthy of reopening" These are two different and often competing metrics.

Comment: @TylerH: How about now?

Comment: @Cerbrus All you did was reorder the same things, no? I feel like the part about making sense and improving the post don't belong in the answer, since the question is specifically already about edits which improve the post, *but are on closed questions*.

Comment: @BoltClock too minor doesn't exist. Do not use it for rejecting valid edits.

Comment: @TylerH: The whole point of this answer is that you should just vote on those like any other question, but keep in mind that the re-open queue is a thing. So, I think it makes sense to also mention when you can / should approve the edit.

Comment: @Cerbrus I guess we just disagree, then. I think the whole point should be *only* approve if it makes the question worthy of reopening. Disregard whether it "simply" improves the post, as that is not a stringent enough metric for currently-closed questions.

Comment: @TylerH: I guess I'm slightly more lenient towards to editor. It's possible that we don't completely agree :-)