# Edit on question rejected. Why?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

[My edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18316268) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916082/why-my-c-program-dont-print-anything-unless-i-type-something-look-at-image-att) was rejected.

The question was later **put on hold** as "unclear what you're asking", due to the fact there was no code shown, and also bad formulation.

But, there was some code in the question(despite it being a screenshot, rather than text). 
I do see that after my edit, subsequent edits would follow, such as transforming the image code into text code, and formatting the question.

However, I think the question would get pretty clear, had the edit been approved. So why the rejection?

Comment: Code as an image does not make a question ok. It’s the OP responsibility to add it to the question.

Comment: _I do see that after my edit, subsequent edits would follow, such as transforming the image code into text code_ That is OP's job and is the reason why it is put on hold.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you there, the edit should've been approved but it wouldn't of stopped the question getting closed.

Comment: @George I agree..But,the problem in such cases is if the suggested edit goes through _after_ all close votes are in, the post will needlessly enter the reopen queue.. refer:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349988/should-i-edit-on-hold-questions

Comment: Inlining the image doesn’t make the post better than linking to the image, IMO.

Comment: @SurajRao even worse; that happens only *once* after editing. So if the reopen review result is to leave it closed, and the OP later edits it into 'good enough' shape, it won't enter the review queue again and it will stay closed (unless somebody votes to reopen it).

Comment: Why didnt you copy the code from the image in the question?  Inlining the image is as useless as having it just linked....

Comment: @yivi there is no image linked, it's a screenshot from the OP's local machine

Comment: @SurajRao The proposed edit was before the question was closed. (And the reviews of the edit) So in this case it wouldn't of been an issue.

Comment: @JohnSmith for improving posts like code formatting, spelling grammar, tags etc.. which an editor can do

Comment: @George yes.. As I mentioned _if_ the _approval_ of the edit goes through after post is closed..It takes a number of reviewers to approve it

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260302/requesting-a-stop-polishing-turds-edit-suggestion-reject-reason

Comment: @Patrice there is no link to the image in the question. Only the editors can see the link.

Comment: Even adding the link is a waste of time. A linked screenshot -or an inlined screenshot- is the same as no code at all.

Comment: @SurajRao And all the people that reviewed the edit did so 20~ minutes before the post was closed. I think we're focusing too much on the question and not the actual edit, the edit did make the question better so rejecting it for the reason "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible." is a bit _wrong_

Comment: The answer to your question would be: it got rejected because despite the many robo-reviewers; the review queues still work.

Comment: Fair enough the link is invisible. However it shouldn't become an inline image. The actual content shown in the link should be in the question. If I want to reproduce to test, I should just c&p from the Q. Not painfully transcribe  an image

Comment: @JohnSmith just a tip. If the post is close-worthy, double check if your edits make the post salvageable (generally that wont be the case). In this case though there is some improvement, it doesnt salvage the post

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since your edits still have to be peer-reviewed in the review queues, you should do your best to make edits that *significantly* improve a post instead of edits that could be described as *superfluous*.

In case of a question, if the question **is not good enough to remain open** you should stop and think if your edits are going to make the question good enough to save it from closure.

If the question was close-worthy before you suggest an edit, and remains close-worthy after, the case can be made that the your suggested edit is actually superfluous.

And more often than not, only the OP can edit a question beyond the *closable* threshold. There are, of course, many exceptions; but I think that the general rule is that **it is much easier to improve someone else's question than to save someone else's question**.

To make matters worse, you may be very well be hampering the questioner. E.g. if the edit gets approved after the post is closed; [it will be sent to the re-open queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078) *before the OP had a chance to actually improve their post to the point is salvageable, and nobody will vote to re-open.*

[But this happens only the first time a post is edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349988/should-i-edit-on-hold-questions). If the OP later on wants to edit and improve their post so it gets re-opened, they'll find it much more difficult (since subsequent edits **wont** send the post automatically to the re-open queue).

In the specific case you linked, the post doesn't contain any code: Linked code, code in the form of an image (or linked images of code) **do not count as code**. Your edit didn't change that, and reviewers took note.

It doesn't matter that the code wasn't actually linked and visible in the original revision and that you subsequently inserted it as an inline image: **code present as an image doesn't count at all, and that's all your edit did**.

While code (contained in either a linked image or an inline image) *could* be transcribed, that's the OPs job; potential answerers are not meant to work as human OCRs.

There is no harm on having an edit rejected. As @Machavity [says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360978/1426539), this is simply the system improving itself by teaching you to make better edits in the future. If you use this opportunity to learn from it, your future edits will better and will get approved and content on the site will get better. Happiness all around!

Comment: An inline image is not an improvement. A question with code present as an inline image, is still closable. Code as an image is the same as no code at all.

Answer (score 6):

Understand that [images of code are not useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). While the list of reasons is long, the most important reason is this

> Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem

Understand that any coding problem needs reproduction. If people have to retype what's in an image to run/debug it, they're not very likely to answer it. So we tend to close these for lacking a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So you're not really making the question better by making the image of code inline.

Your edit creates problems as well. If the edit is approved *after* it's closed, it goes into the Reopen queue. Since you didn't solve the problem, people will leave it closed. So now you've foreclosed on the best opportunity for the OP to get it reopened.

My advice to you is you need to ask yourself this question anytime you make an edit

> Am I making the question better?

In this case, the answer is No. But this is your opportunity to learn. If one person stops editing closable questions without making them open-able, it's worthwhile.

See also [Would you accept an edit where link images of code are replaced by inline images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358771/would-you-accept-an-edit-where-link-images-of-code-are-replaced-by-inline-images)

Comment: Again, I **didn't replace a link by an inline** image. There was no link shown at all.

Comment: @JohnSmith That's all your edit did, though. Look at the rendered output. The inline image is all that was changed, which leave my point unchanged

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916082/why-my-c-program-dont-print-anything-unless-i-type-something-look-at-image-att     unless you edit the question, you can't see the link

Comment: @JohnSmith, I'm sorry but you are being rather obtuse. We do understand your point, but the fact is your edit wasn't helpful. It's very hard to imagine a suggested edit that ends up with code as an inline image and will be considered useful. It doesn't matter that if the link was originally visible or not.

Comment: @JohnSmith What we're all telling you is that an image of code is not acceptable, and your edit just did that, it showed an image of code. That's all. Changing OP's invisible link to an image of code by a visible image of code is **not** an improvement because **we do not want images of code** anyway. The fact that the link to the image wasn't originally visible is irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnSmith You're still missing the point. Yes, the link is invisible without an edit but **the link adds no value to the question**.

Comment: @yivi I thought that after the image would be visible, someone else would jump in and transcribe the code. I've seen that happen before, to other questions.

Comment: @JohnSmith: while it **could** happen, it's a long shot. In the end, it's the OP responsibility to edit their post into shape. Focus in the other parts of these answers: after your edit the question was still closable, so it wasn't a good enough suggestion, and could have been harmful in the end. The important lesson is to usually steer away from this very low quality questions. Or, as is colloquially said around here: [do not waste your time polishing turds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360978/1426539). :)

Comment: @JohnSmith So... why not edit the code in yourself? That would have made for a good (and approved) edit...

Comment: That edit would be much better. Still, I wouldn't want to give credence to the idea that users different than the OP should go around OCRing code posted as an image, nor training users posting questions without any runnable code to expect their questions to be salvaged by the good Samaritans of SO.

Comment: I'm against having anyone else than OP transcribing their image to text. An editor could easily add a typo or miss something, this would make things confusing. Besides, seriously, we're not OP's minions. There's more interesting things to do, on the site and in life, than transcribing an image of code that's in a poor question.