# Should we accept/reject an edit to a question that is unsalvageable?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was in the Help and Improvement queue. And there was a question of the type "How do I do this in X language. I am not a programmer, I don't know X language, I am told by my developer team I should implement this. How do I do it?"

So basically the question was too broad, there was no code, and likely there was not going to be any, since the OP really had no clue what to do. I would usually flag a question like that and move on. However this question was also very poorly written (although you could understand it) and another user had edited it. I was given the option to "Reject, Improve, etc." the edit, which BTW didn't truly fix all the issues of the question, since the wording was still poor.

Should we reject edits to questions that are basically unsalvageable? Or should we just let them be/improve/accept?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155961/is-dont-polish-turds-a-valid-edit-rejection-reason

Comment: There are many dupes for this, but while someone finds them: if a closable question gets a suggested edit that **doesn't** push the question into non-closable territory, just reject the edit, IMO.

Comment: @yivi I tried looking for dups, but I couldn't, I guess is the wording.

Comment: Apparently, I had [written](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360975/1426539) an answer about something related as well.

Comment: @yivi I like your answer to that question, it makes it really clear for me how to proceed. Specially the part about hampering the OP by an edit that gets approved after the question gets closed.

Comment: If the edit does *nothing* to salvage the post, in your judgment, then yes, you should reject it on the grounds that it does not provide any improvement. This is one of the standard rejection reasons. It’s even more important with closed questions, because users get one chance to place a closed question into the reopen review queue by editing. If this opportunity is wasted on a useless edit, well, it’s wasted. Note that, while usually discouraged to preserve author intent, *major* edits that rewrite the entire question are valid for otherwise unsalvageable questions.