# Mass editing questions, but some of them are closed

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, closed-questions, serial-editing

I seen yesterday this meta discussion:
[No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it/385424#385424)

It encouraged "serial-editing" (not sure if it's proper term) questions that should be edited. Especially there was hundreds of "thanks in advantage" questions that all were fixed. I'm quite sure, that at least some of them should be already closed.

I thought that I can help and started to fixing (slowly, because I don't have 2k rep) questions "thank in advance". Some of them are closed, so I looked at meta to find if I should touch them.

On one hand there is this: [Should I edit on-hold questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349988/should-i-edit-on-hold-questions) (question about closed questions point here). But one the other I'm sure that mass-editing like described above had to touch some closed questions.

Should I also fix closed question, while trying to remove all question that contains some "forbidden" text?

Comment: Actually, I'd advice you to wait until 2k rep - don't waste the time and reviews of reviewers! Secondly, you shouldn't edit closed questions if they were closed <=5 days ago because they are pushed into the reopen queue.

Comment: It's a minor cultural point, but we tend not to think of chatty material as "forbidden", exactly - it is discouraged, but for positive reasons (succinctness and readability) rather than negative reasons (avoiding punishment).

Comment: For what it's worth, we tend to use the term "serial editing" when fixing mistakes related to one user. This area can be contentious - some users do not like it, and there is some disagreement in the _Meta_ community about how to do it (there are several topics here about it). If you do do this, then wait until you have 2k rep, and do it slowly, so that users do not have to proof-read more than a few updates at a time.

Comment: @halfer Why I should "do it slowly" after 2k rep? I thought that after 2k rep edits don't require validation.

Comment: @franiis: in the case of finding consistent issues per user, they will get a notification per edit, so they can check if they agree with your edit, and it is generally kinder not to swamp one user with too many notifications. If you are just removing, for example, "thanks in advantage" generally, then you do not need to worry about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please don't fill the [suggested edit queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/) with [edits like this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23298480). It's a very basic question with fewer than 50 views, asked two years ago, it shows no research effort, the OP wasn't seen for a year already, and removing the "Thank in advance" doesn't make the question one bit better.

As for editing closed questions:

> only edit the question if your edit makes it eligible for reopening

Please find better, more promising questions to edit, and edit them more thoroughly.

Comment: One should also note, that a edit below 2k should be as complete as possible. Removing "Thanks" but not fixing the capitalization of an i is suboptimal

Comment: Sorry, I try to fix all mistakes I can find (I missed this capitalization).

Comment: @franiis the point is that if you don't have full edit privileges, you shouldn't join these (benign, futile) crusades. All you're doing is creating more work for others, while only marginally improving the site as a whole. Spend your effort finding posts that really need editing. The newer, the better.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I'll be more careful to only make edits that are worth time of someone else.