# Thwart publishing duplicate and low quality questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, duplicate-questions, low-quality-posts

I had a thought when I was reading over this post and its interesting answers: [Are high-reputation users answering fewer questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions) specifically [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252770/998328) answer.

### Why do we allow duplicates and low quality questions to be posted?

Now, obviously the first knee jerk response to that question is *because, Carrie (you stupid head), there's no real pragmatic way to tell what's a dupe (duh)*. This is true, but, there are ways to thwart new comers from posting who haven't (re)searched their problem(s). I personally believe that new comers have way too little responsibility when it comes to asking questions. After all, we (the community and stack overflow as a whole) are providing them something for *nothing*.

### Shouldn't asking questions be a (sort of) privilege now?

In the beginning, Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood created a place for anyone with any skill level to ask their programming questions and be heard. These same people could, in turn, answer questions. As many of you know, this idea not only worked, it became an amazingly successful place and almost some kind of FAQ for common and uncommon problems that the community (and their inner communities) faces.

Stack Overflow is established now. Isn't there room for improvement when it comes to the privileges we afford new (and possibly low-rep) users? AFAIK, currently new users can come in and ask questions with the minimum requirements being

- a title with at least 15 characters
- a body with at least 30 characters
- at least one tag
- (possibly captcha but I don't really know the rules regarding this)

Now, I am not suggesting that we disallow new users from asking questions but I do have a few ideas that aim to slow down the asking process and enable users to solve their own questions.

---

### Force a new user to view (click) at least {n} similar questions before submitting

Right now, when you start to ask a question, after typing a title it will provide the list of questions that are related. Are there any checks to see if the user views any of these questions before proceeding to submitting their question?

Keep in mind that new comers don't **know** how Stack Overflow works. *wtf is a dupe and why do i care when i have this super important problem?!?* They don't care about that and aren't interested in contributing and taking care of Stack Overflow (at this point)  **and that's okay!** They're allowed that, but I think we should really press them that Stack Overflow possibly has an answer to their question.

Maybe we put more emphasis on the "Questions that may already have your answer" box. One way to do this is to minimize the question when they click the <kbd>Post Your Question</kbd> button and start one boxing related questions similar to a review queue where they have to view the question/answers for {n} amount of time before review the next one and they have to review {n} amount of questions before posting the question.

### Require a survey concerning what a new user has tried, researched, included, etc.

Probably one of the biggest annoyances for regulars are questions that show absolutely no research effort. When I was new(er), I would usually post some snappy comment because I was disgusted that OP didn't show the same respect for this sanctuary as me. I wanted OP to know that this was a silly way to treat an amazing tool and they should be internet-reprimanded! Fortunately, I realized this approach accomplished little to nothing and grew out of that but the problem still remains rampant with little resistance.

Providing a sort of *survey* during the question asking process can accomplish a lot if polished correctly. Depending on links and word combinations included in the title, body and tags, we can ask pointed questions.

A few quick examples:

- **Have you looked at the documentation of included tools and languages?**

  - Yes:

    > Include the documentation you've read that's related to your problem and explain what's lacking or how it is not helping
  - No:

    > Consider reading documentation, if any. This will help you narrow down your problem and if it still exists afterward, it will also help you narrow down your problem.
- **Can you provide code that replicates the problem?** (this question will have some [tag] dependency but can probably be generalized)

  - Yes(generalized):

    > Then include it! Try to narrow down your problem to the smallest amount so that others can narrow down the problem without digging through a lot of code. This process will also help you debug your code.
  - Yes (tag specific, for example [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)/[js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js)/[css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) related)

    > Then include it! A visual example usually helps others identify your problem as well. Consider using a tool like {playground IDE link} to help show your problem to others.
  - No:

    > Why not? If code is not related make sure your question is on topic for stack overflow [link]. (a lot more can be implied by this. This could break down into another series of questions)

A lot of these questions would benefit from a flow-chart kind of breakdown. A few things this does:

1. Push the asker to drill down into the problem and provide necessary links, code, explanations, inline examples, reproduced online IDE examples
2. Possibly provides OP with a generalized debugging process that helps them find the answer without ever posting
3. Sets a standard of what we expect in order for you to post a question
4. Saves the new user from being torn to pieces with downvotes and facetious comments

None of the survey questions would really stop a user from asking, but I think they should require an answer. Ideally, it should slow down the asker from submitting and push them to build a *worthy* question.

### Add a delay between when a new user submits a question and when it's public

I see *a lot* of questions that go something like this:

> i am having a problem with *x* and cannot figure it out
>
> edited 6 minutes later
>
> oh! i found the solution and it was so stupid >:( silly me! {link to stack overflow dupe that was most likely in the related questions list}

My thoughts on this is that OP really just needed to type (think) out his/her problem and really analyze the problem in a way that they could explain it to others (and in a way themselves). We could possibly even have a queue similar to how the low quality review queue works where the questions could be semi-public for those who care enough to review and specifically search for duplicates. If duplicates are found, the OP can be notified:

> here's a possible solution {dupe link}

and not

> possible duplicate {dupe link}

because, again, new comers don't know/care what duplicates are. They want solutions. Wording is everything.

Then, the question be *recommended* as a possible duplicate (or possibly close vote depending on the reputation of the reviewer). There could  even be a way for a user to "mark" a suggested possible dupe as a solution to streamline the process.

Here's a list of immediately obvious pros and cons: (I'm sure there's more of both)

Pros:

- Allow the user to think through their problem without polluting SO
- Free up users from reading/solving trivial problems that already have an answer
- Stop the idea from forming in new users' minds that SO is a place where they can do little to nothing and keep receiving solutions (this is fueled, in part, by answerers and is another discussion entirely, but I still feel its semi-relevant to point out)
- Clean up the new questions feed
- Puts more value into thorough research since the asker is unable to immediately yield results from questions

Cons:

- What if a user does find the  solution in the time that the question is *delayed*  but it is useful and should be shared? How is this handled?
- Robo reviewers gon robo review
- Does the review queue stop it from being public or is there a strict time limit? What are weights of these things? ie what happens if a review is never made and its past the time limit?
- Do we really need another scary review queue on the already heavily burdened community?
- Potentially stops a high percentage of new comers from asking because they're impatient (not sure this is necessarily a con)
- **In essence, we've just turned into the asker's specially altered, human search engine**

---

### Overall TL;DR: Let's do *something*

I am open to criticism (implying I have a choice, hah!) and other solutions and realize that all of the ones I've proposed have cons. I really believe that we can do more to put a dent in the flood of low quality questions and duplicate questions that flood Stack Overflow every day.

Our highest contributing members are becoming more and more inactive and we have to place some blame on this topic. In my humble opinion, it is time to at least *try* to address it.

Comment: remember that according to many of the "elite" here you're a new user who shouldn't be allowed to ask questions because your rep is under 10k (or fill in arbitrary number). At least that's the idea I get from many similar meta topics, the hostility against people with lower than 10k (or fill in number) is massive among some.

Comment: If such a system is implemented, users who have high enough rep to not be forced to use it should be able to opt-in and out at will. This way, high-rep users will be able to try the system out and discuss it intelligently on Meta, as well as help out new users who have questions about the system.

Comment: @jwenting This is stupid. We don't have problems with people who have low rep. We have problems with people who are ruining the site.

Comment: @kapa I see a LOT of high rep people scorning people with low rep. They're automatically considered useless, their questions automatically downvoted or mindlessly voted to close, people assume anything written by someone with less than 10k rep (or whatever they themselves have) is wrong, uninteresting, not worthy of attention. There's even been topics that demanded effectively that questions by low rep people not be shown at all, or be automatically lowered in the search rankings so they "don't bother people".

Comment: @jwenting Most questions posted are unfortunately wrong, uninteresting, not worthy of attention. This has nothing to do with rep. I upvote good questions by lowrep people, and I see others doing the same. People should simply read the help section and ask good questions instead of blaming everything on a highreps vs lowreps conspiracy theory.

Comment: I like the idea of having the "Ask a Question template" being optional. A new user can choose whether or not to use the template but if they don't use it and their question is subsequently closed then they are forced to use the template for all future question. Or a high rep user can toggle the users "free text question" privileges off until they ask a well received question.

Comment: @CarrieKendall I have no idea why this was closed as a duplicate, it obviously is not a duplicate of the target. Though it is interesting to see that the first close voter is the author of the target question. I smell something fishy there.

Comment: @TinyGiant I am so burnt out with the over-moderation of this community that I didn't even cast a reopen vote, hah.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have ***some*** of this in the works, although we're looking at implementations that are slightly different than what you describe. I'll jump into what we *have* working right now:

- A new Triage queue, where new questions are quickly sorted into those that are fine as-is, those that need some work, but are otherwise okay and unlikely to be closed as anything but a duplicate, and those that are just not going to be okay without a Herculean effort. The outcome of triage heavily effects how visible any given question will be unless acted upon.
- Badges to providing incentive for folks *answering* questions to also take a moment and improve the question if possible, since by answering they've shown that they clearly understand the question and are in a good position to edit it
- Allowing anyone with a gold tag badge to mark anything having that tag as a duplicate with a single vote. Tangentially, the success we saw here is leading us to investigate other tag-based privileges.

This is all working quite well. The next piece is a special queue for those that want to spend time helping new users with questions that can clearly be understood with a bit of work, but need editing in order to become permanent fixtures of the site and attract experts willing to answer. While sometimes leaving just a comment or answering the question yourself is enough to help something over the edge - *almost all of these* are going to need editing. This caused us to sit down to work on an editing interface that actually helps editors but doesn't get in their way.

***The following mock-up is not carved in stone, and Is not yet ready for commenting. It's provided for illustrative purposes only.***

[image: WIP]

That's not done, it needs more, it needs extensive testing and it needs less text (I did say less). When you're competing with text boxes where people can type stuff for a user's attention, *every single word you can shave off your copy matters*.

If this works well, and we think it will, we're going to explore an *optional* guided version of the ask question page - more guided than what we currently have. It will be strongly suggested that you use it *if*:

- You appear to be having a difficult time submitting your question due to formatting, code ratio, tags, etc
- You have a short (e.g. 2) history of asking questions with at least one
- There's a strong, *recent* history of people coming from your network posting low-quality questions. We see quite a few offices full of people get it totally wrong, and educating even *one* there can have a massive impact

No, It's not a wizard - at least not in the sense of what you'd expect from one. Wizards have some flaws, such as giving you an expectation that everything will go well if you simply complete the steps - *that's* why I've resisted trying them.

The trick is *guiding*. We ask people to give us a title, we don't really do a good job of letting them know that bad titles cause their question to never be seen by someone that can probably answer it. Hence - yes, more is planned, some of it touches on points you provided here, so [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) it goes.

Learn more about the new queue [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue).

Comment: This looks like a real step in the right direction. I'm really excited to see how this will pan out. I am.. hesitant of an opt-out _guide_ but, I think this is definitely a great start.

Comment: How do these questions end up in the special queue? I am assuming _Needs Improvement_ from the triage will kick off to this new queue?

Comment: That's it precisely, _needs improvement_. We've been testing how well folks would actually sort stuff once we implemented triage as this system kind of hinges on accuracy there, and they have been spot-on almost all the time. Stuff in this queue will (for the most part) just need a little help to be good, while the real garbage that wastes people's time gets very little visibility and is ultimately closed / removed.

Comment: I'm not married to opt-in (as it would be strongly suggested that you _do_ opt-in based on criteria) - we have to test it pretty extensively to find out. It's my next project after the help & improvement queue, so I'll try it a few ways to see what makes the most impact.

Comment: Well, that seems reasonable. Do the posts stay open when moving from queue to edit by OP? Or does it get put on hold and queue for reopening after editing?

Comment: They stay open. A message will be shown to anyone about to edit the post, asking them to be thorough because it was identified as needing improvement. Something will also be shown to encourage editing to anyone answering the question, also citing that the post was identified as in need of some improvement and we could use their (apparent) understanding of the question and expertise if they can spare another few minutes. It's a pretty gentle yet effective system, if it works as well as we hope it does.

Comment: As I understand it, we're supposed to click Should Be Improved if the question would be answerable after an edit _even if that edit must come from the asker_.  That means editors may need to ask the asker for more information.  I'd hate to be stuck in that queue waiting for a comment reply.  Are we supposed to just comment and leave?  (I often comment from triage which seems just as good.)  Maybe add an 'invite user to chat' link to that interface?

Answer (score 151):

I fully support the idea of a "new question wizard" type of approach for low rep/new users. It does not need to be as structured as you suggest, but I think you are absolutely correct that it would help both weed out facepalm-style questions (Oh! I found the problem, and fixed it), it would also give the would-be question asker something far more valuable: the basis of the debugging process. Teach a man to fish sort of thing.

If you already have such skills, and you've examined the problem well enough to ask a lucid, good-quality question, that's great! Robert seems to optimistically credit our new question askers with a higher average skill than evidence suggests they have. The fact is, a majority of the new questions benefit from comments asking very basic, preliminary questions that the interface could ask instead.

The "wizard" shouldn't be a bunch of required hoops, and as long as that's the case, gathering pertinent details would not be burdensome to the hypothetical experienced programmer asking a question for the first time. They'll just fill in the boxes. If this process was a sort of question composer, then it wouldn't be a waste of time to fill it all in. You could also give an opt-out route to go to the basic/standard question interface --the new users we're targeting are unlikely to switch to "advanced mode" if they aren't confident and comfortable with the process here.

Your example survey is a good idea. If the user went through a 4-5 step process, and at the end, their answers were compiled and posted as the question body (last step can be "Anything else to add? Please don't add signatures or "thanks in advance" here), then it isn't a waste of time or a barrier at all.

---

I wanted to add a point I made in chat discussing this:

We can't have it both ways. Either we want question quantity to decrease and quality to increase, or we want quantity of any sort.

If the latter, then the amount of [hand-wringing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow) and belly-aching over quality and tone doesn't jive.

If the former, then we must be prepared to raise the front-end expectations for newer users, because that is the source of most of the low-quality questions. *Even if this drives away a fraction of our users*

---

I'm spitballing here; please don't get wrapped up in trivial details. This is a mockup of what I envision:

[image: Step 1, ask the question]
[image: Step 2, forced review of other answers]
[image: Step 3, guided collection of details]
[image: Step 4, preview and tag, forcing review of what you're actually asking]

We aren't asking for any more information than we already do; we're just putting the brakes on a little. By dedicating the entire screen to reviewing questions by title, then reviewing answers, THEN entering in your own question, we're asking the poster to really examine each part of their question individually.

When you just show someone a text box, they're going to fill that text box. The current question intake form shows the duplicates, but who is looking at that when you've got a giant text box to fill? So you separate them into steps. First I'm asking a question. Now, I see some answers, but they don't work. NOW I type in details, and these are the specific details I need to include.

Comment: Don't really understand your edit, especially about the hand-wringing and belly-aching.

Comment: There is a lot of angst on meta right now about question quality, and the tone high rep users take with low-rep users concerning lower quality questions. If we want to change that situation, we must be willing to raise expectations on the source of the problem -- the people asking questions. If we aren't willing to do that because it might prevent people from asking, then it is illogical to be so concerned about quality. If our approach invites quantity over quality, we cannot be upset when we receive the quantity.

Comment: Now with mockups.

Comment: Sick mockups, I really love this. Thanks for spending the time to make a mock up. If it were an option, I'd choose to use this kind of system when asking a question.

Comment: Quora does something like this for duplicates.  But their process is better than ours; they ask for the title of the question *first* ("what's your question") before allowing the user to type in the body, which not only makes for better question titles, but also makes it easier for their search engine to look for duplicates.  Many good Quora questions consist *only of titles.*

Comment: then we're doinitwrong

Comment: That is what I took this proposal to intend. Slow down, break it into steps, and isolate the "look at what we already have" phase from the part where you add your question.

Comment: Perhaps this forum can only apply to questions using mostly tags a user has not used before. That way it'd apply to users [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435199/css3-transorm-rectangle-to-trapezoid) who have some reputation but still ask poor questions

Comment: You **are** asking for more (and should be IMO). You're asking that they fill out all of the vital and important parts of a valid question. You're asking that they formulate their scrambled thoughts into a coherent question. The current system doesn't ask for that. It asks for a title, body, tag and it also makes you scroll through a help page concerning asking.

Comment: I find most of the questions that answer the question I'm writing in the list of duplicates you have at step 1.  However, sometimes they have completely different titles from the title I picked.  I've noticed when I start writing in the question body it continues to update that list, and half the time I don't see an actual question that matches mine until I'm almost done.  The downside to having the list first is it can be less relevant to the actual question.

Comment: This is a really neat idea, perhaps it will help with the "Show me the codez" 2 line questions as well (probably not, but I can be optimistic :) )

Comment: Great idea. I like this very much. I see a problem with this approach, though - it all depends on the quality of the title. "My program doesnt working. HELP URGENT!!" won't be able to find any useful duplicates (just like it doesn't today). Maybe there's a way to assess the descriptiveness of the title (for example by examining how many votes similar titles received previously).

Comment: Brilliant idea, in the mockups.  It slows down the act of asking questions, which discourages trivial questions.  It also results in a stronger case for question closure.  Missing one of the Details fields?  Close it, unless it's an extraordinary case.  One comment, however, is that the ability to toggle the wizard should be gained as a privilege.  Once you contribute significantly to SO, it can probably be assumed you understand what makes a question good, how to ask it, and how to find duplicates.

Comment: One problem I don't think this answer addresses, as far as finding duplicates, is that an inexperienced programmer could read a question that answers their slightly different problem, and not recognize that they have the answer already.  As an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447753/iterate-through-lists-in-a-file .  It's a good question.  It would fill the criteria in your mockups, for sure.  The asker even searched using Google, which indexes SO, and likely led him to related questions.  Nonetheless, this question has been answered many times before.

Comment: If this were to be implemented, or any other "jump through hoops" for new users, I would want the criteria for a "new" user to be based on the *highest rep from any site*. If a new user comes from Programmers with 10K, I don't see the point in forcing them to do this.

Comment: Honestly, if we're going to be serious about improving question quality, then we should take a serious look at replacing the built-in Elastic Search engine with results from Google itself, when helping users look for questions that have already been asked. Google is still far superior for finding results on [main]. I just about never use the internal search engine.

Comment: See also [How to figure out if a SO question is viable prior to posting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252327/456814). Someone was designing a process much like this proposed a week or two earlier.

Comment: @Phox: I'm not sure that scenario you gave is necessarily a bad one. First, it would happen much less frequently, so closing such questions as duplicates would be less burdensome for the community. Second, and more important, the asker would learn what terminology to use in the future. If the asker didn't recognize the answer to their question, then they probably have a gap in their knowledge about what things are called, and having a question marked as a duplicate is a for them to learn what to look for in the future.

Comment: As a new guy I would _love_ this sort of a wiz(z)ard. Not being able to ask questions _well_ because _I_ didn't know what was expected of me has been one of two big headaches and sources of irritation to other members and me as well. For example, one is used to say hi and thanks, and without a concise explanation, the _switched politeness rules_ are not easy to grasp. And the dupes, and the jsfiddles, and the lot... I don't find my questions that bad, but hadn't I _incidentally_ discovered the meta, I would have left covered in self-loath on the first day...

Comment: As @Cupcake pointed out, I've been working on a similar wizard offsite to help new users craft good questions. I've spent a lot of time thinking about this - my only concern with my/your wizard approach is if stack will just have the new problem of very nicely structured bad questions. It could be the case that giving a user 9 textboxes to fill out simply yields more garbage to edit once a question is posted. I also agree with cupcake that a simple Google search yields much better results than the SO site itself, even in the case of using the API to try to find similar questions.

Comment: @TimPietzcker In my version of this wizard [How to figure if a question is viable prior to posting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252327/456814) I use Bayesian Inference on the question title to solve that problem. Stack Exchange sites are perfect for this type of probability analysis because every question is scored. In your example, "My program doesnt working. HELP URGENT!!", a simple analysis would yield that it has **Negative Sentiment**, **Basic Readability**, **Low Score Average**, **Bad Spelling and Grammar**, and **Neutral Subjectivity**, which equals don't post this question.

Comment: Not sure about removing closed questions but questions without answers should probably not be in there...

Comment: This looks good, but I would suggest to include showing the asker to the tag wiki FAQ too, if applicable.

Comment: "Questions that may already have your answer" Fine, sort by vote, but also allow users to sort by relevance if they want. The most relevant question/answer might not be a popular or common one, so it might not have enough upvotes to be on the first page of results.

Comment: @TylerH At that point, you're searching. Use the search interface. The intention here is to catch people that did not (and will not) search.

Comment: @Chris actually, there is another meta discussion going on about how the suggested Q&A search function is leaps and bounds beyond the actual Search function in terms of usefulness.

Comment: Yes, please! I started to write up a question similar to this one, but the "similar questions" sidebar saved me. :) Good points worth extracting from this answer and its long comment thread: titles are easier to analyze for common-dupe potential than entire posts, making the "wizard" optional (default for low-rep-across-all-sites),  highlighting the tag wiki.

Comment: Perhaps adding a 'cool-down' to each button. You can't just enter '.' and then press 'next' you've got to wait say 5 seconds, maybe more if it looks like you're rushing.

Answer (score 16):

Here's my take on some of these things.

#### Duplicate questions

For those questions that are frequently and repeatedly asked, we should be creating a General Reference question (a.k.a. Canonical Question) and closing those as dupes of the General Reference question.  Good examples of reference questions are [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php), and [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).  Reference questions can be cited in the Tag Wiki for the main tag (i.e. Java, PHP).

For all other duplicates that are posted, just close them as duplicates.  *Make sure that they are actual duplicate questions,* not "Your answer is over here."  That's the moral equivalent of posting a Link-Only Answer, and we all know how much we love those.

#### Minimum Requirements for Questions

In addition to the ones you cited, there's already a sophisticated Question Quality Filter that looks at things like punctuation and sentence structure.  Many questions never actually make it to the front page, because they don't get past this filter.  Question block eventually stop the ones who manage to ask low quality questions, despite the filter.

#### What have you tried?

This has never been a requirement for asking questions on Stack Overflow, and should not be.  If a user can compose a well-crafted, lucid, on-topic question that is of relevance to other programmers, it deserves to be answered.  Frankly, `icanhazcodez` questions don't bother me all that much, provided the question isn't too broad.  Obviously, we're not going to write their entire program for them, but if we can provide a code snippet, why not?  Code snippets help everyone; they are the *actual* currency of Stack Overflow, not reputation points.

#### Force new user to [jump through more hoops]

If I am a software professional who already knows how to ask a good question, why should I put up with this the first time I come here?  We don't need this, and here's why: *we already have good systems for dealing with new users who can't form a complete sentence,* if we will just avail ourselves of them.

New users are already required to read a page with tips on how to ask a good question.  There's a checkbox at the bottom that they have to check, indicating that they have read and understood these tips.  Adding new hoops just means the user will ignore a few more things before they can ask their question.

Also, not to put too fine a point on this, but the material that new users are presented with is supposed to show us on our best behavior.  Which face do you want to present, the one that says "welcome, and we hope you succeed in being productive here," or the one that says "go away, we really don't want you here?"  We can't be *too* insular.

#### What is the one thing that we can do to vastly improve question quality?

- Close questions.  Close questions, close questions, close questions.

  We have 24,000 people on Stack Overflow who have vote to close abilities.  Why aren't more questions getting closed? Because we're constantly debating whether or not we're being fair to people, giving them a grace period to fix their questions, and arguing with them about their objections to closing.   We already have a grace period; it's called "on hold."  Let the system work.

#### Code Dump, How Fix (aka My Code Doesn't Work)

In my opinion, this is *by far the single biggest problem on Stack Overflow right now.* Instead of a resource that benefits all programmers, we've turned Stack Overflow into a troubleshooting tool that only benefits the question asker.

There's no other way to say this: *you should be closing these questions.*  There should be a general expectation that users who come to the site with their code problems should have *already performed some basic troubleshooting on their code first.*  They should be ready to tell us what the exact wording of the error message that they're getting is, and on which line of code they're getting the error.

They should be prepared to go back and do some more troubleshooting on their code if that's what they need to do.  We can point them in the right direction, but their question still needs to be closed.  And it needs to be closed *now,* folks.  Not five minutes from now, or an hour from now, when the OP fails to provide the needed information. **Now.**  Use your close vote privileges; let the system work.

Of course, on those questions where the OP has provided enough information to figure out the problem from the question itself, by all means, go ahead and answer it.  But if the user just dumps some code and says "it doesn't work," close their question as "Insufficient information to diagnose problem."

Comment: Thanks for your views on this. Especially the minimum requirements clarification.

Comment: and to clarify, I am not saying (nor trying to imply) the current system doesn't work. It does. I would argue that it doesn't work efficiently. The main reason, IMO, is that we assume new users are professional software developers who know how to debug their problems (to some extent) and have arrived at a stopping point. That, however, has some very relative, opinion-based presumptions. The suggestions I've made take the assumption out of asking questions for new comers.

Comment: in reference to "jumping through hoops": Why is it a bad thing to make a new comer verify that they've made as much effort that they're in turn asking people to make on their behalf when posting a question?

Comment: I've clarified that portion of my answer.  With respect to the main reason: the main reason, IMO, is because the community doesn't fully avail itself of the tools it already has.  There are a number of reasons for this; combat fatigue is one of them.  Differing opinions on what should be closed is another.

Comment: I still feel like you're focusing on the current system and its tools being the only tools that are necessary. These **are** necessary and they work. I am suggesting that we put more responsibility on new users as well as reviewers.

Comment: The way you do that is by downvoting and closing their questions and (optionally) explaining how they can make them better.  New users who ask bad questions dive into the deep end without reading the Help Center for the same reasons that make them bad programmers.  The only way you can change behavior like that is by *imposing consequences* (not by simply wagging more fingers), and the way you do that is by downvoting and closing their questions.  I am saying that the system isn't working as well as it should right now because people aren't using it correctly.  We need to fix that first.

Comment: Also, to further my point, the fact the community (and let's be specific, **reviewers**) doesn't fully avail itself of the tools is further proof that these tools aren't working regardless of the reason(s) (possibly fatigue, ignorance, etc)

Comment: Yes, but you have to figure out whether these are tools problems are people problems.  You can't conflate the two, and I submit that the tools are already adequate, for the most part, if people would just use them properly.  The Review Tools were created to draw more people into the moderation process, but what we may have overlooked is that the people who are most qualified to moderate were *already involved before we put in the review tools.*  In other words, because they expressed an interest, they also took an interest in learning how to do it correctly, not in earning badges.

Comment: This is sort of how I read that: _If the community that makes the website work doesn't know how to adequately apply and use its tools, then it is the community who is flawed._ Is this what you mean or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes.  In no small part, it is our fault.  Closing people's questions that don't meet site standards is not mean, cruel or heartless; it is *the way things are done here.*

Comment: I just don't understand the resistance to putting more responsibility on new **askers**

Comment: When the Question Ban system was put into place, it was based on a fundamental guiding principle: *most users who get banned will never reform.*  If you believe this (as I do), then putting up more hoops is simply pointless.  We've given them a help system, a "how to ask" page that they must agree to, and a comment system for community members to guide them, and *they ignore all of that.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: We already close them. At least using the [tag:cv-ring] on the PHP room, we can close a question as early as it's discovered, generally 3-4 minutes after it was posted. The problem is, for every question you close, two more take its place. Our users max out their CV count daily. The system does not work. We are outnumbered, and given insufficient tools. Don't forget that unlike mods, we have a limit on how many closevotes we may cast a day. Some of us hang out on the close review queue as well.

Comment: @SecondRikudo: Perhaps it's time to give high-rep users some binding close votes.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you're willing to consider giving more responsibility to those who gain nothing (personally) ie reviewers, but stand against giving more responsibility to new comers who stand to gain a lot from asking questions?

Comment: Not reviewers.  High-rep users.  People who have been on the site for an extended period of time and understand how the system works.  New users don't have this capacity; you propose to give people responsibility who have no authority or knowledge (and who are not sufficiently motivated to get it).

Comment: Tag-based "mini-mods" is a thing. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252586/regarding-the-stack-overflow-close-review-queue/252603#252603 :)

Comment: @Chris: That's not a feature request; I'm writing one up now.

Comment: Actually, you're specifically referring to reviewers if you're relying on the tools you've mentioned.

Comment: The tools are just a way to provide visibility to those who have moderation privileges.  I wouldn't give binding votes to all of those people (the rep requirement would be higher than that).

Comment: Can you expand on why you think expecting more from new comers is a bad idea? I am not saying that altering current tools is a bad idea, but I do feel it isn't on topic.

Comment: Can you better explain how making new users jump through more hoops before asking their first question will alter their behavior?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders ?

Comment: Well, the survey idea offers a different perspective of giving them exact instruction on what they should be doing and could be customized (by the community, even) by tag. This is an alternative that suggests people can learn with the right guidance. I fear that you might have a black and white view on new users and it isn't realistic. If we can help the {n} amount of users who simply don't know the expectations of stack overflow, what is the loss (this is not meant to be rhetoric)? A more complex system?

Comment: Also, some of my suggestions could be altered so that the ban is placed without a horrid question ever reaching the public eye.

Comment: @CarrieKendall: It's based on a lot of experience, and I was here during the dark times, before the filters were put into place.  In case I haven't made it crystal clear, I don't think giving new users more information (or changing the way that information is presented) is going to help.  They already have enough information available to  them to become productive community members.  The problem lies not with the information, it lies with **them and their thinking process.**  You're not going to change 18 years of conditioning with a survey.

Comment: So, don't change them. But force them to adhere to our question standards.

Comment: That's what downvotes and close votes are for.  And the whole idea of a ghetto for new users until they can graduate to the main site is a non-starter.  You can't address bad questions without touching them in some way first; that's just the way it is.

Comment: Giving new users more information to read does not solve the problem. To most new users the FAQ is TL;DR; and they don't even bother reading a sentence from it. Putting more text for them to read will just make it more of a thing to ignore. However, forcing them to go through a series of steps which basically indoctrinates them into forming good questions would help.

Comment: We reward help vampires (with solutions) because the system is flawed to reward those who only seek to answer and receive rep (regardless of question quality). So, the way I see it, you either punish those who would reward these vampires, or you stop (or slow down) the vampires before they can be rewarded. Burdening the community with this task isn't working efficiently.

Comment: @CarrieKendall: The way you take rep from people who answer bad questions is to close the questions so that they can be deleted.

Comment: Is that how it works with duplicates (this one is rhetorical :P)?

Comment: «Which face do you want to present, the one that says "welcome, and we hope you succeed in being productive here," or the one that says "go away, we really don't want you here?"» How does a question template constitute the latter, @Robert? It might irritate some first-time askers, if they're already capable of asking a solid question, but it won't _stop_ them asking, and for others, "Wait a second. Do you have X piece of info? Okay, put that in the question" might be just the nudge they need to be successful here. And then there are those who are helpless, and it won't affect them at all.

Comment: Just to provide an example, the point @JoshCaswell is making is proven all the time with comments like "please include code", "can you provide an example?" etc. The majority of the ones I come across ends with OP trying to provide the code in a comment that gets community edited into the question. And keep in mind, people leave down votes for this.. inb4 read the faq

Comment: @CarrieKendall: What does that have to do with any of this?  Not all questions require code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Read over the second example in my "survey" suggestion. That's true and a survey shouldn't enforce that you include code, but suggesting that they include code and giving examples could help in this area. Many users just don't know to include it and have to be informed.

Comment: @CarrieKendall: I think you've glossed over a very important point I've tried to make.  *People don't change their behavior from suggestions; they change it from consequences.*  There are no consequences for skipping a template.  Questions that ask for code troubleshooting without providing code should be notified in a comment that they need code, and then the question needs to be **immediately closed** while the OP provides that code.

Comment: The suggestions I've proposed alter what these people are allowed to do. We require that they meet {n} requirements before being given the privilege of asking experts, for free, to provide insight to their problem. I am not trying to gloss over your point. I just don't think we're on the same page. I don't intend to change them. I do, however, intend on thwarting them from having access to people who can solve their problems. I also don't believe there are users who will never change and perfect users (ie black and white). There **is** a gray area that you refuse to notice. (1/2)

Comment: There are people who just don't know. There are young people who didn't know it wasn't _"cool"_ to say "thanks bro" at the end. There are people who have spent a lot of time on forums who don't know that the answer box isn't a reply box. These people aren't intentionally bad and quite frankly I have no more interest than they do in reading the super long F̶A̶Q̶ help center. (2/2)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I made a cheesy mockup of what I see the proposal as. I may not have nailed it, but I think the idea is imparted. We aren't creating new hoops, we are increasing the burden on the asker to actually jump through the hoops instead of running around them. This is accomplished by isolating the hoops into steps.

Comment: @CarrieKendall re: your rhetorical question about duplicates.  Duplicates don't bother me all that much, unless it's a question that is asked repeatedly and frequently.  If it was worth asking the first time....

Comment: Then its worth searching the first time

Comment: See my comment below the mockup.

Comment: As a total _freshman_ here at SO, the _go away, we really don't want you here?_ message is what I actually got after trying to answer the first bunch of questions (I really started with answering before posting my own questions). The way the system is set up right now isn't welcoming at all, opposite to all the _come among us_ singns all over the place. A nice guide to asking, and answering, would be,  ... _nice_, really. Because there are really just too many unsaid rules to everything, that the _gimmetehcodez_ with tough skin are the only bunch to remain coming in, as I see it.

Comment: @PavelPetrman: The guide you're referring to is [here](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).  It is referenced at the bottom of [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), along with a half-dozen articles (one written by Jon Skeet) that describe how to ask questions the right way.  The problem is not that the material does not exist; it does.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Thank you for the link, definitely something to read and adhere to. By the _guide_, however, I meant the Guiding process envisaged by Chris up above. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @PavelPetrman: That process seems to be mostly about identifying duplicates, a problem I've also addressed in my answer..

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is that all you see in Chris's answer? Your last comment makes me sad in so many ways. :(

Comment: @CarrieKendall: To a certain extent, I think focusing on question duplication is looking at the wrong problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, this line "Instead of a resource that benefits all programmers, we've turned Stack Overflow into a troubleshooting tool that only benefits the question asker." echoes my sentiment.  Thanks for articulating it.  More like this would be well received.

Comment: I feel like we should also be pointing "Code Dump, How Fix" questions to canonical Q&As as well.

Comment: Honestly, as a new user, I love this idea. When I first came to SO I had no idea how it worked, I was used to forums, so I posted the "wall of code" or "I want to do x, discuss" type questions, and they kept getting closed, and I didn't know why, I read all the documentation, but I wasn't really clear why my questions were getting closed and downvoted, I saw SO as an elitist, unhelpful community. I wholeheartedly agree with a "New Question Wizard" that guides new users through a basic debugging process while also constructing a well thought out question

Answer (score 5):

I think the "New question wizard" is the right approach. It's the best of both worlds, helping users find answers more quickly while also filtering out junk questions and reducing duplication.

I would add to Chris's proposal: Users should see a list of "Similar or Related Questions" twice -- once after writing the title, and again after writing the question itself. Each time, they'd have an opportunity to revise the title (or title + question body) to clarify what they're looking for.

This may answer their question, so they wouldn't post a duplicate, or would give them more information to work with, so they could click "Edit" and write a better-informed question.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing duplicates is something that is perpetually on our radar. One effort we are currently working on to help with that is the Staging Ground. We believe this will help reduce the overall number of duplicates that go public.

However, we don't see any of the suggested approaches here to mitigate duplicates as options we will pursue. Hence the status decline tag on this request.

Answer (score -3):

Main points in bold.

I've read several different questions that all address the same thing (low quality questions on SO) and all the ideas that I've read so far are dealing with preventing low quality questions from getting into SO. But what if we approached this problem from another direction. **What if we shielded high rep users from low quality questions?**

I was reading a question posted in Meta about someone not knowing the community-imposed guidelines of SO (stuff that isn't necessarily outlined in the help, but things you will get down-voted for). Understandably he was frustrated for being down-voted for what he thought were good questions. I think for most of us, we experienced this when we first started posting on SO. But we learned and now we know. But the gap between new people and experienced SO users is wider now, and the tolerance is lower.

**This whole situation makes me think of an MMORPG.** When you first start out, you're put in a "newbie" area with other newbies where you can learn the game without any real consequences if you do something wrong. Eventually you progress out of that area into the real game, and of course it becomes harder and more complex, but you also get to do a lot more stuff. But most of the game is still unavailable to you until you have leveled up a ways. You see "end-game" characters walking around, and you might even interact with them a bit, but can't level with them. You have to level with people your own level and in dungeons that you can handle. Eventually you reach "end game" and you are now one of those characters with all the cool gear that the newbs see walking around. But it's not just your character that has leveled. And it's not just about the gear. You have also changed. You know much more about the game than when you started. And what you did when you were level 1 or level 5 or level 10 is no longer interesting when you are level 50.

**So instead of expecting new SO users to act like veteran users, why not create a "newbie" area on SO where the new users can answer the questions on Stack Overflow from other new users?** After they have answered a few questions, you won't need to explain to them what the rules are and why they are important--they will know for themselves. People who aren't SO newbs would not see the newb questions unless some limit had been reached (time, up votes, etc.). After a while, these people would attain the required reputation to move them into the full Stack Overflow site where their questions are seen by everyone. At this point, they know the rules and the only way they get to this point is by following the rules.

Comment: As to your last point, I would *strongly* suggest that you read [Should we fork Stack Overflow for beginning programmers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254381/289086) and its [associated dups and linked questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/254381?lq=1).  This has been suggested many times and is not seen as a good idea.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't seen those in my searches.  Maybe I will move this answer to one of those.  But in any case, the objections to those questions are based on people "projecting" what they think will happen based on their experience.  Which is fine in the absence of better information, but this is a model that has already been proven.  So the question isn't "will it work" because we already know it works.  The question is does the model apply in this situation.  And I haven't seen that addressed anywhere.

Comment: *"What if we shielded high rep users from low quality questions?"* that doesn't work unless you can identify that a question is low quality! I find it difficult now days to downvote a low quality question without it receiving sympathy upvotes.

Comment: I think the idea is fine, but it should instead by tiered by the *type of requirements* imposed to maintain top quality. E.g. at the top level, only questions that are either migrated by gold-badge holders from the second-top level, or written and self-answered by same.