# Give more attention to user-identified duplicates

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

There are many proposals for changing the rep incentives associated with closing vs answering duplicates. But they either (1) can be gamed, or (2) penalize users who put work into answers on interesting niche questions, for which the duplicate was hard to find.

I have two suggestions, which I'll post separately to allow separate voting. The other is

- [Help askers find duplicates before the question becomes public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253339/103167)

Part of the problem with the duplicate identification workflow is that the OP can't do much to expedite the process.  At best they can leave a comment responding to a duplicate "Yeah, that answered my question".

For experts too, evaluating duplicates requires leaving the page.

I think we can improve this situation, and also rebalance the rep issues, with a simple concept (yes, it'll be a rather invasive change to the code I'm sure):

Display suggested duplicates as if they are answers.  Include an excerpt like appears when a question/answer is linked in chat, or like appears in the close-as-duplicate UI.

[image]

[image]

Let the finder add some explanation.  Let other users leave comments why it seems to be a false duplicate.  Accept up- AND down-votes on the duplicate suggestion.  And add the checkbox for the OP to accept an identified duplicate as "THE ANSWER" if they choose.  And the proposer of the duplicate can also delete it, if the question gets clarified and becomes clearly different.

Votes for duplicates won't award as much reputation as on answers, but there will be a little.  The green checkmark I think should carry full value.

The `[duplicate]` tag gets appended to the question title if an suggested duplicate gets either a green checkmark or more than 5 net votes.

Less sure about this part, but I think the highest-voted duplicate should be displayed above all other answers, and other duplicates can be mixed in with the answers according to vote count, newness, or whatever is the viewer's chosen sort order.

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166844/show-duplicate-suggestions-as-answers  
(Oh the irony)

Comment: @Servy: different meta site... keeps it out of the possible duplicates list :(  Please put that in an answer and we'll see whether the process works.

Comment: It's automatically converted to a comment... :(

Comment: Also, mine definitely calls for some particular features on the duplicate-shown-with-the-answers.  Such as the excerpt/preview.

Comment: That was *also* brought up in the other question.  If not in the question itself, then in the comments/answers.

Comment: Doesn't this run counter to wanting to close duplicate questions?

Comment: While that's certainly a nice idea, can we first please get duplicate suggestions _actually_ _handled_? It's been quite some time since one of my duplicate flags was acted on - most are still active even after some months.

Answer (score 4):

> This is [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166852/206447) from a proposed duplicate question [Show duplicate suggestions as answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166844)
>
> For more information regarding how this works, see [the help center](http://example.com).

I think this idea makes a lot more sense now that we're (sorta) [mandating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question/) that duplicates be pointed only at *answered* questions. In my experience, it's often much easier to *identify* duplicates when the answer to the older one clearly fits the newer one. Obviously, there's always the danger that two completely different problems just happen to share a single solution - but that's even more reason to make duplicate links *compete* with actual answers to the new question.

That said, I have a couple of suggestions:

*blah blah blah*

---

... and that's my suggestion for how it should look.

Ok, maybe it doesn't work so well on Meta, as answers often don't actually answer the question, but it could work pretty well on the main site (although maybe not always).

Regarding which answer gets displayed - either it could be the highest-voted / accepted one, or we could allow the duplicate-voter to pick one of them.

But I definitely think we should be displaying an answer, not the question, as another question doesn't help the asker much, and requires navigating away to find the answer.

I think displaying the whole answer would be better than just displaying part of it. Although it could take up a lot of space sometimes, it's better because it fully answers the question right there - a partial answer may or may not be largely useless.

Comment: How about a scroll Window like we see when voting to close. ..and when the page opens it is scrolled to the accepted answer?

Comment: @BenVoigt That could perhaps also work.