# Train new users about quality posts using "suggested" close votes (like suggested edits)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, vote-to-close

[There has](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow) [been](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions?rq=1) [a lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions?lq=1) [of talk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254202/is-the-reputation-points-system-biased-flawed-and-thus-provoking-bad-feelings-la?cb=1) [lately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no?lq=1) [about how](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions?lq=1) [to improve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253339/help-askers-find-duplicates-before-the-question-becomes-public?lq=1) [question quality.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253342/give-more-attention-to-user-identified-duplicates?lq=1)

### Motivation

- People receive a benefit (reputation) for doing something we don't want them to do: Asking and answering questions that should be closed.
- People don't receive a benefit for doing the correct action, e.g. downvoting and flagging for closure.

### Solution: Allow and reward "suggested close votes"

We already give a small amount of rep to encourage new users to edit/improve posts. **I think we should do something very similar for close votes.** Imagine the following:

- Low rep users can vote to close a post... that DOESN'T COUNT, or counts far less, e.g. 20 low rep users needed to close.
- These posts will go into the close vote queue, however.
- If it turns out that they're correct, and the post does get closed, they get 2 rep.
- One possibility is give each low rep user 1/4 of a vote, and cap low rep votes at 12 * 1/4 = 3 close votes, and two high rep votes are still needed to close. Only those first 12 would get the 2 rep.
- We also get low rep users used to the concept of "cleaning up noise" **from day one**, which I think is the biggest benefit.
- Higher rep users would still not get two rep for closing a question, just like now when they don't get any for edits.
- Inspired by @PeterMortensen: We should also cap the total amount of rep that can be gotten this way, just like with suggested edits.
- Inspired by @Amicable: Only award the rep if the close reason matches the reason it's ultimately closed.
- The exact details can be worked out, that's why I marked this as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

But durron597, they can already flag posts for moderator attention!

- They're not rewarded for doing that now
- However, they're much more massively rewarded answering "noise" questions

  - One upvote is a lot more useful to a low rep user than a "helpful flag".
  - It can even be a lot more than that if they're fast at answering an easy wide audience duplicate.
- They may click the wrong one, because they don't understand the difference between a question that's say, too broad, and "very low quality", or they click "other" when they really meant to click "off topic"

**Update:**  @Servy points out that there's never a reason not to mark every post for closure. This can be combatted in the same way it's combatted for suggested edits:

> Additionally, any user who submits many rejected edits will be banned from suggesting further edits for 7 days.*

We could do the same thing... close vote too many questions that don't ultimately get closed and you lose your ability to do it.

Comment: As a lower rep user who is trying to help, I would love this.  I flag all the dang time "685 flags, 67 waiting, 589 helpful, 16 decline, 12 disputed." and proudly growing.  The amount of noise on the site is making me feel (even as a low rep user) that I have no impact on the deluge of junk flooding in.  I recently hit the 2k mark and have been trying to edit/review as much as I can in my spare time, and it just seems like an uphill battle.  As someone already doing it, it would be nice.

Comment: @Walls, I fear you are the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: I was quickly saddened when I realized with my new edit queue super powers I no longer got 2 measly points for saving the day and making things slightly more readable.  I cringe when I see a pending edit and I have already reviewed my queue's worth for the day, and I see the edit and wait... knowing it will get approved when it is minimal and there is work to be done.  I refresh with a fury until it gets approved, and not fixed properly.  It's a bummer, but I trudge on with a sigh.

Comment: If a lower reputation user is the _first_ to vote to close a question that subsequently gets closed this might work. However, if they can be second they can just pile on close votes to get the rep. People may/do explain why they're closing in the comments.

Comment: @Ben Good point. Maybe they can only see close votes by 3k+ users at sub 3k rep? Or maybe the first few low rep close voters get rep, but they don't find out whether they were one of the first few until after the post is closed?

Comment: All those upvotes on those questions make me sad...

Comment: You're essentially asking to gain rep for helpful flags.

Comment: You can get reputation points above 2000 by editing tag wikis (until you hit the 1000 ceiling).

Comment: @roippi In retrospect I agree... not about what you're saying, but that it doesn't belong in this post. Removed it.

Comment: Given this implementation it would incentivize users to flag every single post for closure.  There's never a reason *not* to.

Comment: As far as I am aware all flags are approved if one type is marked as valid and the question is closed, so if this went through a user could get reputation for using the wrong flag type. E.g. I flag as "Too broad" the question is closed as "Unclear what you are asking" but I still get reputation because my flag was auto-approved.

Comment: @durron597 the potential issue I saw was rewarding incorrect actions.

Comment: @Amicable Edited with your comment in mind

Comment: FWIW, the proposed system resembles something called a "Keynesian Beauty Contest." I was told so by [a guy who knows a little something about things like this](https://twitter.com/spolsky/status/448518562924490752).

Comment: Why don't we just award 2 rep for helpful flags?

Comment: Yes we are rewarded for flagging posts.  I am working towards a silver badge for flags - 76 to go.

Comment: I would so love if we were rewarded rep for flagging... then I'd be likely to actually hit 3k anytime soon. It would make a great deal of sense, since good flagging says way more about one's ability to properly help with the Close queue than good answers do.

Answer (score -1):

More than anything else, the main reason I see not to do this is that it just *isn't needed*.  We don't really have a major problem of people not flagging stuff for closure when it should be closed.  We *do* in fact have a problem of not having enough people capable of closing questions that have already been flagged for closure.  If this actually *worked* then it would *increase* the number of close flags.  Since they aren't being handled quickly enough, that means more flags just getting ignored and never acted on (or it means people getting a piece of candy for flagging a question that would have *already* been closed without their flag).

So even if this feature requests works *perfectly*, it still doesn't help the site.  No more questions get closed.  People just spend more time doing fairly unproductive activities.

And of course, that's if it works perfectly.  That's not considering any possible problems or abuses, such as people going around flagging posts that don't warrant closure (either because they don't understand what should be closed, or because they think they could get rep for trying anyway).  We'll also see a ton more flags on all of the *really* bad content that already gets cleaned up fine by people hoping to get some rep.  People will end up being incentivised for activities that either are harmful, or at the very least, aren't helpful.

You're also replacing an intrinsic motivation with an extrinsic motivation here.  This will *decrease* the quality of contributions notably.  Currently most people flagging content are flagging it because they just want to help.  People flagging content because they want to help are going to do a better job than people flagging because they want some reputation.  You might get more people if there is an extrinsic motivation, but they won't do as good of a job.

Comment: Replied to you by editing the OP

Comment: Also, you could say the same thing about **answering questions**. Consider the sentence: *People answering questions because they want to help are going to do a better job than people answering because they want some reputation. You might get more people if there is an extrinsic motivation, but they won't do as good of a job.* Yet we give reputation for answering questions **correctly** anyway - and that is the key, they can only get reputation for correct closures.

Comment: And that's exactly the problem that inspired this post from the beginning... there is a lot of incentive on one side of the coin - generating new content. However, there is little on the other - working to ensure that new content is high quality.

Comment: @durron597 The extrinsic motivation is there for answering questions because there is (at least a belief) that there won't be enough people trying to answer questions without it, more so than because it actually improves quality.  It pretty demonstrably *lowers* quality in my eyes, in most cases.  While ensuring that the reward only happens for desirable behavior *helps*, it is not a silver bullet.  Just look at the suggested edit queue you're trying to emulate.  It's a mess.  There's *tons* of crap, and *tons of crap that gets approved*.  It's a *terrible* system to emulate.

Comment: @durron597 Your suggestion is to improve the side of the code that there isn't a lack of, flagging posts for closure by lower rep users, and *doesn't* improve the side of the coin that's lacking, the voting to close posts by high rep users.

Comment: The idea is to get people thinking about working to improve the signal-to-noise ratio of the SE network from day one. Also, do you have data that many low rep users frequently flag to close?

Comment: @durron597 Sure.  A hundred thousand items in the close vote queue.  A low rep user flagging a post will do one of two things.  Add the post to that queue if it's not there, or do nothing if it already is there.  Since the items in the queue aren't being processed as quickly as they're coming in *already*, more close flags won't help.  The percentage of the items in the queue that were put there from flags (versus close votes) isn't really relevant; the point is that any more flagging isn't helpful.

Comment: that's why I originally paired this proposal with the idea of removing rep from questions/answers that get closed... but then I removed it to keep the topic single-subject

Comment: @durron597 That suggestion has been discussed before, multiple times, and it does have its own set of problems, but unlike this answer it at least has some *potential* for helping.

Comment: Well, at this point I'm happy to agree to disagree; I think we both have instincts about how this would play out that ultimately are difficult to back by evidence with the tools available.

Comment: @durron597 But it's *not* difficult to back by evidence.  There is *lots* of significant, conclusive, and concrete evidence that indicates that we already have more than enough people flagging posts for closure, or at least that additional flags won't be helpful, because the existing flags simply can't be processed.  You can't claim that there isn't evidence when *there is conclusive evidence* that this won't do a thing to help.

Comment: That's what you believe. I believe that by adding suggested close votes to the rep system, people will begin to do that more and, as a result, **encourage/reward duplicate questions less.** [Maybe you're correct, but I don't think it's demonstrable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot) I think it's worth a try, though.

Comment: @durron597 We can provably show that close flags are *already* not being processed as quickly as they're coming in.  That means that we *know* that more flags coming in will have *no effect whatsoever on the number of questions that end up closed*.  Since there will be *no effect* on the number of questions closed, there will be no effect on the people asking close-worthy questions.  Your belief is not based in fact or evidence.  You can't just *say* that there is no conclusive evidence when *there is conclusive evidence, and it contradicts your point*.

Comment: The idea is to get new users THINKING about what they post differently.

Comment: @durron597 And in what way is encouraging a bunch of flags that will never get handled, or encouraging flagging of posts *already* being handled, going to change how people think about posting questions?  Or are you suggesting that people are going to post close-worthy questions just so that they can get 2 rep for flagging to close their own question?

Answer (score -3):

This is a needlessly complicated system. We already have flagging. Low rep users can flag to close. Why would we need suggested close votes when flags already do the job? Questions with active close flags enter the Close Votes Review Queue. Your proposed "suggested close votes" system is almost identical to the current flagging process.