# Could: "Possible duplicate of.." be given prominence for answering users?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

**Scenario:**

- User 1 asks a question
- User 2 votes to close as duplicate
- User 3 ignores the comment/dupe link and answers

Other than the link in the comments, users that answer are not directed in any prominent way to the dupe target and often prefer to just continue and answer.

Could users that answer be given a duplicate preview before they answer when a close vote exists?

**Scenario:**

- User 1 asks question
- User 2 votes to close as duplicate
- User 3 clicks to answer and is presented with dupe preview
- User 3 has to choose to close or continue to answer

Implementation-wise, this would require some changes to alert users that are about to answer. My initial thoughts were as [@NathanTuggy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099598/nathan-tuggy) [suggested in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352450/could-possible-duplicate-of-be-given-prominence-for-answering-users?noredirect=1#comment494030_352450):

> *The implementation could use the same logic and UI as adding a second answer to a question: answer box is hidden behind a button saying "Add Another Answer" which pops up a confirmation dialog before allowing any typing.*

Other suggestions: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352450/could-possible-duplicate-of-be-given-prominence-for-answering-users?noredirect=1#comment494024_352450) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352450/could-possible-duplicate-of-be-given-prominence-for-answering-users?noredirect=1#comment494028_352450)

**Dupe Preview Example:**

[image]

It would require some logic around if you start posting an answer before the close vote comes in, but for users that navigate to the page after the close vote, they could be shown any dupe targets before they can answer.

This wouldn't prevent answers and I don't think one dialog and click is too much of a barrier to answering in the situation where a vote exists.

**[Comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352450/could-possible-duplicate-of-be-given-prominence-for-answering-users?noredirect=1#comment493950_352450) from [@rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) re: rep requirements:**

*You need 15 rep to flag and 3K to actually VTC*, which would have to be accounted for.

**Related reading:**

[Show duplicate suggestions as answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166844/show-duplicate-suggestions-as-answers)

[Give more attention to user-identified duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253342/give-more-attention-to-user-identified-duplicates)

Both relate to posting duplicates as answers, as opposed to showing them in a dialog to people that are about to answer, in the same way users that close vote see existing close targets.

Also:

[Reputable people keep answering duplicates - What's the solution?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution)

[How much research effort is expected of answerers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376165/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-answerers)

**Similar request (minus the implementation details here):**

[Warn answerers on close candidates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256352)

**Similar requests (posted as answers to other questions) by [@gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat)**

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316638/839601

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285952/165773

Comment: Why stop at duplicates? Why not just force User 3 to do a CV review of the post?

Comment: You need 15 rep to flag and 3K to actually VTC but beyond that I like this idea.

Comment: also related: showing a modal popup to the answerer if the question is voted / flagged as duplicate ([proposed at MSO here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316638/839601) and later [submitted for second iteration SE quality project here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285952/165773)) _"dupe close without answers teaches user: "next time, search and research". Close with answer teaches, "No need to research, just dump your question and it will be chewed up to you like it was to 10,000 guys like you before"..."_

Comment: @gunr2171 maybe if the answerer has a more specific solution with regards to the new question or has some new answer to add..

Comment: @gunr2171 well, sure but it does make sense to ask an user that is about to answer to validate/evaluate a possible duplicate as they can be considered SME. You can have a wide variety of reviewing behavior/strategy when it comes to the other close votes. Duplicate matching is best done by users that know what they are doing and this is an excellent moment to dig into that knowledge.

Comment: Kind of related, but I saw a user the other day (with gold badge in the topic) answer a question, get the upvotes and THEN close as duplicate when they stopped getting votes. What's stopping someone from continuing, then after  they've got the votes, closing as a duplicate similar to that situation?

Comment: I have the feeling that most users who answer dupes already know it is a dupe, but maybe just maybe, it could reduce some noise on SO - so I think this is a good idea.

Comment: @Albzi I consider that borderline abuse.  You should not answer and vote to close.

Comment: Too late for me to raise a flag for that specific issue now, was a week or so ago. But if that's what it's classed as, then hopefully that wont happen in future :) @NathanOliver

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest the same thing should happen with typo and tool request flags/close votes.

Comment: +1 Combine this with gaining rep points for **successful** dupe flags (+5?)  - and **penalties for failed** ones (-2?) to *prevent abuse* - and it will be enough motivation to actually find duplicates for the question as opposed to just answering it.

Comment: @Ihazkode I wanted to steer away from the reputation gains/penalties as that's been suggested many times and gone nowhere. This is specifically designed to show people that are about to answer, similar posts in the hope they may vote to close rather than answer from time to time.

Comment: @Tanner makes sense. They are two separate things.

Comment: @gnat they seem like very similar proposals, did you ever post your own feature request as a question as opposed to those answers?

Comment: good question @Tanner - and the answer is no I didn't do that because back then when they collected ideas for quality project they made it look like it's not necessary: "what do _you_ think we should include in this round? Try to link to the [tag:feature-request], but don't fret too much if you can't find it (just explain what it wanted, and we can rely on Shog9's RAM-like memory for the location)." I am now thinking about editing my answer over there to add link to your request

Comment: This is a great idea; it does a decent job of balancing between people abusing a rep-incentivized dupe closure system on one end, and the current situation of users disregarding duplicate questions and answering for rep anyway on the other end.

Comment: I mean, people are still going to answer dupes for rep if they're doing that now on purpose, this would just put up a stop sign that they've gotta stop at before submitting. I like the idea, but, would prefer the dialog to instead be more of an alert, similar to the one we get when downvoting documentation examples. Less obstructive.

Comment: The dialog should be shown when someone *begins* to enter information in the answer (or when the first CV is cast, if already entering info), not when they click "Post Your Answer". When they click that button, they've already invested time into answering. A dialog shown then makes the person choose between dumping the effort they've already put into an answer, or posting it anyway. Lots of people will post it anyway, as they've already put in the effort. Showing the popup when they start entering info into the answer lets them make the choice *before* expending effort on writing an answer.

Comment: Right, but what if it was voted as a dupe while they were typing up their answer? i'd expect that to be the more common case.

Comment: @KevinB the orange message in the top bar can be used where it normally says *1 new answer* it could now say *duplicate vote casted* or something like that. That does require an extension to the websocket messages so might take longer then 6 to 8 weeks to implement.

Comment: @Makyen The implementation could use the same logic and UI as adding a second answer to a question: answer box is hidden behind a button saying "Add Another Answer" which pops up a confirmation dialog before allowing any typing.

Comment: worth noting that as pointed in one of the answers you linked, "it can be tested say, at MSO / MSE prior to making decision on whether to give it a go at main site"

Comment: "I consider that borderline abuse". IMHO, that's on the wrong side of the border. OTOH, I think it's ok to post an answer on a Q that you dupe-close if the old answers don't quite match the new question & you think the new OP needs a little assistance to apply the old info to their problem, or if there are a variety of old answers (some with possibly outdated info) and the new answer summarises the info & has a code example illustrating current best practice. But in that situation it's probably a Good Idea to make the new answer community wiki.

Comment: (cont) Of course one can always add a new answer to the dupe target, but if it's old, with lots of highly voted answers, it's hard for new answers to compete for visibility.

Comment: The team is going to look into this one a bit deeper in a future sprint so I've updated the status to deferred.

Comment: @Rosie 5 & half years later... I'll come back in another 5 & half years and perhaps we'll see some progress...

Comment: @Tanner I completely understand being frustrated that this was in status review limbo for as long as it was. It along with some other older posts pre-dated the current escalation process. The team just put in a huge effort to triage all of the older posts and update the statuses so the community can see which ones will be picked up. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386681/ticket-smash-for-status-review-tag-part-deux