# How much research effort is expected of answerers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Every once and awhile I'll encounter questions that have a very simple, low-effort answer. This includes questions that have been asked numerous times before and have well-known answers (e.g. the nth question about null pointer exceptions) and questions that ask for brief explanations of very basic topics. For example, awhile back I encountered a question where the answer was "this is a constructor."

In virtually all cases, the question deserves to be downvoted and/or marked as a duplicate. How about the answers, though? Can an answer that requires little to no effort on the answerer's part be considered a "good" answer? [At least one site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) recently banned a certain type of question in part because they attract low-effort answers:

> **closed** as off-topic by JNat♦ Jan 19 at 14:35
>
> This question appears to
>   be off-topic. While what's on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by reading the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - "**Identification** questions are off-topic, because they tend to attract
>     low-quality and low-effort posts. The community has decided to no
>     longer support these questions. Please refer to [this meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontinuing-support-for-identification-questions) for
>     additional details." – JNat
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), please edit your question.

> locked by Shog9♦ Jan 19 at 23:42
>
> This question exists because it has historical significance, **but it
>   is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please
>   do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.
>   This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More
>   info: [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help).

That being said, what's the proper way to handle low-effort answers here? How much effort is expected *of answers*?

The ["Don't Ask" document](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) suggests that "good subjective" questions "inspire answers that explain 'why' and 'how'" and "tend to have long, not short, answers". This implies that questions that have this kind of answers are probably bad, but does it imply that the *answer* is bad, too?

Comment: [anime.se] does the same thing, and for the same reasons.  It's been eons since we first saw their examples and what they were accomplishing...

Comment: There is a relevant post somewhere on MSE about downvoting answers to bad or off-topic questions regardless of the specifics of the answer. There's a divide between people who reserve votes to specifically rate the post voted on, and people who see merit in discouraging answers to unacceptable questions in order to avoid "broken windows" (there's a blog post on that) and maintain overall site quality.  I personally have no qualms in downvoting low-effort *anything*. Laziness is *not* in the best interests of the network.

Comment: @DanBron Do you mean [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive) on whether a comment telling someone not to answer is constructive? Or were you thinking about a different one?

Comment: @EJoshuaS No, it’s another Q entirely. But the SE search engine simply frustrates me.

Comment: @DanBron [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1) perhaps?

Comment: That's one of them. This is a related on one off-topic, as opposed to simply poor, questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions . Note the topvoted answers to each oppose each other.  Obviously the case is stronger for downvoting answers to OT Qs than LQ Qs. But the 2nd highest-voted answer in that link is my position. Here's something on [broken windows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52530/are-duplicates-creating-broken-windows).

Comment: Net net, downvotes are a privilege you earned, and you are free (both technically and ethically) to use them as you see fit. They're a tool for you to shape SE into the network you want to see.  You can't abuse them, but so long as it's "one person one vote", it's **your** vote.

Comment: @DanBron You are expected to vote on posts based on your opinion of their usefulness.  You're given *very* wide latitude to decide what you consider useful, but that doesn't mean that you're free to use votes however you want.  Likewise, the fact that there are very few mechanisms for the site to know if you're voting contrary to your own opinion of a post's usefulness, at least with enough certainty to act on it, doesn't mean it's okay to do, it just means it's hard to get caught for doing it wrong.  So it's on the honor system that you do it right, but you still are expected to do it right.

Comment: Please do not conflate research effort with other forms of effort. Generally, "low-effort answer" refers to answers that not only are poorly researched, but are also poorly written. (An answer doesn't have to meet *all* of these criteria to be considered low-effort. You'll know such answers when you see them.)

Comment: Loosely related: I still feel that SO should [push answering users to close duplicates when a close vote exists if applicable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352450/could-possible-duplicate-of-be-given-prominence-for-answering-users) to avoid some low quality duplicated answers.

Comment: Also loosely related: [Reputable people keep answering duplicates - What's the solution?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution)

Comment: Unfortunately memory becomes its own enemy. With nothing left to squeeze the rational vice tears through its screw threads and SO becomes the turf of proud bullies. Helpful, kind people go elsewhere. Get rid of this benighted reputation nonsense and the bullies would be without incentive. Not that I have much, but I personally never needed it. The fact that people are even looking at a question should be enough reputation to participate in "direct democratic" decisions about the content.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As with literally any post, the question is, "is this post useful".  Do you think it's useful to repeat the same answer to a commonly asked duplicate question whose answer is already very readily available, even before the answer was posted?  After all the voting tooltips don't say, "This post is technically correct." they say, "This post is useful."

Of course, this will depend on context, so you can't say *universally* whether a given post will be useful, but in my experience it's pretty rare for such a post to be useful.  Answers like this are frequently less detailed or less well written than the canonical answers (which is why those answers tend to be the top results when searching for the answer to that question), and in the rare cases where the answer is better than the other readily available ones, it would have been better posted *on the canonical reference*, rather than on the 10,000th duplicate where few people are likely to ever see it.  So while there are exceptions, then tend to be rare, in practice.

Comment: True - I have seen low-effort answers get upvoted a lot, though. For example, I recently saw an answer from a high-rep user (who will go nameless) that was literally 4 sentences explaining what a C# constructor is. It ended up receiving 5 upvotes. Was it proper in this case, since it didn't require much effort on the answerer's part?

Comment: @EJoshuaS People upvote the answers for the same reason they post them.  Too many people think upvotes are for post that are correct, and downvotes are for posts that are wrong, rather than votes being an indication of whether or not the answer is *useful*.

Comment: True - under the standard you propose here, I guess the answer should've been downvoted because the information was already readily available elsewhere, so it wasn't useful to repeat it there for the nth time.

Comment: Indeed it should.  And if more people were willing to downvote / vote delete pointless duplicative answers, there would be fewer of them, and StackOverflow would be a better place.  (OK, maybe the last is an exaggeration ....)

Comment: A non useful answer is better than a no answer at all. This is because while these answers might not provide the real value, they sometimes act as a pointer or provide clues to proper answers.

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic If someone wants to do either of those things they should be either closing a post as a duplicate, or posting a comment, not posting an answer.

Answer (score 15):

Answering to question in the title: Answerers are generally expected to put *close to zero efforts* to research the answer. The one reason SO is so successful is it taps into enough people that likely know answer already and don't need to "research" it. Note that it does not mean one can post anything as an "answer" - it means your prior education, research and work experience give you enough knowledge to provide that answer.

I think the question actually asks if answerers should spend time to see if it was already answered and provide detailed explanations. So far community and SO team has roughly an opposite guidance - community would prefer duplicates as single place for detailed answers (see nice Servy's answer [on "usefulness" votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376167/477420)). The SO gamification is setup in opposite way discouraging researching for duplicates and partially favor fast not necessary detailed answers (there are plenty of discussions on how to encourage search for duplicates/other research before answering without much success yet).

As I see it if SO would want to enforce research effort from people who answer we'd see some feature that makes instant answering harder - like one can only post answers 30 minutes after seeing/editing/up-voting a question. So far opposite is true - early answers are somewhat encouraged while spending time on research (even searching for duplicates) is essentially penalized by decreased visibility of such posts...

Comment: I can tell you, as a 25K+ member of EL&U, "close to zero" efforts is a very bad estimation of the effort I put into researching the answers I'm most proud of. Questions which cause me to put a *lot of research in*, because *I'm intrigued*, are 100% my *favorite* questions on the site. My top-ranking answer, by almost an order of magnitude, I put about a *week* into researching. No, sir.

Comment: @DanBron I'm not sure what your argument is. No one is *required* to spend a week on providing an answer. Everyone is definitely welcome to spend as much time/money/effort as they find necessary and it will very likely lead to outstanding answer but I'd not call it expectation. I  personally tried at least to research for duplicates first when I was answering question but that's against how gamification rewards setup now.

Comment: I'd probably say "not expected to put effort into research" rather than "expected to put zero effort into research" in that case. Though that still doesn't sit completely right with me...

Comment: @BoltClock I think you should provide your own answer on that question - we have very solid guidance for questions (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) but not much for answers. (I'll try to edit that phrase in my post to maybe clarify it so).

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: I'll think about it. It won't be a simple answer for sure. I'll need time to put something together. But I think I have a rough idea what I want to say.

Answer (score 12):

You should also consider things not from your perspective, where the answer is trivial, but from the perspective of someone who does not know the answer.

You don't link to examples, so this may not fit the actual questions at which you are looking.  But I have linked questions to other questions and had people respond that that's not what was happening in their cases.  Meanwhile, when I look at it, it seems an exact duplicate.  The only difference is that the variable has a different name and semantic meaning.  But the problem isn't related to the variable name and semantic meaning.  They needed a more specific answer than I was giving.

In your example, you have someone saying that it is a constructor.  That may actually help people who don't understand why a question is closed as a duplicate of "How do constructors work?"  It may be obvious to you that the post is about a constructor.  But that may be the one thing that the asker really needs to know.  And if that asker needs it, other askers may as well.

Recently, I was researching an error that said something like JSF view is expired.  One post had a beautiful answer explaining what is happening.  Other questions were closed as a duplicate of that one.  But that post did not give the single answer that I needed so well as the low effort, "View's stored in the session.  Set a higher session timeout in web.xml."  That told me that I should be searching how to set the session timeout in web.xml, which was the information that I really needed.  The other answer was in many ways better, but it was missing the information that I really needed at that moment.

For someone who already knows that session timeouts are set in web.xml, being told that that's where it is set is low information.  But I didn't know that.  I needed the weak answer in the duplicate question to tell me that.  The well-researched, knowledgeable answer was by someone who knew that (as once I started searching for the right thing, I found posts by him talking about it).  But that person did not link that piece of information from the place where I was looking.  I had to go crawling through lesser answers to duplicate questions to find it.

Please be careful about deleting answers that you don't find useful.  The truth is that other people may get use out of weak answers that you wouldn't.  Down-voting and deleting such an answer makes the site less useful to the people it is most meant to help.  A generic rule saying to always down-vote and delete answers on duplicate questions would thus make the site less useful.

Duplicate questions do not automatically get deleted or merged for a reason.  Some questions will show up in a search better than others.  Or they show up in different searches.  Some answers to the specific problem in the question may help more than better but less specific answers in the dupe target.

Comment: I agree; identifying a question as a duplicate is often tricky, because two people asking the same question with a different level of base knowledge need different answers.

Comment: If a question is closed as duplicate, @mdfst113's experience is the best argument for moving questions (and answers) from closed questions to the better question.

Answer (score 3):

My first consideration is always to the person who asked the question. If I know the answer and can respond in 10 seconds, then it seems churlish not to do so.

It's true that in very many cases, such questions are duplicates. But often, it's not easy to identify an exact duplicate that contains an answer which the OP will recognize as an answer to their question. It might be evident, for example, that they don't have a sufficient grasp of the concepts or the terminology to understand the relevant answer. Or there might be 300 other people who asked the same question (or more likely, asked a different question that was equivalent, but they don't know enough to realise that), and finding one of those 300 that is going to help them is a substantial piece of effort. I don't have a week to refactor the SO knowledge base for such a topic; I do have 10 seconds to help the OP move forwards.

(In fact, yesterday I responded to this question: [Element 'xxx' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126586/element-xxx-is-invalid-misplaced-or-occurs-too-often/53130290#comment93154612_53130290) saying it was a duplicate and pointing to an accepted answer; the OP responded by saying they didn't understand the answer. When that happens, I don't feel I have responded well, even if the information I provided was technically accurate and in line with SO policies and guidelines.)

Comment: This reads to me as you would advice to answer duplicates instead of closing them, with which I completely disagree. Information shoulf be kept in one place and not be spread over several questions. This also makes it easier to Google a problem.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that posting a answer that is barely more than a link pointing to another SO question (with some minor tweeking to fit to OPs code) is an active missuse of the system. IMHO, this can be seen as just trying to get the maximum rep out of it instead of trying to get a clean knowledge base.

Comment: @MichaelKay - I appreciate your empathy with question posters, especially new users. We can't just mindlessly follow SO rules, there are human beings on the other side of the question posts.  Have an upvote.

Comment: @BDL I find the "brownie point" system of rewards on StackOverflow as pathetically childish, and the idea that I would be motivated by it as mildly insulting. I'm 67 years old, for goodness sake, I have no need to prove myself.