# How much effort are answerers expected to put into finding duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I was thinking of asking the question "How much research effort is expected of answerers?" that corresponds to the "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)" FAQ which focuses more on asking. There already is a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376165/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-answerers) with that title, but I really wanted to ask very directly about finding duplicates on SO.

Based on reading a lot of meta discussion I've read on the topic over the years, I think most of us agree on these things:

- If you answer a lot of questions in a tag, you probably have an idea that a new question may be a duplicate, even if you don't know the exact one yet.
- If you know the answer to a question it's often easier to answer it than it is to look for a duplicate.
- You shouldn't do that.

So, we don't approve of people putting *no* effort into finding a duplicate of a question that probably is one, but how much effort *is* expected? Should an answerer put as much effort into finding a duplicate as the OP should have put into researching their question before asking it? That seems excessive to me, but maybe other people disagree. I think it's somewhere in the middle, but I'm curious what other people think about it.

I don't think "effort" is an easy thing to measure. Maybe it could be expressed as a reasonable set of actions someone should take toward finding a good duplicate before they answer a question.

Comment: IMO it is not so much "don't answer duplicates" as it is "don't answer poor questions" problem.

Comment: Do you mean poor as in poorly researched? I'm assuming for the sake of argument that the type of question I'm asking about here is sufficiently clear and on-topic.

Comment: Bit of a both. Poor questions are usually poorly researched. If it is simple question about basic thing and it does not involve brand new technology it has probably been asked and answered before.

Comment: Not very easy to answer. On one hand, you have people who could have literally googled the title of their question and gotten an answer *from StackOverflow*. On the other hand, you can have somebody post a question which *has* a dupe...posted 6 years ago under a rather different title, and it has 1-2 answers and maybe 3 upvotes, so it's super hard to find. Or it's another question that revolves around [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Many questions fall between these extremes, so drawing a line seems rather arbitrary.

Comment: Depending on the tag you can judge if it's a duplicate by the number of answers or the answerers name alone. Finding dupe vary from beeing an expert in the tag  to picking 10+ consecutive chars from the question and google in.

Comment: At least a considerable part of what would be needed to ask the question. Searching with different search terms should be mandatory too, I think.

Comment: I think the issue is, the time needed to answer most posts, and find duplicates scales in the same way. That is simpler questions (quick to find duplicates) are more likely to have simple answers (quick to answer). As questions get harder to answer, so does it get harder to find dupes. But it's almost always easier to answer than find dupes. If you take the right amount of time to find a dupe, you are likely to have been pipped by someone answering first.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Generally, answerers are expected to recognize if the question appears to be something which has *probably* been asked many times before. If that is the case, then the degree to which it is a duplicate will factor into how long and hard to search.

Absolutely do not answer a question asking how to convert a number to a string. At this point a decade in, we can all recognize those have been asked a bunch of times. It is also built in (toString / ToString / str / to_string etc.) ... so there's that. These also take the least amount of time to find canonical targets for.

If the question may have been asked once, somewhere 4 years ago, then it is really a toss up of whether it is found for duplicate or just answered straight out with a fresh take. These can take the longest amount of time for a sometimes questionable duplicate.

In between both of those situations is a lot of grey area. For the most part, just use your best judgement.

The real burden here lies with the Question Wizard implementation in my opinion. The Wizard should be helping users in the process of asking questions identify existing questions with a much stronger degree of accuracy. That is where the effort should be directed.

Comment: I agree it would be very helpful if the question wizard was better at identifying duplicates. Leaving it up to answerers depends a lot on each individual's ability and inclination to identify likely duplicates and find good originals, which obviously varies widely.

Comment: This answer pretty much covers my opinion on the matter.

Comment: If the *Ask Question* wizard depends on Stack Overflow search, then it is a lost cause. Search is mostly broken, and its another bug we can't get the people who [mod edited] that run this site to fix. They spend their time policing pronouns and secretly colluding against moderators rather than fixing real problems.

Comment: @jww - If it [considered tag use](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369724/1026459) in the search then it would work just fine, or at least good enough that you could assume the large canon targets were found. No comment on the other stuff ;)

Answer (score -16):

Stack Overflow is a strange hybrid of a Q & A site, and documentation. It should really realize that it is in fact documentation, written in the form of Q & A; this will help move the design of the site down the path of canonicalization, and remove this absurd fight between question answerers, and those that bring the hammer down on/punish duplicate questions. If you can answer a question, you surely should. If it's a duplicate, the answers should be combined in some way with the parent / tombstone question.

Comment: I think closing as duplicate _is_ the way the answers are combined. But I don't think duplicate closure is a punishment. I'm not sure if that's what you meant, though.

Comment: There is a difference though between answers closed as a duplicate and duplicate answers merged into the original answer. Sometimes the latter happens.

Comment: Much is driven by gamification. How would you change the gamification to make this work? Currently, the gamification wants new answers to new questions. Whereas deduplication works on a honour system. How well is the honour system working?

Comment: Generally the only time I see duplicate questions punished (presumably you mean by downvotes, since I can't think of what other kind of punishment there would be) is when the question would be low quality even if it wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: That's interesting how you propose that duplicates should find themselves on their own without all those @#$@# elitist searching for duplicates... Explaining how you see that happening would be a very interesting post on its own...