# Prevent question being asked unless the poster has made use of the Similar Questions list

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, similar-questions

Why don't we make more use of the **Questions that may already have your answer** list?

How? When someone asks a question, the OP may not even bother looking at that list, or not know what to do with it.

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055264/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536), and tried to ask a new question with the same title
and in the suggestions list, as the VERY FIRST result, I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536). It's even the same title, letter by letter, and the OP still posted his question.

The new question does not show that the OP tried to search. The OP could say "I saw this answer ... and that one, they did not help, so I am posting."

So is it possible to force the OP to view at least 3 results from the suggested list before the **Post Question** button is enabled? It could be done in a tricky way, just telling the OP: you have to view some of the suggested results, so the OP does not cheat by just clicking 3 links from the list. We can make it randomly-dynamic, so some posters have to view 3, others 2.

There is a large amount of questions that can appear in search, either by Google or on this site. 90% of OP's have rep 1 or under 10. Why not try to make it little harder to ask a question if it's already appearing in the similar list?

I'm just presenting the idea of making more use of this list, if you have other suggestions for how to do that please offer them.

Comment: I think that [Help askers find duplicates before the question becomes public](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253339/help-askers-find-duplicates-before-the-question-becomes-public) and [Thwart publishing duplicate and low quality questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions) are very similar to this suggestion.

Comment: What if the user has already done their own search first, seen most (or all) of the questions in the suggested list, and not found an answer? This would make them review the same questions *again* in order to post a question they have in fact researched well.

Comment: @ken white yes. I have mentioned that my suggested way is not good. And you have found 1 disadvantage. I am asking this to put some light on that list to find a good way to do this

Comment: That 1 disadvantage is pretty major IMO. I know it would give me a very negative impression if I had put significant research into trying to find an answer before posting, only to be told I had to revisit several of the posts I'd already seen before being allowed to ask. Putting up barriers to punish or discourage users who have not done anything wrong in the first place is a horrible idea; the idea is not to drive people away before they're even given a chance to make a mistake.

Comment: @ken White  you still missing my point, i am the worst person who could suggest a sol. i accept this, i am focusing on something highlighting an issue, with a humble suggestion, so why don't you participate too, suggest something, i am not defending my idea ok?, the developers did not start implementing  it, so we are talking here to findout if there is a way to make use of that list, if you gonna keep pressing on your first note, we will go no where.

Comment: And you're missing my point. :-) First, I don't think there's a severe enough problem to be solved; the current system of closing duplicates is working fine. Second, I don't think there *is* a solution that will not also act as a deterrent to new users. And third, if all you're doing here is regurgitating an old idea that was not selected to be implemented, then this post counts as a duplicate; you've not offered any new solution that wasn't in that previous question. Shouldn't we close this question as such? Oh, wait - I see it has been. :-)

Comment: ironically, yes and it was closed, but at least it does not have the title of an old question, you might be alright, but my idea was about an earlier stage, where question is not asked at first place, not to allow asking then closing. it looks this issue is not as easy as i thought :)

Comment: @KenWhite, what is wrong with a "deterrent to new users", we have more new users then we can cope with!