# Forced new-user tutorial as a solution to low quality questions

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

**Preface:**
At the suggestion of another user, I have posted my idea as a feature request. [This is an answer to this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252244#252244). There may be some fluff that is irrelevant to this feature request as this was an answer to a question, originally. I have tried to prune it, though.

**TL;DR VERSION:**
Instead of tackling the "issue"(perceived or real, it matters not) with the current userbase, let's invest in the long-term health of our wonderful site by requiring a minimal understanding of the site's charter and rules BEFORE the permission to ask questions is granted.

**Long essay alert:**

I am a relatively newb user of this site(I like to think only in account age). Only recently have I begun to take notice and care about the health and how this site works (after I had admittedly commited the rep-whoring everybody is guilty of). I too have already become rather disgruntled at the utter lack of "care" that some users of this site show, both new and old. **(Especially recently, must be final project time in CS courses nationally...)**

I don't think the problem is as simple as a because **crap**, or **poor programmers**, or **homework questions**, or even **laziness***. These merely skirt around the problem. From my brief stay here, it is clear that these are merely side effects of the problem that this site seems to be experiencing.

It seems to me that the extreme low quality questions that seem to comprise a great majority of the currently asked questions are asked by people that show absolutely no care for the charter of this site or its rules to the point where they do not even display the capability to learn. This, to me, is the initial problem that serves as a catalyst driving certain people to respond to such low quality questions in hopes for easy reps, and the related chain of hate that awesome diagram shows. Even though I might not be the most active on this site, I still see that there are obviously more questions that seem to fail to actually diagnose a problem such that answerers can actually answer them. This conceivably causes experienced users, or heck, even newbie users such as me that actually RTFM to become frustrated with the community.

So this lack of care is spreading, people are becoming lazy. Good questions are sometimes burned because people either a) don't spend the time to read them, assuming that they are just a repeat of "how i debug this" or "give me the codes" or b) actually lack the understanding, but may carry high rep and the possibly associated high ego.

Now, I have actually experienced this first hand in kind. I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095119/understanding-eclipse-debug-source-lookup-with-dynamically-compiled-and-loaded-c) once before the currently linked question, but it merely lacked the preface telling our fellow downvoters to not downvote my question because it's actually a good question and not a pasted "how do I debug my homework" question. That question was downvoted to oblivion and recieved TWO close votes. Having been literally the 4th question I asked, I almost lost it there and then and wanted to rant on and on. Even though this is just one example of the negativity that I have been seeing and sometimes am guilty of exhibiting, just this one example happening, to me, is completely unacceptable. We cannot be so lazy as to shoo away newer users that ask good questions. Perhaps lazy is the wrong word here, a more fitting phrase would be that it seems that the community **lacks confidence in newer users' ability to ask coherent questions**

**How do we solve this?**

Well, I have one possible solution. Instead of attempting to address the problem that exists with the CURRENT active userbase, how about being slightly more selective as to who is allowed to participate on this site? A short and sweet 10-20 min "Introduction to StackOverflow" course that EVERY new (and existing user that is under some calculated cutoff) must take before they have the privilege of asking questions on the site? This course could have a quiz in the end, with questions that test the understanding of the charter of this site, and how to ask questions. I do not believe this is too much to ask from new users, because frankly, as a new user (unless you have been browsing SO for a long time, in which case you probably don't really even need to read the manual at all) you are NOT capable of asking a coherent question that follows this site's rules UNLESS you read the manual. If certain new users are not even willing to do that, then do they REALLY deserve to even belong in our great community? Conversely, if they DID care, then EVEN if they did ask trivial and stupid questions, they would respond well to feedback(however harsh that feedback is) and learn, slowly. Slowly and steadily, the general sense of a real community of programmers asking questions and giving answers to programming questions will return to the masses. Running with this idea, the moderating/review community could be given greater powers to maybe infract/warn new users that are STILL not exhibiting the bare-minimum qualities of a SO user, with a system that resembles that of many forums.

**Regarding ***: and this laziness would not be exhibited in such great frequency if the new users were FORCED to be educated in the ways of SO.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to disagree because I don't think what you've proposed is workable.

We already have a whole system in place to handle crap, and you've failed to show how your suggestion will improve on what we have - all you're doing is preventing entry to a whole bunch of new users till they've jumped through whatever hoops we've put in their way (there's a good chance they won't). For example there are already [incentives](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) in place for reading the [descriptive material](https://stackoverflow.com/about) about a site*.

- question quality is often in the eye of the beholder. That crap question is someone's baby, and they think it's fine. Sure they're probably wrong, but they don't know that and will need interaction and/or persuasion from other users to bring it into line.
- there are a lot of crap coders and crap students out there - get used to it. Most of those newbie questions from students will be coming from people studying at the tertiary level, if they cannot construct a proper question then there is little hope for them especially in any programming related industry. Forcing them to interact with a community driven review mechanism while getting the answer to their question should be good for them.
- the learning material would have to be very generic unless Stack Exchange wanted to invest in tailoring the resources for each site. Also English is not the native language of every SO user. Making them sit through a bunch of learning items and a quiz is not necessarily going to have a whole lot of benefit and may turn away a reasonable number of new users.

*let's not get into semantic arguments about the worth of badges

Comment: Yes, there are INCENTIVES in place, but is there any enforcement of having read the rules and charter of the site? It is not an uncommon thing to find on online forums for there to be forced "read the rules, then get confirmed through a series of steps" before posting is allowed on a massive scale

Comment: The entire point is so that every new user is required to spend at least 10 minutes reading a simple set of rules and about this site. It does not have to be even written at higher than a middle school level, but if they cannot communicate at a certain level of proficiency in English, there is a GOOD chance they are just going to ask crap questions over, and over.

Comment: From what you are saying, it seems like you are implying that the Stack overflow community is open to any random new user, we cannot inconvenience(?!?) them and _turn away_ users that do not even want to spend the effort reading a simple set of rules and regulations? The point IS that these 0 effort users are shunted from the site, they do not belong because they not only show 0 effort and post terrible questions wasting metamoderating time, but also show absolutely no desire to learn. You forget that the purpose of this site is for questioners and answerers to learn _together_

Comment: @rpg711 No, my point is that we already have mechanisms in place to turn away or limit the crap from those users - the system already has heuristics to identify and question ban problem users, and mods have a good range of powers.

Comment: So because we have mechanisms of moderation, we should accept the endless flow of low quality questions? Let's extrapolate this effect, I do not personally have access to any hard statistics related to this site, but according to analysis done by other users(see the "negative" question), the most active users are leaving the site, and new users continue to increase on a daily basis... we can see that this metamoderation can be overwhelmed in time. At the regular american night time, the amount of bad unmoderated questions increases significantly, already, from what I've seen on long nights up.

Comment: @rpg711 There's no need to extrapolate the problem - it's been recognised for a long time and I wouldn't say it's getting any worse (not at a noticeable rate anyway). One of the other problems I have with your proposal is it slows down **all** new users - so while it may slow down the rate of bad questions it will slow down the rate of new users overall, including good knowledgeable new users.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the cost/benefit is too high. One of the things that made SO successful was what Jeff Atwood called its [*low friction nature*](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W25450). Now, since then we've been made some compromises that added a little bit of friction (requiring signup, for instance; preventing certain words in titles, duplicate titles, etc.), but it's still basically show up, sign up, ask or answer a question. And that formula *mostly* works.

I think if a new user has to sit through a 10-20 minute process, we won't be seeing questions from new users anymore, and it wouldn't be long before tumbleweeds were blowing through.

I'm not averse to adding a *bit* more friction (I'm the one who suggested [requiring new users to check the preview](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295683/require-new-users-to-check-the-preview-before-posting), for instance), but a 10-20 minute course? I think that's much too far over the line.

Of course, it would be possible to get metrics on it, but only after having spent the time to build it to a level where it could be tested. I'd rather see that time spent on [other features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets).