# Why may new users ask questions without having gained the informed badge?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users, quality-improvement

I'm active in a "medium" traffic tag, Codeigniter, a php framework. Lately I noticed a lot of new users (1 rep) asking their first question, but not showing any badge at all. As example see [Application to become a Moodle Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798577/application-to-become-a-moodle-plugin) (which I'm sure was deleted in the meantime). Here is a screen shot:

[image]

With all the discussion going on how to avoid low quality questions, wouldn't be the implementation of **you didn't read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)**, so you didn't get the informed badge, so you cannot ask a question, back to tour...

be <s>a quite effective</s> a bit of a barrier to avoid this kind of low quality questions?

**update**:

> One thing is to "pretend doing the tour" and being allowed to ask a
>   question, another thing is NOT to be able to ask a question without
>   doing the tour.

this is successfully implemented for getting a driving license: If you are legal age you are not allowed to drive a car until you take "the tour" (which obviously doesn't mean that afterwards you know how to drive, but at least you have a notion)

Comment: *"be a quite effective barrier to avoid low quality questions?"* - No, not really. You'll get that badge when you scroll through the tour, you don't have to actually read it. So, if you force careless (#) users to read the tour, then they just scroll through it. (#) A careful user would read the tour without such reminder.

Comment: @Tom, I know, but at least you were there and maybe some people care reading it...Anyway if you may ask a question without the "taking the tour" why do we have this tour at all?

Comment: @Vickel the people who would care to read it probably got to it when they started writing their first question. You get a pop-up showing you a link to the tour. Whoever cares enough reads it at this point. I feel like it would just end up with a LOT of users who get the badge by scrolling  and not reading it.... so back to square 1.

Comment: That's the sad thing, too many new users couldn't care less. They want their homework done and if they can't they start crying here on meta. They even circumvent other checks like "too less non-code text" by adding nonsense, rather than explaining the actual issue. Thus, I don't think adding more restrictions will help here :/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't "taking the tour" made mandatory?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271804/why-isnt-taking-the-tour-made-mandatory)

Comment: @AndrewMyers your comment shows definitely a post I've been looking to find. But nevertheless, the reason why I'm putting this on Meta is the recent explosion of users who seem to have no glue of what's going on here whatsoever. The link you show is from 2014, I think a lot has changed since then....

Comment: And I also want to point out again: One thing is to "pretend doing the tour" and being allowed to ask a question, another thing is NOT to be able to ask a question without doing the tour

Comment: ah.. are you sure the user is not suspended(for some reasons) after asking the question?

Comment: Suspension would not remove badges, @Sagar.

Comment: it won't. but badges won't show publicly if the user is under suspension

Comment: @SagarV, no, the user was(is) not suspended

Answer (score 3):

For starters...the vast majority of accounts that exist on the site today were created *before* the badge came out...

Also, there's nothing there actively preventing the user from hitting Page Down on this page so they get past our silly little block so they can ask their question.

I doubt this would actually fix anything.  If anything, it'd actually make the situation *worse*.

Comment: I don't agree with you, eg. that particular user I picked out is member for 5 months (with 2 questions and a total of -12), others alike. I don't know how to make a SEDE call to find this out, but maybe it would be interesting.

Comment: Fair, but there are *lots* of 1-rep accounts. Most had to exist before this new system. Mine definitely did.

Comment: because you belong to the "old generation" :)