# Quick delete for obvious unsalvageable questions

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, dupehammer, vote-to-delete

You need 5 close votes, 3 downvotes and 3 delete votes to delete a regular question. Spam etc. can of course be handled with moderator attention.

However there are many cases where the question is based on completely unrealistic expectations, usually in the style of "I want to build a space ship, can anyone help me?". Now naivety is not worthy of moderator attention, but it's inefficient to explain in comments that you simply have no possibility of achieving this no matter how much you want to, and then gather up the required votes for deletion.

Of course there are review queues and other mechanisms that should handle this eventually and at least in theory, but if an obvious unanswerable question is getting the active attention of a few high rep users it would be more efficient to somehow speed the process up.

Instead of a dupehammer style heavy duty tool, perhaps a combined downvote, close and a "future" delete that would go off when/if the question is closed. Currently you may downvote and close vote, but you'd have to come back for the delete explicitly.

Naturally the user gets an explanation that he's asking for something **completely** unrealistic. The current "too broad" close vote is quite varying on what constitutes as "too broad".

---

So with this combo of Close & Delete 3 high rep+ users and 2 high rep users would be able to close and delete a question.

It would be hard to abuse, resistant to false positives as it would still require 5 trusted users in total and 3 of them with higher reps, and it would make getting rid of true garbage faster.

Comment: So, what exactly are you suggesting / requesting?

Comment: Related: [Let's give very-trusted users a Closehammer to go with their Dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256657/294055)

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chatroom, where you can work on getting exceptionally bad questions closed / deleted faster.

Comment: @Cerbrus ah, thank you. My idea of a streamlined close & delete would allow 3 high rep users to vote close & delete, then it would require only 2 close votes more to "activate" those deletes.

Comment: I do not know if this is **the** solution, but anything that goes into the direction of getting rid of garbage faster looks interesting to me. The perennial solution can't be just "let's have another election".

Comment: Might be obvious to you but other people have opinions that may differ

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and that's why it's not a dupehammer style single user power tool. It would be pretty much like the current situation, except when you've voted to close you don't need to come back to vote to delete afterwards. If there are differing opinions and it doesn't get closed, the deletes wouldn't affect anything.

Comment: @Kayaman: Sounds good!

Comment: Yup - it's a pain to have to keep track of hopelessly-bad questions, waiting for -3 rep, then waiting for close, before the deserved and inevitable delv can be applied.

Comment: Even more related, possibly even a duplicate: [Pre-register delete vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287910/245360).

Comment: We already have problems with certain "trusted" users regularly coordinating downvotes + delete votes on answers that don't at all warrant speedy deletion. I'm not sure how comfortable I am with this.

Comment: I guess I'm looking at this from a naive perspective, not understanding all the complicated interactions (and shall we say drama) that goes on deeper in SO. Maybe I need to pop into the chatrooms more often.

Comment: Its a good idea nonetheless. I mean yes it can be potentially abused, but that is no different today as BoltClock says. People will remain people with varying interpretations of right and wrong, whether they have a future delete vote function or not. Maybe a secondary problem is more that certain delete voters are a little too free to do as they please, that shouldn't get in the way of progress.

Comment: Related: [Answering questions when no attempt has been made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364755/answering-questions-when-no-attempt-has-been-made) (slightly different problem, but same proposed solution)

Comment: I'm not sure how useful this request is. For me, deleting posts isn't the problem, it's *closing* posts faster. We have the dupe-hammer which is a great start, but I'd like to see more feature(s) like that.

Comment: closing the question is enough. Deleting it will be done by roomba. close+delete is useful when question has accepted answer. Yes SOCVR has a lot of nice tools (and will be nicer in 6 or 8 weeks), but a close+delete would certainly be handy, only for those "no roomba" cases.

Comment: Getting a question deleted really fast will only help making the perceived unfriendlyness of the site worse. I agree with the others that just closing it quickly is enough, and then there’s nothing wrong if it sits like that for a few days before it’s automatically deleted.

Comment: @poke or actually *salvaged* by the OP adding detail and / or narrowing the scope (i.e., I agree with your point). speedy deletion in hands of the few is a really *really* bad idea. Give OP a chance! only if they do not engage it becomes a problem. Granted, 90+%  of them do not engage... Still it won't be fair to the 10-%  that do.

Comment: [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time; can we have a "no comment" close reason?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261858)

Comment: why not giving gold badge users the ability to close "typo/cannot reproduce" questions? after all, they qualify to be able to reproduce or not, like they qualify to find good duplicates.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, There [was hope](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/383944) back in 2014: "we might consider giving gold tag badge holders more weight in other areas" - but that's not what SO Management *now* want.

Comment: @jpp the site isn't going to change much now I'm afraid. the question has been asked: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319399/closing-questions-with-typos-faster-typo-hammer

Answer (score -3):

> However there are many cases where the question is based on completely
>   unrealistic expectations, usually in the style of "I want to build a
>   space ship, can anyone help me?".

Often this kind of questions come from new users who are unaware what is on topic and what is off topic. One way to reduce such garbage questions is to prevent asking them. If they are not asked - no need to delete them. One way to achieve this could be to somehow force users to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) from where they could better know what is off topic.

Comment: I am not sure how helpful the tour actually is for new users, especially inexperienced new users with little industry and work place experience/knowledge for the necessary context the tour is embedded. Nothing stops someone from just scrolling to the end without reading anything so the next fix is a kind of a literacy test. The only fix to poor performance that seems to work is learning to get better through a combination of training/education and learning from mistakes and feedback.

Comment: "the next fix is a kind of a literacy test" - agree, I was also thinking of some kind of quiz after taking a tour.

Comment: I was actually being a bit cynical about the literacy test thing pointing out that a tour or a literacy test or all the other standard external tools used to fix what is really an internal problem with lack of experience and training just do not work very well.

Comment: this isn't really answering the original question. And this "tour" idea has been discussed already. It's been decided that it's better to let _everyone_ answer. That is IMHO one of the strenghts of SO.

Comment: For the reference, here is discussion of "tour" idea: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271804/72178.

Comment: A forced tour seems unlikely to do much. There's too much information in the help center for anyone to read all the way through when they just want an answer to their question and users are already presented with some text many obviously don't read or pay attention to. A better idea is to present them with a question wizard or template.

Answer (score -6):

One issue to consider with this proposal, is that it dramatically reduces the chance of salvaging the question. 
Closed question can generally be reopened by 3K+ users, if they were closed in error, or have been improved.
With the close+delete feature, after the question was closed, it would be instantly deleted, and only 10K+ users would have access to it to vote to reopen if needed.

So if it is implemented, there would have to be some safeguards, e.g. have only a tiny number of them each day, to have some pipeline/review task for examining the deleted questions, to allow 3K users to see/reopen the question for a limited amount of time, or similar.

Comment: This question was just bumped, and no one has commented on your answer yet, so obligatory "First." The goal of this proposal is to facilitate speedy deletion of questions that already have a negligible chance of being salvaged in the first place. The only problem lies in users of this feature misidentifying salvageable content as unsalvageable.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, but that problem is important IMO, judging by the erroneous closes/deletions we have seen over time...

Comment: Indeed. The proposal as a whole doesn't sit right with me either for the same reason, as I acknowledged in my comment on the question.