# Require new users to check the preview before posting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, new-users, question-quality

Following on from [*Highlight the preview on the Ask Question page*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295682/highlight-the-preview-on-the-ask-question-page), whether or not we do that, I wonder if for **new** users, we may want to (softly) force a review of the preview before allowing them to post.

There are lots of ways we could do it. Here's one: When the new user clicks [Post Your Question], we scroll up so the top of the preview is at the top of the window, everything but the preview is dimmed out, and there's a box next to it saying:

> **Did You Check the Preview?**
>
> Your question is not posted yet. Look at the preview:
>
> - Is your question clear?
> - Is your code shown as code?
> - Is your title a short version of your question?
> - Have you included all of the code for the question ***in*** the question? (Not just linked to it.)
>
> [Post My Question]              [Let Me Edit More First]

***Yes*** most people will just find the "post" button and press it without reading, but we might reduce the garbage a bit.

We'd need a reasonable definition of "new user." I'm thinking a user who's posted fewer than 10 questions or answers.

Comment: About `<10` - at the rate SO currently deals with it, I think any new user would learn their lesson from 4-5 bad questions

Comment: @DJDavid98: You'd hope so, wouldn't you? And yet, I'm routinely adding code markup (and a cross comment) to questions from people with rather more than that... :-| (Of course, some people will never learn to do it...) But yeah, < 5, something.

Comment: Related, probably a bit more intrusive: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289144/establish-a-two-stage-question-commit-process

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would so love to have that implemented :) Only if just one out of 1mio. users would read it, that would be enough.

Comment: This already works in a similar way for answers by unregistered new users, they are taken to a confirmation page which asks them to check the preview as well as the general quality of their answer.

Comment: Maybe add a timer as well... if the time between Ask Question and Posting is short you could say something like: *If you only copy-pasted your question here you probably screwed up the markup needed to make it look right*

Comment: This is an excellent idea. Too many users get on here, pay no attention to the rules or norms of the site, post garbage, and then complain that SO is hostile to noobs. This would help reduce all of that and boost the signal-to-noise ratio a bit. Every bit counts.

Comment: Your example is missing the `Screw readin wot i jus writ, jus gimme teh codez` button.

Comment: ...which would link to the [chat with an expert](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174407/179541)...

Comment: Seriously though, it's a good idea in principle, but just another minor roadblock for the (dare I say it) majority of the new users of late. These people don't even bother to read How to Ask so what chance is there of them actually reviewing their masterpiece?

Comment: @TLama: Or, better still, the hypen site.

Comment: I really like the part about drawing _all_ focus to the preview of the question - the ask page is kinda 'busy' with stuff moving about as you type.

Comment: Let's not forgot some strong incentive for the user to scan the "Related" questions one last time to help avoid yet another duplicate question.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm not so sure incentive would help there. Making it easier to see the top voted _answer_ those got might be a better idea, but space on that page is tight. Sometimes you don't know it's _really_ related until you see the answer, making that more convenient? Probably a good idea.

Comment: @TheBlueDog - That is a valid point to make. Some users are clearly going to bypass convention with the understanding what they are asking is not appropriate. However, I do not think those are the majority of new users and I think this will help new users who are well intentioned but just not used to the process nor culture here.

Comment: @TravisJ: That's a very fair comment, my use of 'majority' is probably slightly unfair - it just feels like it at times ...

Comment: @TheBlueDog - I agree. Sometimes I feel more like the nail than the hammer when looking at posts too. Just have to take a break or go to a different part of the site when you start to develop a red spot on your forehead from too much facepalm :P

Comment: @TravisJ: I'll be the first to admit that I'm extremely intolerant and far too dismissive most of the time; I'm working on it, but lately it seems to be an uphill struggle. I suppose, like all popular sites, SO is a victim of its own success.

Comment: I think maybe do it by rep, not answers. I've seen a few users that have more than 10 questions, but all they post is crap (there's no nice way of putting that..). I'd say make 15 rep the threshold.

Answer (score 77):

We're going to be looking at the ask question page from a few different perspectives soon, the most interesting of course being that of a new (or inexperienced) user.

Instead of having one place to type all the things that need to be typed, we're *considering* a version of the page that asks for things individually with additional guidance for each thing:

- What's the title of your question? Your title should be a short summary of the problem you're having.
- Tell us about your problem in a few sentences. Start with phrases like *How do I* or *I don't understand*, followed by the main idea of your question.
- Tell us the steps you've taken so far, or how you arrived at this problem. If you've done any debugging, let us know what you've tried here. If you're stuck on how to get started, let us know what you searched for prior to asking, so we get a good idea of *your* understanding of the problem.
- Show us the code that illustrates the problem. Don't paste *too* much, but make sure you provide the code you suspect is the problem, and any other code we'd need to understand how it works. If all you have is a few attempts, show those to us instead, it helps us understand where you're stuck and write more relevant and helpful answers
- Anything else we should know? Are you working on a non-standard platform? Does the problem require special circumstances to reproduce? The more information you provide, the faster you'll get an answer.

Finally, we'd show them the tags we inferred from the question, a brief bit of guidance about what tagging is and why it's important, and ultimately have them post the question.

What's next? You guessed it, just combine all of the input in order and .. there's the question.

#### What I have above is probably too long, too many words, and too much like getting a quote for car insurance. This is a very hypothetical idea that folks responsible for product development have been kicking around, it's just relevant in the context of your question.

And, to be clear - this would only be shown to very inexperienced users for a very short time, while giving them the ability (along with a bit of caution) to switch to the normal editor.

But, that's the gist of it. Showing a final 'preview' *does* sound like a reasonable idea, provided that the brains and designers working on this find a way to break the essential parts of a good question out into smaller bits.

In the meanwhile, have a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) - I don't have a timeline on when we'll be getting deep into building this, probably months *at least*, but something is coming and I think this idea *could* be a nice part of it.

Comment: Is there a meta post on that multiple-parts idea being kicked around (recognizing it's *just* an idea at present), for comments on it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not yet. While I could _probably_ do a half-decent job of explaining the concept in text, I think we need to get to the point where we have some mockups that we're reasonably happy with before asking for comments - kinda worried that we'd spend more time on clearing up misunderstandings / misinterpretations otherwise (it's a reasonably big change)

Comment: Okay, thanks. Yeah, input is important at some stage, but too early on it can be counter-productive.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder We will definitely post the idea here for discussion since it involves quite a big change, and we'll definitely need help getting the most bang out of the buck when it comes to copy - needs to be about _half_ as many words as I used.

Comment: That will probably lead to a major improvement in question quality. There's been a couple of mentions recently of the idea of "do you know how this site works?" (as in "have your lurked around for a few days here"). A short "what to expect next" could be useful, with bullets for voting, accepting, commenting, what's on-hold/close, or some such and links from there. In some ways size of content matters less if it shrinks on becoming competent in their interactions. Clarity and reasoning is going to be more important to its success than gross size.

Comment: As side suggestion - consider *not asking for title* (at least till the end) - it was suggestion for h&i queue I think at some point... And guestimated vote count - "based on historical data your post so far likely will get following vote count XX" (i.e. post with 5 lines of code +1, 15 lines - 2, 25+ lines  - -5, "please" -1, no title/tags in title - 3)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov We're going to run some tests on how well that actually worked _implemented_ in the helper queue. It follows a very logical cognitive process, in practice .. it kind of reverses thought patterns folks have, since we look remarkably like a 'forum'. Placing emphasis _on_ the title in some kind of preview pane might not be a bad idea, with "Are you sure about your title? That's all folks will really see when selecting stuff to answer" is something I'd like to explore as we build this (wording off my hip entirely).

Comment: @BillWoodger That's also something I'm looking at. We have the tour page, along with lots of text we put in front of new users. UX wise, we have a lot to fit in a relatively small place, more words probably means more 'yes already just let me hit the button!' If you don't mind, I'll ping you here when we toss the idea out officially if I haven't seen you reply in a day.

Comment: Yes, fine with me, thanks.

Comment: Are there plans for any measures that reduce usage of `Code snippet` tool for unsupported languages and code excerpts that are not intended to run?

Comment: @PM77-1: I'm 100% with you there.

Comment: I like the idea of breaking out the parts into stages in an ask question wizard type of approach. And also, to your reference for car insurance quotes, keep in mind that basically every person is able to use those. So vote++ Tim, I like the idea of reworking the flow for *new users* and the ask question feature. Please leave it alone for us regular people though :P

Comment: I rather like how this sounds, Tim. My only concern is that it emphasises code debugging questions.

Answer (score 3):

Every user now goes through a preview review phase before they can post any question. This phase of the asking process encourages users to review their content and explicitly points out any deficits that the system has identified so that they can be improved.

[image: Screenshot of the normal question asking page review phase. The informative text in the upper right is circled, indicating that the question doesn't have any system-recognized issues that the user needs to improve.]

We've also created the Ask Wizard (two variations since this was asked) and new users are specifically guided to review their questions as part of this process.

[image: The review step in the Ask Wizard - a sample question is shown and the helper text guiding the user to review their question content before posting is circled in freehand red circles.]

While these aren't perfect and we're still working on the new user asking process, I feel that the current state of things is sufficient to consider this particular request "completed".

Comment: This obviously isn't working. Hundreds of questions are posted every day with formatting and visibility issues. Make it a separate step between authoring and posting, eg _"Here's what your question will look like when posted. Please check it for any formatting issues before submitting"_

Comment: Not sure how that's different than the review state, @Phil - it's not necessarily a great thing to point out but I'd guess that at least some people don't really care about formatting being "correct" because they don't know what it should look like. I'm not convinced we can distinguish between people overlooking the preview and people who don't really care... but I'd guess that if they cared, they would try and edit it once the post is live.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It's just a gut feel that some people simply scroll to the bottom and click the button without even a glance at the preview. I'm not just referring to formatting; some questions are almost entirely HTML / PHP / some other markup language that renders completely invisible when not code fenced.