# Quick modal to show bits of help to new users when they ask a question

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users

When a newish user wants to ask a question, show him first a modal with a couple radio buttons:

> Your question is about...
>
> - Code that does not work
> - A feature of a framework
> - A programming-related software
> - [...]
> - Something else

Clicking one button dismisses the modal and shows some help text paraphrasing the help center and the flag reasons, placing it between the title field and the question field:

> Your question is about **code that does not work**. Do not forget to:
>
> - Include all the code necessary to reproduce the issue (see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
> - Explain what went wrong with the code
> - Include what you have tried to solve the issue, what research you have done
>
> You can find more informations in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

In the end, make a specialized "How to Ask" box depending on user input allowing newbies to quickly get what should absolutely be present in a question, to make them better understand StackOverflow and integrate well with us.
Also, fewer crappy questions.
<sub>Maybe. I hope?</sub>

Comment: You should try to ask a question as a "newish" user so you can see the interstitial we put in their faces, the topic and formatting hints we put in the sidebar, etc. All of that usually for naught. You can lead a user to the Help Center, but you can't make them read.

Comment: See here, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295683/1927206, and Tim Post's answer on that.

Comment: Its a nice idea, but the list of selectable options would be very difficult to put together. They should not overlap, and see the provided examples: both "code that does not work" and "a feature of a framework" already do overlap. What if it is code relating to a feature of a framework that does not work? Which one do you pick?

Comment: A quick timed modal, and not closeable before five minutes or so?

Comment: @Christopher, looks like your edit is wrong -- the questioner is indeed referring to a *modal* (as in *modal dialog box*), not to a *model*.

Comment: I think this is a horrible idea.

Comment: Users [who urgently need help with their questions|in general] don't read. The Ask a Question page is already quite obnoxious with links and warnings, and if you're going to stuff the question textarea they'll happily clear it.

Comment: @Tanner Strongly related, although it doesn't feature any direct user input.

Comment: @Kyll it doesn't contain direct user input, but I'm not sure that the input you have suggested brings any additional benefits, as that list could become a long list to cover all types of questions. The suggestions on the linked post, would contain generic hints towards making a question better. The checkbox is the only direct user input in the linked post.

Comment: @Tanner All types of questions _a new user generally asks_, which is hopefully a lot easier to manage?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks for the clarification and reverting my edit. In all of the contexts I previously knew about, "modal" was an adjective. +1 to your comment. (For anyone wanting to know more, see [Modal Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) ).