# How to close this question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm not sure which close reason fits [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722170/how-to-find-oracle-database-connection-details).

1. Its asking about SQLDeveloper so its not for forwarding to SuperUser.
2. Its not about database administration, so its not for DBA.
3. Its not programming related.
4. Its not broad, unclear or opinion based - its actually quite specific.

Its a bad question because the OP is expecting someone to help find a solution, something that's explained in meticulous detail in the documentation (I linked to this in my comment) and it seems he just can't be bothered to search.

I feel there should be some reason for these specific "lazy" questions, other than downvoting to oblivion and then hoping for a close.  Its closely related to [this similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions?rq=1), but that's more to prevent these questions from being posted - mine is asking for a specific vote reason for the ones that get through.

Comment: I usually just comment along the lines of RTFM, downvote if the question is stupid, and move along.

Comment: I do the same, but these questions just clog up the site. There should be a way to close them, similar to the gold close-as-dupe hammer we have.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the question remaining open. If someone wants to dig through the docs, and write an answer for the problem, then it will probably help future googlers searching for the error message.

Comment: @user000001 the error message was aded just a few minutes ago, but now I agree it is worth keeping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rule of thumb: if you can't identify anything specific wrong with a question, **then don't vote to close it**. Closing is not a good venue for expressing your personal frustration and distaste; use downvotes or, if you *must*, a comment.

Dunno about you, but a lot of us are here with the idea that we can do better than the documentation. Chances are, this guy's not gonna be the last person to go looking for an answer to that and miss the docs anyway...

Comment: Can I cast half a downvote? Your first paragraph is spot-on but I'm experiencing difficulties in dealing with the second one.

Comment: If it helps, I hate Oracle and have nothing but bad memories of wasted hours trying to get connections working.