# Split up the body of the question, for struggling new users, into logical sections

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Would it be helpful for the system to spot low rep users who're trying to use the system, and then give them multiple boxes to post it, to encourage more structure to the question?

Something like:

[image: Suggested layout]

Would something like this help? Similar to the extra help in the edit queue, that was recently introduced?

Comment: similar suggestion in this post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253317/57475

Comment: Your intent of catering to new users is commendable, but if you think most of them will give a second thought to the split structure instead of dumping their full question in the first block, I have several bridges for sale you may be interested in.

Comment: and more loosely this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140517/251594

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi we were all new once, but we were the ones that stayed. Getting more 'new users' to stay has to be good, right?

Comment: @Tanner that first one is spot on! Let's get on it now!

Comment: @Pureferret, are you implying new users would leave the site if we do not encourage them to provide more structure to their questions? Most of them would stay I believe.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi hard to tell, but my suspicion is that a fair number will leave when then their question is rejected, attributing it to people 'not being nice' rather than 'I'm asking crap questions'.

Comment: @Pureferret, that's hard to tell indeed. My gut tells me that's not the case, but my gut is not admissible in court and has been wrong before.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi my gut: IANAL